# Product over a range

Tags: code-golf, math

Your task is simple: given two integers \$a\$ and \$b\$, output \$\Pi[a,b]\$; that is, the product of the range between \$a\$ and \$b\$. You may take \$a\$ and \$b\$ in any reasonable format, whether that be arguments to a function, a list input, STDIN, et cetera. You may output in any reasonable format, such as a return value (for functions) or STDOUT. \$a\$ will always be less than \$b\$.

Note that the end may be exclusive or inclusive of \$b\$. I'm not picky. ^_^

### Test cases

```
[a,b) => result
[2,5) => 24
[5,10) => 15120
[-4,3) => 0
[0,3) => 0
[-4,0) => 24

[a,b] => result
[2,5] => 120
[5,10] => 151200
[-4,3] => 0
[0,3] => 0
[-4,-1] => 24
```

---

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

---

### Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=66202,OVERRIDE_USER=44713;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I'm answering this in TI-BASIC tomorrow.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Good luck ;)

Comment: Can the input be taken as `b, a`?

Comment: @FlipTack yes you can

Answer (score 38):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
rP
```

Takes two numbers as command line arguments. [Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=clA&input=&args=MQ+NQ)

Note that this is inclusive range. For the cost of a byte (3 bytes), we can make this exclusive:

```
’rP
```

[Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZclA&input=&args=NQ+MQ) Note that the arguments must be given in the order `b a` for this version.

### Explanation

#### Inclusive

```
a rP b
  r   dyadic atom, creates inclusive range between a and b
   P  computes product of the list
```

#### Exclusive

```
b ’rP a
  ’   decrement b (by default, monadic atoms in dyadic chains operate on the left argument)
   r  range
    P product
```

Comment: I doubt this is beatable...

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos you jelly?

Answer (score 34):

### [ArnoldC](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ArnoldC), <s>522</s> 511 bytes

First post on codegolf !

I had fun doing this.
Exclusive range.

```
LISTEN TO ME VERY CAREFULLY f
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE a
I NEED YOUR CLOTHES YOUR BOOTS AND YOUR MOTORCYCLE b
GIVE THESE PEOPLE AIR
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE r
YOU SET US UP 1
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE l
YOU SET US UP 1
STICK AROUND l
GET TO THE CHOPPER r
HERE IS MY INVITATION r
YOU'RE FIRED a
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER a
HERE IS MY INVITATION a
GET UP 1
ENOUGH TALK
GET TO THE CHOPPER l
HERE IS MY INVITATION b
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET a
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
I'LL BE BACK r
HASTA LA VISTA, BABY
```

Explanations (Thanks Bijan):

```
DeclareMethod f
        MethodArguments a
        MethodArguments b
        NonVoidMethod
        DeclareInt r
        SetInitialValue 1
        DeclareInt l
        SetInitialValue 1
        WHILE l
                AssignVariable r
                        SetValue r
                        MultiplicationOperator a
                EndAssignVariable
                AssignVariable a
                        SetValue a
                        + 1
                EndAssignVariable
                AssignVariable l
                        SetValue b
                        > a
                EndAssignVariable
        EndWhile
        Return r
EndMethodDeclaration
```

Comment: Hahaha... I am stil laughing

Comment: but an explanation would be great

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/tGLbXYWX) it is converted and indented using [this](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC) as reference

Comment: Which interpreter are you using?

Comment: The official [one](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC). You're right about @NO PROBLEMO and 1 (not 0 ;) )

Comment: the wierdest language i ever came across honestly !

Comment: This isn't weird, this is Arnold ! Take a look at the [official page](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC) or the [wiki](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC/wiki) if you like it

Comment: Get up. Enough talk. Get to the chopper.

Answer (score 21):

### Python, 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a>b or a*f(a+1,b)
```

Inclusive range. Repeatedly multiplies by and increments the left endpoint, until it is higher than the right endpoint, in which case it's the empty product of 1 (as True).

Answer (score 18):

### Minecraft 15w35a+, program size 456 total (see below)

[image]

This calculates `PI [a,b)`. Input is given by using these two commands: `/scoreboard players set A A {num}` and `/scoreboard players set B A {num}`. Remember to use `/scoreboard objectives add A dummy` before input.

Scored using: `{program size} + ( 2 * {input command} ) + {scoreboard command} = 356 + ( 2 * 33 ) + 34 = 456`.

This code corresponds to the following psuedocode:

```
R = 1
loop:
  R *= A
  A += 1
  if A == B:
    print R
    end program
```

Download the world [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/uapxuk2ppror5ms/PPCG__Product_over_a_Range.zip).

Comment: Program size is counted by [this scoring method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/36670).

Comment: Dammit, you got to it before I did. :I

Comment: You need to specify snapshot version, i.e. `15w46a` or something.

Comment: Minecraft :D LoL, golfing in Minecraft :D

Comment: @username.ak This may surprise you, but it's not that uncommon here. Lol

Answer (score 14):

### TI-BASIC, 9 bytes

```
Input A
prod(randIntNoRep(A,Ans
```

Takes one number from `Ans`  and another from a prompt.

Also 9 bytes, taking input as a list from `Ans`:

```
prod(randIntNoRep(min(Ans),max(Ans
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out for myself, so I'm gonna post it here: Each function in TI-BASIC is one byte.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Lots of them do, but not all of them. `%` is two bytes.

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2, <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```
lambda l:reduce(int.__mul__,range(*l))
```

Pretty much the obvious anonymous function answer.

EDIT: Thanks to xnor for saving 6 bytes with some features I didn't know.

Comment: You can use the built-in `int.__mul__`, which works in place of your lambda. The two numbers `x,y` can also be written unpacked as `*l`.

Comment: Crossed out 44 still looks like 44.

Answer (score 10):

### Pyth, 5 bytes

```
*FrQE
```

Pyth doesn't have product, so we reduce * over the range.

Uses exclusive range.

Comment: `*FrFQ` is equivalent but with different input, just for fun :)

Comment: Q is implicitly read, so this can become `*FrF` - 4 bytes

Comment: @Scott This question and answer were written long before Pyth had implicit input, so I'm keeping it.

Answer (score 10):

## R, 22 bytes

```
function(a,b)prod(a:b)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
1##&@@Range@##&
```

A shorter solution that only works for non-negative integers:

```
#2!/(#-1)!&
```

Comment: Even shorter for non-negative integers: `#2!#/#!&`

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```js
(a,b)=>eval("for(c=a;a<b;)c*=++a")
```

Sometimes the simplest answer is the best! Just a `for` loop inside `eval`. Inclusive range.

Comment: Wow. That's impressive!

Comment: Aw man, I thought of this exact solution while trying to golf mine just now... +1

Comment: This one is even shorter with 25 characters:

`f=(a,b)=>a<b?a*f(a+1,b):1`

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 7 bytes

Easy challenges like this are always fun. :)

```
UoV r*1
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VW9WIHIqMQ==&input=NSAxMA==)

#### Explanation

```
UoV r*1  // Implicit: U = first input, V = second input
UoV      // Generate range [U,V).
    r*1  // Reduce by multiplication, starting at 1.
```

Wow, this seems pathetic compared to the other answers so far. I need to work on Japt some more...

Comment: Explanation? :3

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Done :)

Comment: Woot, 5K rep! :D

Comment: looks like you got it to 5 bytes: `oV r*` [Try It Online](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=b1Ygcio&input=NQoxMA)

Answer (score 6):

### Seriously, 4 bytes

```
,ixπ

,         Read list [a,b] from stdin
 i        Flatten it to a b
  x       Pop a,b, push range(a,b)
   π      Pop the list and push its product.
```

Hex Dump:

```
2c6978e3
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c6978e3&input=[3,6])

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, <s>6</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s>  10 bytes

Thanks to Dennis and RetoKoradi for help with golfing!

```
q~1$-,f+:*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E1%24-%2Cf%2B%3A*&input=2%205)

Takes input as `a b`. Calculates `PI [a,b)`.

*Note: this program is 6 bytes long, and only works if `a` and `b` are positive.*

```
q~,>:*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%2C%3E%3A*&input=2%205)

Takes input as `a b`. Calculates `PI [a,b)`.

Comment: `q~{_)_W$<}g;]:*` saves three bytes.

Comment: `q~1$-,f+:*` for 10 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Prolog, 45 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(A,B,C):-A=B,C=A;D is A+1,p(D,B,E),C is A*E.
```

**Explained:**

```
p(A,B,C):-A=B,      % A is unifiable with B
          C=A       % Unify C with A
          ;         % OR
          D is A+1, % D is the next number in the range
          p(D,B,E), % Recurse on the range after the first element
          C is A*E. % The result C is the product of the first element and the result 
                      of the recursion
```

**Example:**

```
p(5,10,X).
X = 151200

p(-4,-1,X).
X = 24
```

Answer (score 6):

### Octave, 15 bytes

```
@(a,b)prod(a:b)
```

Straightforward. Uses the inclusive range.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
a#b=product[a..b]
```

Usage example: `2#5`-> `120`.

Comment: You're allowed to choose to include b.

Comment: @xnor: Ups, must have overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think PPCG allows answers given as expressions.

Comment: @proudhaskeller: the [default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) is to allow full programs and functions. Snippets, expressions, etc. have to be explicitly permitted in the task description.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 16 bytes

```
f(a,b)=prod(a:b)
```

Note: if the range object `a:b` (which is literally stored as a start value and a stop value, and internally includes a "increment by 1 on each step" value) is permitted as the input, then just 4 bytes are required: `prod`.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 13

```bash
seq -s* $@|bc
```

Assumes there are no files in the current directory whose names start with `-s`.  Start and end (inclusive) are passed as command-line parameters.

This simply produces the sequence from start to end, separated by `*`, then pipes to `bc` for arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: But I start all my files with `-s`! :P

Answer (score 5):

## C, 32 bytes

For `[a,b)`:

```
f(a,b){return a-b?a*f(a+1,b):1;}
```

For `[a,b]` (On Katenkyo's suggestions, 32 bytes again) :

```
f(a,b){return a<b?a*f(a+1,b):b;}
```

Comment: I found an other solution in C, if you're interested, it's also 32 bytes `f(a,b){return a<b?a*f(a+1,b):b;}`. :)

Comment: -5 bytes in gcc with `a=...` instead of `return...`

Comment: -1 (inclusive) with `a>b?:a*f(a+1,b)` as the body

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 4 bytes

Inclusive Range

```
2$:p
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MiQ6cA&input=Mgo1)

#### Explanation

```
2$: % Implicitly grab two input arguments and create the array input1:input2
p   % Take the product of all array elements
```

Thanks to [@Don Muesli](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/don-muesli) for helping me get the hang of this whole MATL thing.

Comment: Isn't `&:p` a byte shorter?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan at the time I posted my answer we didn't have `&`

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

I can't believe none of us JS golfers thought to use recursion...

```
a=>F=b=>a-b?b*F(b-1):a
```

Assign to a variable with e.g. `var q = a=>F=b=>a-b?b*F(b-1):a`, then call like `q(2)(5)`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
⟦₃×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG04vK/z@av@xRU/Ph6f//R0cb6ZjG6kSb6hgaAKl4Ex1jIGUAJoEcg9hYAA)

Input is passed as `[A,B]`. The range is exclusive of B, but could be made inclusive by replacing the `₃` with `₂`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nowadays, it doesn't matter when languages are made, so this answer is perfectly competitive. Hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: Ah, good to know! I guess I've been looking at too many old challenges with answers sorted by votes.

Comment: @UnrelatedString By the way, if you see those non-competing messages it's perfectly fine to edit them out.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), 4 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=T3JqSg)

```
OrjJ
  jJ two inputs
 r   range between them [j,J)
O    product
```

Comment: In modern Jolf, this can be `Orj` (which automatically is transpiled to `Orjx`)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```
->i,n{(i..n).reduce:*}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
-> i,n {
  (i..n).reduce:* # Product of a range
}
```

**Usage:**

```
->i,n{(i..n).reduce:*}[5,10]
=> 151200
```

Comment: I was thinking about this same solution last night but didn't have the time to write it up.

Comment: A byte is saved with the introduction of implicit named parameters `->{(_1.._2).reduce:*}`.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, 30 Bytes

```
param($a,$b)$a..$b-join'*'|iex
```

Takes input as two integers, creates a range with `..`, then `-join`s that with asterisks, pipes it into `Invoke-Expression` (similar to `eval`). The range operator in PowerShell is inclusive.

Pretty competitive with non-golfing languages.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
ŸP
```

Explanation:

```
Ÿ   # Inclusive range [input, ..., input]
 P  # Total product of the list
    # Implicit printing top of the stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## J, 8 bytes

```
[:%/!@<:
```

#### Usage

```
>> f =: [:%/!@<:
>> f 10 5
<< 15120
```

where `>>` is STDIN and `<<` is STDOUT.

#### Explanation

It computes `∏[a,b]` as `(b-1)!/(a-1)!`.

```
minus_one =: <:
factorial =: !
of        =: @
monadic   =: [:
division  =: %/
f =: monadic division factorial of minus_one
```

### Previous 13-byte version

Written when I had no idea what `J` even is :p

```
*/(}.[:>:i.)/
```

Usage:

```
   */(}.[:>:i.)/ 5 10
30240
```

Explanation:

```
*/            NB. multiply over
  (
   }.         NB. remove [the first x items] from
     [:>:     NB. increment all of
         i.   NB. the numbers from 0 to [y-1]
           )
            / NB. insert the above code into the following numbers
```

Detailed explanation:

```
i.10 would produce 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

>:i.10 would make it 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 10

the [: is used to make the ">:" take only one argument (a monad)
because if it takes two arguments, it is a different function.
so [:>:i.10 becomes 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

}. means take away the first [x] items from the following list,
so 5}.1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 becomes 6 7 8 9 10

the two slashes "/" in the code are actually the same
for example, */6 7 8 9 10 becomes 6*7*8*9*10
```

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: You can use `[:*/]+i.@-` for *10 bytes* if you take the range `[a, b)` as `b ([:*/]+i.@-) a` such that `10 ([:*/]+i.@-) 5` outputs `15120`.

Comment: @miles That answer was written when I didn't know `J` at all :p

Comment: Your 8 byte solution won't work if neither argument is positive.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>8</s> 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
×/…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn///B0/UcNy/6nPWqb8Ki371HfVE//R13Nh9YbP2qbCOQFBzkDyRAPz@D/RgppCqZcpkDS0IDr0HoTIMOYywBMQniH1hsCAA)

`…` range

`×/` multiplication across

This is an "atop" so `a(×/…)b` is `×/a…b`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

*Thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126) for [helping me brainstorm input methods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55468258#55468258).*

```r
prod((a=scan()):a[2])
```

Uses inclusive range. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoP0VDI9G2ODkxT0NT0yox2ihW878Rl@l/AA)

#### Explanation

```r
      a=scan()         Read the two inputs as a vector and assign it to a
     (        ):       Use a as the lower end of a range (R interprets this as "use the
                        first element of the vector" by default)
                a[2]   Use the second element of a as the upper end of the range
prod(               )  Take the product of all numbers in the range
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 19 bytes

```
f(a,b)=∏_{n=a}^bn
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iqtrnjbvwn)

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 7 bytes

```
nnL$*N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nnL%24*N%2E&input=5%2010)

#### Explanation

```
nn         Takes two numbers from input
  L        Pops b,a and pushes a..b
   $*      Product the whole stack
     N.    Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 52 bytes

Very simple code; a bit too long.

```
def p(a,b):
 t=1
 for i in range(a,b):t*=i
 return t
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> 41 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ*

```
(a,b)=>[...Array(b-a)].reduce(x=>x*a++,1)
```

Seems a little too long...

```
(a,b)=>           // Define an anonymous function that takes parameters a and b, and returns:
[...Array(b-a)]   // An array of b-a items,
.reduce(          // Reduced by
x=>x*a++          //  multiplying each item with the previous,
,1)               //  starting at 1.
```

Comment: That works? kudos! I don't think you need the `y` in the reduce mapping, so cut it off at `x=>x*a++`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks, that trick works really well!

Comment: you should add a semicolon at the end. for the score.

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 14 bytes

```perl6
{[*] $^a..$^b}
```

usage:

```perl6
my &code = {[*] $^a..$^b}
say code |$_ for (2,5),(5,10),(-4,3),(0,3),(-4,-1);
# 120
# 151200
# 0
# 0
# 24

say chars code 1,10000;
# 35660
```

If you wanted to exclude the last element use `..^` instead of `..`

Answer (score 3):

## gs2, 4 bytes

Hex: `57 0e 4f 65`

Mnemonics: `read-nums dump crange product`

[Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=Vw5PZQ&input=NCAyNwo&debug=on)

`dump` pops a list from the stack and pushes its contents (like `~` in GolfScript), and `crange` gives `[a,b)`.

Answer (score 3):

## LabVIEW, 14 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

Range is exclusive. Creates an array from `a` to `b` then multiplies all elements.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 54 characters

```
int p(int a,int b){int p=a;while(++a<b)p*=a;return p;}
```

We cheat the first multiply by assigning it to the temp-product. Then we pre-increment the counter (shamelessly stolen from the input parameter) to skip the first one.

Compare `< b` instead of `<= b` - both are to spec, but this saves a character.

Sample:

```
C:\files>type BadProd.java
class BadProd {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println(p(2,5));
        System.out.println(p(5,10));
        System.out.println(p(-4,3));
        System.out.println(p(0,3));
        System.out.println(p(-4,0));

    }
    static int p(int a,int b){int p=a;while(++a<b)p*=a;return p;}
}
C:\files>java BadProd
24
15120
0
0
24
```

Comment: 43 bytes if you use a lambda: `(a,b)->{int p=a;while(++a<b)p*=a;return p;}`

Comment: Currently on Java 7 - updated to clarify. Good point though!

Comment: Came here to create a Java 7 answer, but you beat me to it. :) I noticed yours is exclusive `b` and uses a loop though, so [I made a (slightly shorter) inclusive `b` method using recursion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82430/52210). Cool to see more code-golfing Java 7 answers, even though you've answered this more than halve a year ago. ;) +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 27 bytes

Input assumes `a` is on top of the main stack and `b` is under it

```
dsar[dsc*lc1-dla<A]sAlAxrp
```

Ungolfed:

```
dsa        # duplicate 'a', store a copy in register a
r          # reverse top two items on stack
[          # start macro definition 
  dsc      # duplicate counter, store in register c 
           #  ('b' is the initial counter value)
  *        # pop top two elements of stack, multiply and push result
  lc       # copy the stored counter to the stack
  1- d     # decrement and duplicate it
  la       # copy 'a' to the stack
  <A       # if 'a' is < the counter, run macro A
]sA        # store this macro as A
lAx        # execute macro A
r          # reverse top two elements of stack
p          # pop/print the result
```

Answer (score 3):

### dc, <s>41</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

This is my first code golf, so bear with me

```
[lad1+sa*dstlalb>d]sd?sbdst1+saltldxf
```

It must be saved as a file, and invoked (with bash, so UNIX only) as

```
dc -f [filename]
```

It will proceed to wait for input, in the form of `a b` integers. Note that negative numbers must come as `_number`.

---

Alternatively,

```
echo "X Y [lad1+sa*dstlalb>d]sd?sbdst1+saltdxf" | dc
```

with X and Y replaced with the two numbers you'd like to product-over-range. This one won't wait unless you don't pipe two numbers.

---

## Explanation:

```
The recursive macro:
[lad    # load the contents of register a onto the stack, and duplicate it
 1+sa   # Add 1 to the top of the stack (a) and store it in register a
 *dst   # Multiply two off the stack, duplicate and store in register t (stack contains t)
 lalb>d # load a and b, as long as b>a execute d (which is this macro)
 ]sd    # Store that macro in register d
 ?      # Wait for input, hope it is [a b] without braces 
 sbd    # store b, duplicate a (stack == a a) (old: sbddsa)
 st     # store a => t (stack == a)
 1+sa   # add 1 to a and store it in a
 lt     # load t since d expects the total to be on the stack
 ldx    # load d and execute it as a macro
 f      # after d is done recursively calling, t will still be on the stack.
        # Print the stack and close (close is implicit)
```

There was a removal of a spare duplication and store (dsa)

Comment: I believe you can omit the `q`, since `dc` automatically terminates when it reaches the end of its input.

Comment: By the way, another common input method is `dc -e "stuff"`. This will also take input from `stdin` or piped in from `echo`. Keep up the good work! `dc` is my favourite language.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

Range is inclusive

```
{a,b->(a..b).reduce{c,d->c*d}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYw5DoAgEAB7X7HlrgGirYn0PoNDEyKuhqAN4e2oU8x0s585Bm6PiXCl00@AC2cBnwik/gtzK0ZYqdEoZUml1d9uLU54qV3va23bzXCYwEhQOvi4UuAcGf8jjmIciLraXg)

---

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 21 bytes

If you can take input as an `IntRange`:

```
{it.reduce{c,d->c*d}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCoAgFEDR3a94o0ZKrUHurf2BqIVkrxBrEb/9ZXc7yz2uHAPSayLc6XIT8AXzanD3AqSGBpiphKySd4/1xfZOatu5Wml7EE4TkAsoDFp3Cpgj8n/ER6XGQQhW6QM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 26 bytes

```
Z}N\;^-[n^\z^*Zn}N^\o^-]z#
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyJafU5cXDteLVtuXlxcel4qWm59Tl5cXG9eLV16IyIsIiIsIjUgMTAiXQ==)!

```
Z                   Save the value (the first argument) as register Z
}N                  Increment and save to N
\;                  Go to the right child and copy the parent value
^-                  Go to the parent and subtract (the left child is pre-set as the second argument)
[               ]   While non-zero (basically, while N is not the same as the end)
 n                  Restore register N
  ^\z^              Put Z in the right child and go to the parent
      *Z            Multiply and save to Z; these three lines do Z = Z * N
        n}N         Restore N, increment, and save back to N
           ^\o^-    Compare against register O; automatically set to the second argument
z#                  Restore Z, the product, and output
```

This is right-exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{*/x+!y-x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs6rW0q/QVqzUrajl4kqLNrI2jVVQ0FewtVMwMgHyTa0NDWIhfENTQyMDoJCuibUxVAjENQDxEFygLEyDkQkAFrcU6Q==)

*-1 byte thanks to PyGamer0 for telling me that I don't need `'` after `+`*

Another easy one. Exclusive at b.

Explainations:

```
Assuming that a is 2 and b is 5

{*/x+!y-x}            Main program. Takes x as `a` and y as `b`
      y-x              b-a to fix the range (5 - 2 = 3)
     !                 Range   (0 1 2)
   x+                  += x to each elenent    (2 3 4)
 */                    Product (2*3*4 = 24)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 30 bytes

```kotlin
{a,b->(a..b).reduce{c,d->c*d}}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/yjh7U1oon)

Comment: By turning the type into `Int.(Int) -> Int`, you can save one byte: `{this..it.reduce{c,d->c*d}}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 36 bytes

```
?A:?B:A.I:(A.B.<^A.1+A:A.I.*I:)I.!$
```

This reads two integers from STDIN and prints an integer to STDOUT. This computes the sum over the closed interval, i.e. `[a,b]` rather than `[a,b)`.

Ungolfed:

```
? A:             ~ Read an integer from STDIN, assign to A
? B:             ~ Read STDIN, assign B
A. I:            ~ Begin an accumulator at A
( A. B. < ^      ~ While A < B...
  A. 1 + A:      ~ Increment A
  A. I. * I:     ~ I *= A
)
I. !             ~ Print I to STDOUT
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39

Inclusive range.

```js
(a,b)=>[...Array(b-a)].map(_=>b*=a++)|b
```

Note: `map` beats `reduce` once again

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that. +1

Answer (score 2):

## zsh, 30 bytes

```zsh
f=({$1..$2})
echo $[${f// /*}]
```

Sample run:

```
manatwork% zsh product.zsh 5 10
151200
```

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxP9lWw1AhRqtaxVBPT8WoVpPLxsZGJTo59r8mF1eagrGCGZC0UDA0AlKGCqb/AQ "Zsh – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 36 bytes

(35 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
reduce range(.[0];.[1])as$i(1;.*$i)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bin/jq -s 'reduce range(.[0];.[1])as$i(1;.*$i)' <<< '5 10'
15120
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=reduce%20range%28.[0]%3B.[1]%29as$i%281%3B.*$i%29&j=[5,%2010]) (Passing `-s` through URL is not supported – so input passed as [5, 10].)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
Prompt A,B:prod(randIntNoRep(A,B
```

Answer (score 2):

### Fortran, 44 bytes

Finally a use for those pesky implicit types.

```
function j(k,l)
j=1
do i=k,l
j=j*i
enddo
end
```

Test program:

```
program testProduct
  integer :: a, k, l
  k = -4
  l = -1
  a = j(k,l)
  print*,a
end program testProduct
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 14 bytes

<sub>Note to self: add range</sub>

Expects input as `b a`.

```
D{-\[D1+]l1-\*
D               Duplicate the top input.
 {-\[   ]       Repeat the stuff in the brackets by the difference between the 
                inputs.
     D1+        Duplicate, add one.
                I now have the range [a,b].
         l1-\*  Multiply all the items together.
```

This is a function in [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) that will leave the product of the range `[a,b]` on the stack. "But how do I test it?!?" I hear you ask?

Concatenate `N`. c:

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=RHstXFtEMStdbDEtXCpO&input=&args=MTA+NQ)

Comment: 3k rep for you ! :D

Comment: \o/ @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ

Answer (score 2):

## [Milky Way 1.5.17](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 28 bytes

```
1%{¢¢L§{?{¢1-e__^}}£*}!
```

---

#### Explanation

```
1          1             # push integer to the stack
 %{                £ }   # for loop
   ¢¢     ¢              # read a single line of input from the command line
     L                   # push a Pythonic range(0, TOS + 1)
      §{          }      # mapping
        ?{    __ }       # if-else statement
            -            # subtract the STOS from the TOS
             e           # order the TOS and STOS (greater-than)
                ^        # pop the TOS
                      !  # output the TOS
```

---

#### Usage

```
$ ./mw <path-to-code> -i <input>
```

Example:

```
$ ./mw test.mwg -i "2
5"
```

Milky Way takes line breaks literally. `\n` is not interpreted as a line break. In future versions, this will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 17 bytes

```
(F(a b)(r *(_ a b
```

This includes `a` but excludes `b`.

Explanation:

```
(F(a b)    ; Anonymous function F(a, b)
  (r *     ; Reduce by multiplication
    (_ a b ; Range from a to b
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 4 bytes

```
_XF*
```

`_` gets the range `[a,b)`, `X` expands it onto the stack, and `F*` folds multiplication over the range.
[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=_XF*)!

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, <strike>52</strike> 51 bytes

```
fn p(mut a:i32,b:i32)->i32{for i in a+1..b{a*=i;}a}
```

Usage (+ ungolfed version) as follows:

```
fn p(mut a:i32, b:i32) -> i32 {
    for i in a+1..b {
        a *= i;
    }
    a
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", p(2, 5));
    println!("{}", p(5, 10));
    println!("{}", p(-4, 3));
    println!("{}", p(-4, 0));
}
```

Uses the current stable version of Rust (1.5.0)

Comment: `fn p(a:i32,b:i32)->i32{(a..b).fold(1,|a,b|a*b)}`. In a future version of Rust: `fn p(a:i32,b:i32)->i32{(a..b).product()}`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```java
int c(int a,int b){return-~a!=b?a*c(a+1,b):a*b;}
```

[*corsiKa*'s answer is exclusive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66332/52210), mine is inclusive (and slightly shorter by using recursion instead of a loop).

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hc2xDoIwEMbxnac4txZbAiqLxPgETozG4VqIKUIhtJAYgq9eaXQVl2@5X/5X4Yi87UpdFQ8nazQGLqj0FAAYi1ZJp7QFSfwi8yvo1Jd26DV/4eYkzhhKgtuECXrEUGSzA@gGUSv5DcDYqgKaJUpy2yt9v94AqX8AkD@NLZuoHWzULSdbayLJjkFKafYbpAySeFXwA4P9qoj/AZ/gyYfMweze)

```java
int c(int a,int b){  // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  return-~a!=b?      //  If `a+1` is not equal to `b`
         a*c(a+1,b)  //   Return `a` multiplied by the recursive call with `a+1,b`
        :            //  Else:
         a*b;        //   Return `a*b`
}                    // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 42 Bytes

```
<?=array_product(range($ARGV[1],$ARGV[2]))

<?=                         // Open file, '=' is shorthand for 'echo'
array_product(              // Get product of array
range($argv[1],$argv[2])    // array is range from a to b
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fith](https://github.com/nazek42/fith), 17 bytes (non-competing)

*This language was created after the challenge.*

```
{ range product }
```

Anonymous function. Excludes `b`. Pretty self-explanatory.

Stack effect: `a b -- *[a,b)`

Comment: Is this your language? :3

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes it is! Mainly inspired by Factor and Haskell. It's concatenative/stack-based.

Comment: I guess then `{range` would be one token, so the whitespace is necessary?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a successor to Forth? :P

Comment: @mbomb007 It's that too :)

Answer (score 2):

### ><>, 33 bytes

```
 1&:@$:@)?\&n;
:$@:+1&*&:/?@@$@)@
```

My first fish attempt.

Inclusive range
Assumes a and b are on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>26</s> 58 bytes

```
func p(a:Int,b:Int)->Int{return(a+1..<b).reduce(a){$0*$1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## tcl, 55

```
incr p
while \$a<$b {set p [expr $p*$a];incr a}
puts $p
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/UMBGY88368)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 7 bytes

Input is taken as two numbers on standard in. Range is `[a,b]`.

```
IIEK*O@

II       read two ints and push to stack
  E      expand range between top two stack items
   K     reduce stack by...
    *    multiplying
     O   pop and print number
      @  terminate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/9/T09Vby9/h/38jBVMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 27 bytes

```fs
fun a b->Seq.fold(*)1[a..b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc1BCoMwEAXQvaf4CAEtOJjuW8gNCl2KCzUZiEimpvH8afQAnc2Hx@cPf7tFosuZj4AJc/d8u51YNtvcWj1MRPOYN5fAeOBPp6pYIjx8gCbSPaxcsl7SF7qfhHKf6EPigPoVxR5LgjAGZYiUGcsTZeqys6LhM9r8Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), 5 bytes

```
p;Brr
```

### Explanation

```
p     - Print...
 ;    - Product of...
  B   - Range...
   r  - Next input
    r - Next input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-hr`, 3 bytes

```
ɧ∑*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////5PJHHRO1/v834jL9r5tRBAA)

Explanation:

```
ɧ   # Generate inclusive range from two integer inputs
 ∑* # Calculate product of whole stack
    # Output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:b<a or a*f(a+1,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCoAgEIDhuZ7iRq0LtHKJepJouCMkoSzCpac3renjH/7rCdvp2xjttNPBKwEhDzwSnDdQZQXVGllGmxMZnJ9Fi0YiCINaZZseu6z6SdlouQxlcd3OBxBpk2g/YvkC)

Range is inclusive (e.g., `f(2,5) => 120`).

Answer (score 2):

### [`W`](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 3 bytes (inclusive)

```
.*r
```

### Explanation

```
ab.   % Generate inclusive range from a to b
   *  % Multiplication
    r % Preserve the operation's action & reduce by it
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
$*Ya,b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fRSsyUSfp////Rv9NAQ)

-1 byte from DLosc.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that this is a yank

Comment: [`Y`ep](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210387/16766)

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal, 2 bytes

```
rΠ
```

Range of a to b, then product

[Try it!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=r%CE%A0&inputs=5%0A2&header=&footer=)

Comment: Vyxal can also do [the inclusive range version in 2 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiw7ciLCLhuaHOoCIsIiIsIlsyLDVdXG5bNSwxMF1cblstNCwzXVxuWzAsM11cblstNCwtMV1cblstNyw3XVxuWy00LC0yXVxuWy01LC0yXVxuWy02LC0yXVxuWy02LC0zXVxuWzEsM11cblsxMCw1MF1cblstNTAsLTEwXVxuWy0xMSwtM11cblstNywtN10iXQ==).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
*F}F
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aF%7DF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%2C5%0A5%2C10%0A-4%2C3%0A0%2C3%0A-4%2C-1&debug=0)

Range is inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 12 bytes

```
[ [a,b] Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlJiXnloMYZfmZSbnp6QqFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoWHOZKhga/I9WiE7USYpVOLdAIfZ/cmJOjoLefwA)

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes 2 integers from the data stack as input and leaves one integer on the data stack as output.

- `[a,b]` Create a range from two integers. As you may have guessed, this is inclusive of both. All of the other words are also available, such as `[a,b)`.
- `Π` Find the product.

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 2.5 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
*(0.,
```

Uses inclusive range. [Try it at HBL Online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=KigwLiw_&a=Mgo1)

#### Explanation

After parentheses autocompletion, we have `'(*(0.,))`:

```
'(*(0.,))
'(      )  Define a function which returns
  *        the product of
   (0  )   the range from
     .     the first argument to
      ,    the second argument
```

Answer (score 2):

### PostScript, 27 bytes

```ps
{1 exch 1 4 1 roll{mul}for}
```

Anonymous function for inclusive product. Takes two inputs from the stack and leaves output on the stack.

(Usage: e.g., `5 10 {1 exch 1 4 1 roll{mul}for} exec =` prints `151200`.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvLilOLsosKNGtKACy//83VTA0UKg2VEitSM5QMFQwAeKi/Jyc6tzSnNq0/KJaoERqsoLt//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
rR
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

Calculates using the range [a, b] (because of bug). Explanation:

```
rR # Takes input as "a b"
 R # Range [a, b]
r  # Product
```

Comment: I am *very* sceptical about the 1.646-byte claim, which seems impossible as it isn't an integer number of bits.  
The size of a program for ```code-golf``` is the size of the program when it is stored.  Other sub-byte-token languages (like Nibbles or seven, for instance) implement ways to actually store the program in the indicated number of bytes/bits, and to do this can even 'cost' extra bits.
Simply declaring that - because you've elected to use only 96 characters - the code 'size' is a multiple of ```log256(96)``` isn't sufficient.

Comment: I think it would be fairer to score this with the smallest number of bytes/bits that you can *actually* store the program in (if the 'Fig' interpreter implements base-96 encoding of the program, and is also able to write/read this as binary bits, then this program could be 13 bits, which could even save you 0.17 bits).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen see [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61541693#61541693) chat conversation, both above and below. TL;DR it is possible to build an architecture that supports any `alog_256(n)` byte count. Also it's allowed by the rules

Comment: Why do you think it's 'allowed by the rules'?  On CGCC the 'rule' has typically been that languages are defined by their implementation, and that code size is it's actual size when stored.  So if you implement base-96 encoding and store the program then it could be Ok (although I suspect that you'll need bits to finally store it on any existing computer).  This is what Stax implements, for instance.  But not bothering to actually implement it and claiming a 'theoretical' information content seems like a shortcut.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=61338422#61338422), [currently accepted rule](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24296/107299)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I wasn't aware of the new rule/consensus.

Comment: How do I pass negative numbers to this program? It appears not to work with anything negative.

Comment: @Deadcode oops, thats a bug in my input evaluator. You can append `N<number>` for the same effect

Comment: `rRN-1N-4` still does not work, though. It returns `0` but should return `24`.

Comment: @Deadcode as in `N1`, not `N-1`. `N` is negation

Comment: I just realized, your post says it's using an exclusive range, but the program is actually using an inclusive range when I test it with Fig 0.3.2.

Comment: @Deadcode hmm, that must be a bug then. Or I can make it a "feature"

Answer (score 2):

## Regex  (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35 or later</sup></sub>), 128 bytes

`^(?!-x*,(?!-))(-())?+(?=(x*),-?(x*))(?=(x*),?(?=\3)(?=\4)(x*,-?|[^,]*)(x*))\5,?+(?=(\2(xx)*(?11))?)((?*x+)x?+)*(?*x+)(\5\7(,|$))`

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbNbttGEL7z1jdYM4W1Sy5TUY5TQzQtpLbQGHDsQJHRNJJD0NRKIkItCf7EihsDPfUBeu2llx7zQOmxT9LZH0qUpaKCuNydnfnmd2f5x5coS6pCPMEsir6MTCfJopx1nCPz5uvgyYRNY87Q69NBvxOcXp31g-vL82Hw0_nZ8CU6Mp7EPEqqCUPHUujp_MSI5mGOgmx0g3w0MH-4u_twe1D9_OnT2-H8-d0c_1WVU-fo66_vcW_PWVpUvAjBDiakZ-Oej5cWoU5PvEi97MFkfCCW42cEKLD_efSe3lhEso0PqRIdd_BySSzcc11AIxj3rKVNlj1b0MQUjw_H32P6-VtClB1_G9-QxyaaFFmZH2S26zX8K8o85jPh4JoWp0Bl4eJki-_EiHmJMpiWAcvzNMdRyosSyeBYC1YU4YwR9EtRTrrdCDjQ8THSZDGVdMYniYdyVlY5R673sIUp1lE6YRTdpmmCUn8aJoWAlWo03Khz-PzGMxD84inCMk_BjGmMQHNhhYNVoq9PX74YHFlEb1JUxPcsneKV4d_VlAY_IURqET-cop5yIkqrEnXRylEi3DOlGJIWdJH5yHkpbJogZY65SVbxmEKRzpUnq6AYD0bFi3jG2QQlKZ-pIeTFHcs9FW6xO3JtF4IgArb4FERhkoBZOhZ6FdwmafQBWRFFH9N4gqxJWIYQy1XkxBr5PsJi2yL7ayCiFdq2sk5qbN_4bU8KRs5JOp0WEPKPLCrTfHRkdcAcZye9fSPKQgO0nJan7RdoD03f28J36VAYc1wbmo2gABPGcUYcKaNCp6oSZZFv4l7X9GBm-5l6mXCwTuHZI0CvAPGgE5RQTMJ6gJ_BRHnVAIp5VpVCXAYQSgdZOavXi7CM5oEMl7WeK7ScFVVSUpV6T_eVN-fv-pIio0ERhBRcmJXzDQYrVWGqKwD6S61_kcUJw7oY37weDkgWPY0CMBYTqjHe9QdXwbA_eHV--WLYP6vJ_bfD_uVZ_wx91oRX1xfD84vzyz5F-9JK_da2tcn6LO3lcBR0OprnUo6arxEMfys-AazDkgXTPF0EWViWLOc4h_N2eX1xoQGaMtBESrYsIaz1zN-1r2HxFoqotbr4awjaOBF0V3E_BlCqkngRN0Ecl3gNpgnLyv9lyllU5UWc8p2MUu00zZHsc_erWobelcCdhFVLiTlV1Ui8-gzU6bknCOiiB-DWmLdA9b3vqiMpJZ6KHoaJ77cJEppjXjFvjQBKoQqFWtW1i_XeyqosLYBhQ3Mty9ldAPIUcUhSWKaxVqrLEtlCGKqTi8IIbwvMxUIwA8VGmB_Xpdb0Scg8UrY6m7LViu5KTW-bA4CxcMQiUByQ2QgXkG5tJWyK0UYuPJwL61yyA2QEXLYtrvYWbW3uPyAGl88u29aaF0pxQ-tuXQ9bfotoKPVSufNI-YItoKBwAVjKDylAUWvZEhGG1EtZoVCpFih1QdVx45uYEGpgUkmDj6AJBpeppEqD63SIK6HRGrtdLnN0C1H-4Cl2X1xU275tJg3989vvCDqwukq0eeoekIuVmGqhmydfNo1m_4PcyuJry_-648BcH7JGyIUnCvW4jfb3tYY9X3fIweBqEFxevXoxPH1JNkPUaHp1Zy_zijWwRVFsyGx4LRwUb-30jpv-4b-aIDRNxvDam-3mqhhWa9K8r9Qm9O_VB5ayHy5V9WX459cfO_TQOKRu23Ce0QOjDQ9MHNeQr47hHMrxeT0eGC4VzzPDOaAg1BGDS12F9y8)

Takes its input in unary, as two strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, with optional `-` signs on their left side, joined by a `,` delimiter, specifying an inclusive range. Returns the absolute value of its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

Additionally, capture group `\8` is set iff the result is negative. This value is taken from the last found possible match, if there is a conflict. But this regex always returns a consistent value in it within a run.

It takes two shortcuts:

- It assumes that the left argument is less than the right argument. This isn't necessary, and in fact removing this assumption wouldn't cost many bytes.
- If the two arguments have different signs, it doesn't even bother calculating anything, because the result will always be zero. This isn't a necessary shortcut (it worked without it), but it results in a *much* shorter regex.

```
^
(?!
    -x*,(?!-)           # If A is negative and B is nonnegative, let there
                        # be no possible matches, as the product would be 0.
)
(-())?+                 # \2 = set if A is negative
(?=
      (x*),             # \3 = abs(A); 
    -?(x*)              # \4 = abs(B)
)
(?=
    (x*),?(?=\3)(?=\4)  # \5 = what to skip so tail = the larger of A or B;
                        # tail = the larger of A or B
    (x*,-?|[^,]*)(x*)   # \7 = {the smaller of A or B} - \5
)
\5                      # tail = the larger of A or B
,?+                     # skip sign of B, if any
                        # First handle the range from larger inclusive to
                        # {smaller inclusive or 0 exclusive}
(?=
    (\2(xx)*(?11))?     # \8 = set iff the inclusive range is negative and has
                        #      an odd number of total members, i.e. the product
                        #      is negative
)
(
    (?*x+)              # Multiply the number of possibilities by tail.
    x?+                 # Advance by 1, but if already at the end, allow the
                        # loop to iterate once more so as to include 0 in
                        # the count.
)*                      # Iterate any number of times (cover the whole range)
(?*x+)                  # Multiply the number of possibilities by tail again
                        # at the end of the range.
(                       # Define subroutine (?11)
    \5\7                # Clamp the range at the smaller end.
    (,|$)               # Assert that we've reached the end.
)
```

As far as I know, this absolutely requires non-atomic lookaround (used here as `(?*`...`)` molecular lookahead) and -output, so it would not be portable to other regex engines currently – though it would be easily portable to  ECMAScript+`(?*)`.

Answer (score 1):

## golflua, 26 characters

```
\p(f,t)~@i=f+1,t f=f*i$~f$
```

Sample run:

```
Lua 5.2.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> \p(f,t)~@i=f+1,t f=f*i$~f$
> w(p(5, 10))
151200
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 66 bytes

Not great, but not too bad.

```
int d(int a,int b)=>Enumerable.Range(a,b-a).Aggregate((x,y)=>x*y);
```

Comment: I believe you need to include the `using System.Linq;` in order to use aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 49 Bytes

```
func f(a,b){t=a;for(x=a+1;x<b;x++)t=t*x;print(t)}
```

See expanded and run online with test case [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=22b13466dc99042c98503c3373515028)

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge, 51 bytes

```
 v          @.$<
v>&20p&30p1
>20g*20g:30g-!#^_1+20p
```

This can probably be optimised with some stack manipulation wizardry.
I went for put and get instructions instead. Might get back to it later on.
Also fails with negative numbers, since AFAIK Befunge doesn't handle them, instead looping back to maxint.

Answer (score 1):

## , 4 chars / 11 bytes

```
⨴⩥…ï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=%5B2%2C5%5D&code=%E2%A8%B4%E2%A9%A5%E2%80%A6%C3%AF)</kbd>

Creates an exclusive range from the array input, and multiplies everything in the resulting range. (Note that although the interpreter is using v2 of the language, this code still works in v1.)

Answer (score 1):

**Python 56**

```
a=input()
b=input()
print reduce(int.__mul__,range(a,b))
```

Comment: `print reduce(int.__mul__,range(input(),input()))` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Detour](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html), 3 bytes (non-competing)

```
rP.
```

[Try it online!](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/detour/master/interp.html?hex=clAu)

Same as [@quartata's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66203/41042), except `.` is required to output the result so it doesn't wrap back around to `r`.
This was not intended to be a golfing language, but the 1-character commands necessary to operate on a 2d grid make small challenges like this really short.

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript, <s>46 45 44</s> 29 bytes

Inclusive range

29 bytes version (anonymous function):

```
(a,b)->c=a;c*=++a while a<b;c
```

Equivalent to next JS code:

```
(function(a, b) {
    var c;
    c = a;
    while (a < b) {
        c *= ++a;
    }
    return c;
});
```

44 bytes version (prompt()):

```
alert [prompt()..prompt()].reduce (a,b)->a*b
```

45 bytes version:

```
alert [prompt()..prompt()].reduce((a,b)->a*b)
```

46 bytes version:

```
alert([prompt()..prompt()].reduce((a,b)->a*b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.3, 25 bytes

This is encoded in ISO 8859-1, and you can try it out [at the new IO page!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Assorted-Programming-Languages/reng.html)

```
ii#x:1+::xe)2(¿Bh$1¶a*¡n~
```

Is an inclusive range.

`ii` takes 2 inputs, and stores the second one (the maximum) in `x`. `:1+::` sets `a` to `a (a+1) (a+1) (a+1)`. `xe` sets the TOS to the equality of the counter `(a+1)` and `)2(` sets the STOS to `2`. `¿` pops two numbers and, if the TOS is true, the pointer moves STOS times. Otherwise, we just go forward. In the event that we have not reached the maximum, `Bh` goes back 11 units. `$` drops the excess counter from the TOS once we are done looping. `1¶` sets the default pop from an empty stack to `1`, so we can use a double-sided mirror loop to multiply everything. `a` is a one-sided mirror, and `*` multiplies values. `¡` mirrors until the stack's length is `1`. Once the length *is* 1, `n~` is met and outputs the result and exits the program.

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, <s>79</s> <s>43</s> 29 bytes

Hooray for auto use!

It's quite elegant, really. A lambda, that goes on the stack.

```
[ 1 - [a,b] 1 [ * ] reduce ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, 4 "bytes"

Uses the built-in Iterated Product Operator, which is entered from the keyboard by ctl-#.  Type k into the iterator and expression placeholders and then type the evaluation operator (=), giving a total of 4 "bytes" where one byte is taken to be the number of characters needed to enter an expression.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [Matricks](https://github.com/jediguy13/Matricks/), 24 bytes

Matricks is a new esolang I invented to deal with matrices. Run like: `python matricks.py [[<num1>,<num2>]]`

```
mg:;+c:1:g:1;-g:;;kp{};;
```

This is a simple answer. Matricks has a built-in for taking the product of an array, `p`, so all I need to do is make the range with the constructor, `m`

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 8 bytes

```
*/a+!b-a
```

Let's break this down:
k reads right-to-left, so:

`b-a` finds the difference between b and a, to give the number of numbers required

`!(b-a)` generates a list from 0 to (b-a), giving the range [0, (b-a))

`a+(!b-a)` adds a to each element of the list, to get the range [a, b)

`*/(a+!b-a)` applies multiplication over all elements of the list; `*` is the multiply operator, and `/` is the *over* adverb, which is like a map/reduce function, applying its left-hand argument over all elements of its right-hand argument.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket (scheme), 29 bytes

Functional programming woot

Apply applies a function to all elements of a list, and range creates a list ranging from a to b. The function being applied is *. Exclusive.

```
(λ(a b)(apply *(range a b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6 - 15 bytes

```
{[*] $^a..$^b}
```

Usage:

```
> {[*] $^a..$^b}(2,5)
120
```

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 33 bytes

Pretty simple looping program.

```forth
: f DUP ROT DO DUP I * LOOP ; f .
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/L0NDQJ)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (using external library) (31 bytes)

```
 (a,b)=>_.RangeTo(a,b).Product()
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/

Explanation of code: Anonymous method accepts low bound and high bound for range, and uses built in .Product method to produce the product for that range

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 56 Bytes

```
int f(int a,int b){var r=1;for(;a<b;a++)r*=a;return r;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 37 bytes

```
=PRODUCT(A2-ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,A2-A1)))
```

Data will be **a** in A1 and **b** in A2.

The above should be entered as an array formula (ctrl_shift_enter) in any other cell. The result is exclusive of **b**.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 8 bytes

Non-competing as the language postdates the challenge.

```
w-:&h;P#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@1@ua6WWYR2g/P//f10THQVdQwA)

Most of the code is building the range, as there is a builtin for finding the product (`P`).

```
w          \ Mirror stack, yielding [a, b, a]
 -         \ Pop (b, a) and push b - a, the difference
  :  ;     \ That many times do:
   &h      \   Push last item +1
      P#   \ Print product
```

The `w-:&h;` is essentially a long-winded binary range function, as Pushy only has unary range commands.

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
$\S=t$iUprP%..%/*U:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/XyUm2LZEJTO0oChAVU9PVV8r1Mrm/39DAy5TAA)

Takes input with order `b, a` from standard in.

**Ungolfed:** (Explanation to be added later)

```
      $ 
     \ S 
    = t $ 
   i U p r 
  P % . . % 
 / * U : <
```

---

**Previous Version (21 bytes):**

```
1\P\p$?Ud$=0%)(/P*U:<
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>a-b?a*f(a+1,b):b
```

Inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=product -p`, 16 bytes

```perl
$_=product$_..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ragKD@lNLlEJV5Pz8bu/38jLtN/@QUlmfl5xf91fX0yi0usrEJLMnNg6v7rFiQCJUz1DAwNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{[*] [...] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@786WitWIVpPTy9WwSG@9n9afpGCRk5mXmqxpkI1F2dxYqVCmkZNrn5MtJ6WfUysvp5rmKOPJlft/2gjHdNYBVs7BUMjA65oUx1DAwjPFMgHCuia6BiDBYBsAwQTKKxrCOYYmQAA)

Reduce the two inputs by range, then reduces by multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

Idea copied from the gs2 solution.

```
~,\>{*}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v04nxq5aq1br/38jBVMA)

### Explanation

```
~        # Dump the input,            e.g. 2 4
 ,       # Generate range from 0 to input: 2 [0 1 2 3 4]
  \      # Swap the stack                : [0 1 2 3 4] 2
   >     # Keep all those that are larger: [2 3 4]
    {*}* # Reduce by multiplication      : 24
```

Comment: The \ is not necessary and this does not work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 13 bytes

```
I::I-F$M:@*|h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39PKylPXTcXXykGrBsg1NFAwBQA)

Takes `b` then `a` from stdin, and uses inclusive range.

#### How it works

```
I::I-F$M:@*|h

I::I-           Take b, duplicate twice, take a, subtract
                [b b b-a]
     F     |    Repeat b-a times:
                [counter product]
      $M          Swap two, decrement counter
                  [product counter-1]
        :@        Duplicate, rotate 3
                  [counter-1 counter-1 product]
          *       Multiply
                  [counter-1 product']
            h   Print top as number and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 37 bytes

```cs
int f(int a,int b)=>a<b?a*f(a+1,b):b;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EIU0DRCbqgMgkTVu7RJsk@0StNI1EbUOdJE2rJOv/4UWZJak@mXmpGmkaRjqmmprWXMhCuiY6uoZAwf8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
f=(a,b)=>a>b||a*f(a+1,b)
```

or

```
f=(a,b)=>[...Array(b-a).keys()].map(i=>i+a).reduce((a,b)=>a*b)
```

## Python

```
f=lambda a,b:reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [5 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
ë|¶Ý║
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=KlwoPT5c&input=MiA1CjUgMTAKLTQgMwowIDMKLTQgLTE=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `*\(=>\`

```
  \           Fold with
*             Multiplication
    (         Begin expression
        \     Fold with
      =>      Inclusive range
          _   Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
    )         End expression; implied
```

The power of the fold operator, alternatives would be `*\=>?1` or `*\=>:}` (hypothetically, for some reason they are broken as of typing this. Trying to fix).

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 9 bytes

```
_.product
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stBd9QjwQiqUFrM4wCAIWw)

Accepts input as a `Range` object (inclusive or exclusive).

Answer (score 1):

## [O](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/), 12 bytes

```
[j:v,;]jv-+*
```

[Try it online!](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/W2o6diw7XWp2LSsq/Mwo1)

```
[j:v            Input and save to v without popping
    ,;          Range (1..n inclusive)
      ]jv-      Range end - start
          +     Add it vectorised with range
           *    Product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
Π…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yCRw3L/v//b/TfFAA)

```perl
   # arguments (² => second last argument & ⁰ => last argument) are implicit
 … # inclusive numeric range
Π… # product of list
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 10 bytes

```
00000000: 8bc8 f7eb 4b3b d97f f9c3                 ....K;....
```

Listing:

```
8B C8       MOV  CX, AX         ; running product start at a 
        MUL_LOOP: 
F7 EB       IMUL BX             ; multiply running product by b 
4B          DEC  BX             ; decrement b
3B D9       CMP  BX, CX         ; is b > a?
7F F9       JG   MUL_LOOP       ; if so, go forth and multiply
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Input *a* in `AX`, *b* in `BX`, inclusive of *b*.  Output to `AX`.

Tests using DOS DEBUG:

[image]

Note: before anyone asks... you cannot use `LOOPNZ` to decrement and compare *a* and *b*.
In the case where input *a* (`CX`) is `0`, it will end the loop before multiplying by the value of *a*, so no good.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>23</s> 11 bytes

```
&nRy[p*y,]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tL6gyukCrUie24P9/Uy5DAwA)

Let's try not doing it the "hard way" this time... :) The code generates a sequence of numbers on a stack, then works through the stack multiplying entries until there's only one number.  When the program ends, that single entry prints as a number automatically.

```
&nRy[p*y,]p  - 
&n           - read in the two numbers
  R          - generate a range of numbers (inclusive)
   y[p y,]p  - as long as the stack size is 2 or more
      *      - multiply the top two entries
```

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 23 bytes

```
dsc[lc1+dsc*lclb>g]dsgx
```

Takes input with the upper bound (inclusive) in register `b` and the lower bound (inclusive) at the top of the stack. Returns the answer at the top of the stack.

Uses register `c` a lot, so removing that would save a lot of bytes. Basically it's just a for-loop.

Run as:

```
{UPPER_BOUND}sb{LOWER_BOUND} dsc[lc1+dsc*lclb>g]dsgx p
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```
proc f(a,b,c:var int)=
  c=1;for i in a..b:c*=i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY39QuK8pMV0jQSdZJ0kq3KEosUMvNKNG25FBSSbQ2t0_KBfKCIQqKeXpJVspZtJlSbKkgll0KirRGXQpKtKRdQtQEXyBSFJB2FZE2u1OSMfIVkiGKYXQA)

All arguments must be variables, passed by reference. Return value in third parameter, original value ignored. As usual with Nim, not very small byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 12 bytes

```
{⍺×.-1-⍳⍵-⍺}
```

Explanation on example of arguments 2 and 5:

```
⍳⍵-⍺ ⍝ Array of numbers from 1 to ⍵-⍺: 1 2 3
1-   ⍝ Substract the array from 1: 0 ¯1 ¯2
⍺×.- ⍝ Substract the array from ⍺: 2 3 4
     ⍝ Then reduce by multiplication, of course
```

Mathematical justification: ⍺-(1-x) = (⍺-1)+x

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5  bytes (5 nibbles)

```
`*>$,
```

Input is `(a,b]`  (so `5 10` represents the range `6 7 8 9 10`).

```
    ,      # range from 1..(implicit) arg1
  >        # drop first      elements
   $       #            arg2
`*         # product
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Knight, 34 bytes

```
;;;;=xP=yP=p 1W<=x+1x+2y=p*p-x 1Op
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKWyNbCeSYKu2bMsUyUKKWgIsJJcP4EuELIPqZFknybws4f56rrvnRSPb5C53ywfLmnm6p/uZnu4eE/ZvwvD7qzgNk@U0GhXlNF68vh03zZEkvq4NheVjFq2A8ji9qQ2V8VxgptEsTiOWJCxZpDf00dSjH08@fWBu9Xrx8Zx51evf9s/ZbvV6ePKO/Vq9nn9ibgU@PL4wsCefjg3op5MP@xe/WwVnFn602b/cX7ie3b@AZcVkeBvkzOaVgIkCW7WK8ZjtVnMnB59xMoVJ8ugbw@@j0QoGlyEMugmYJOEIrGHenp4eEwg/9sjJAfpmGHL@XgBA3rD1LkiWEeeX6YQ3m@QH7MrlxD9vHZweWt@H8Oc/nPmPZ37G3M8j/6HrPnS9Rz@zs/4Dc0@z7xyAraGQtUE4CubMRy3DZhOWyoK8iCzOnpqNOC1ZPGw2YJSW7TF7tkxDGCHhEN7LedYrsvTSm/hPTs95Bh2NGNQRHp4ODrx5g@rjjN3fxmVUZEEYNRvwPYksGAdxS5jRY62r8iq9ml3l7On5cmLxwasWJ1Ma8YxZ2lqfdV51OBMq1OgWjF6lMNztihGwsxElRWQOPAtzwtso/AebLXKWLufXUV5Ie5gVF9P4Ji6VVlgd3XF72iPxtJnrsC6zpeXdLmd91nE6sARaGnOWR@UyT5kKFCFGsTJcteEuyOPgOomUFWBEsriPciuE9ZQh7Ns3powL6S0kIr50uKQn3uB67Ls92CNfD69Yh0dPhihA0ukys3BLmeS0z@Bt3WCRCAqhTZhx1elUNrU6YtNAGDzQRjFQAokDvoNlWVCUrLyNQFmQlwCWG2ArRnFDQ46eKGON8/SisfDpctroRkUGmY@hW8aLFMzGiHUmYFqoGCmWWYaEcxVVasSk34w/oN0gG3WoUM5SiGNIYhi50nLByseOPuli4BAHMKENMJGhmSrIKAcKVy20G00NkmQRWrtOz@XoIA5rJ8jBdJkkQf5oOlrtz7mxPWcdbRktKOWX6Yo0LeHiEjIpbPJ0/@Dtu69/bB3/dmo4bKq9jjfq9db1btUUvz@6eEFjGeWkMkin7J/LQL2i2jtziZ31JQQB7zuai6MNXJDwbl24jnmmVJkvU9yhoUzEdrkoLJUr6QBAaJdxyGj2ejm79HYn0g6x0W1KD9qAIoNjVc4sgIL/20kybam8Q4Woh0pWFcCh0ApEiRPr13Aj5u7U/UTnMRb3WKvMl1ELYlCPY0jC@CyADIITLYysVkUC@om@y1pEdHx5u1gkMHNdZ@BFXyu3fuSQ/fMemWZer5mZoI3pX2ojBG25SBLLNLXHnB5UiP/B5HTNZKzCH/bPTnpYi0WgwevRpes4DoQTuAKv6q2I/4y@lAwfQyNGDW@RAXjr4YdHnzu@q0o6Zjis6vigT088dgBweHR8YLMZJMdhQ4e2XA/TcBhkvSRKqQMwuFKtkuAMzt1LZKwKYm3C0oYFx4qpl4BaPCIuhlBUYpzUeSOcZys7QCTFkyqFIE3xBJcp7uMyvLVsYGatswKOmPwLsU519jsDhqsIgI@EYm8GWZi3ySmpXnaHtZDlQ6rCFYJa0DLH0kVd6OWEP1VhBg0U5Xax8DksXNedQ8azeNt5mOFfhTwDJGgVHN1EZQINpNWmvWzjDmGJnMYpH8Yzy6L9xIYgvM3Rlh7EKedim31nuNFWeHBqA8R6B2I90TliNpCEDJW9SJLMnZWVbyt/BF7PvKtmUNKkWGO@AgajAeLPzxZZlFrGwr1W3qJWAazy56JSQjz6nrP7K43L5sISHckMTJ@iU9DCQcj2sL8DOPQO9IZrwNIqvCwYZF2fWiE8sYDkkm7QQ2sR1ajB9pln9iwVjZUnf4An0QO0cXja1/zcqu063RO2MJOtAY/XwgNWSeq8GPDfOgPZJ24IZJ35ZAVqnVBbbGEN4qoIjce7vGos19KhEr2g5tDaLlCwfhjWhYFOaH3MdSGT8lYFVRNYXqIglWpfKmGyZpk7IHOLZOG0YgEPhrj4IGliP2vUsXabLlf9PkInos29ona7oczafm0XYI8Fb5ypo5Yb5i/LQu2@jgnR6wmDutogypOQLzElY2gZ2yO66UZ9t8VNFdHQ9zMVS57Yc@x/6TCIDSAUDuMp95WXHt8cqmFQqofsOt1uRRNX31EXh260R89S5gjpV38tOo1ox1a9bq8Qsqvd2cDCannewIO9xoPY100szDe4ZhPGN5WQANQgizKk37mCSx6Chv0@6ZNEUclc3WjBaFk7/W9@SMybzcRs/1Boe7PQ34nNmkPi6kBjnunlUNIuWPdZ39UsExaod@Gc9V04Y64J9n4SPYL0WMP6PkJp3YEacRTlRLQ3diTXHqd2xfaJ/@bqgaBJcgXuCJRgscTAd7wy3EZ51ClYuoAeOk7KOGX3wSPwxqYLuJOW0U2Ug0y2SKO0jAO8RcBJXrD7iN0GdxEApSKEl2wepEsIn8fXOIreXSPjQAUxUSyTEn80oMV1wlOQvolRS65QZsppyIp61Pcy0nnZEA0b1VAO3c@DBGvjI3idTpNoyr5WZn/VWp7wm2jMjEUqZ8aorN9X75zgDQm1DdOfdR4cUbCuFD5MerW86Nez4h4zD//IPAYoOpC/wbWZAOyxWqNIgz1mZEPU4QhJVXI9UQcQu@VDtTG6oDEcSgytxXQxYPNoHmYYZikbf937f10Z/wWujJUrWxt88aUv0pW9l9kXq24wGaf3WA3gaYSnCujWJjurF@2eyjymAm1eu0p/6Mum2rBnSspUouW//TfyMgcZarT8sDMw0bU2dxXrV1m3Pv3TFxnV21Y3GcQ1arcZnQoJgxonfk3aSJMogYhuV4sJkz@De@JXL7PRrHnHzN5Fih3Vu3aEGvJ73mDHoOW9uDL4RofVNQvQ@h0plRePnj4LO7WG9kIQvaJ0uFryvE0lb4frPsDT0rs0@B8aIjQMn7gVoW7@dTtk9kYeeIirdl1skqhBEPEvJulBiK48CbD6NJoFkCTBM9VhxilMxlP6ESkISyhTne2wgz0njnD2wi0WlekaCN2g/CFhHsQpNqssyG/CHim1bfh@x/HnKrpf4r90LIesqV/jnr//0nSdfwM)

Comment: You should shave a two bytes off by doing `=pT` (you'd have to not make it the last assignment, though, as it'd conflict with the `W`), and then doing `=p*-xTp`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 12 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∏&..&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?6A1VPX)

Answer (score 1):

## HP48 User RPL,

Input is `a` and `b` in the stack.

```
«
  'X'
  DUP
  4 UNROLL
  UNROT
  1 SEQ
  ∏LIST
»
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
ŘΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6IxzC/7/N@MyAgA)

Takes inputs as `b, a` separated by newlines

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 29 bytes

```
&1$:&v
v?=&:<|.!02$*@+1:
>~n;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJjEkOiZ2XG52Pz0mOjx8LiEwMiQqQCsxOlxuPn5uOyIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiI1IDEwIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes

```
×´⊢+↕∘-
```

Thanks to @ConorO'Brien

[Try it](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkMOXwrTiiqIr4oaV4oiYLQoKNeKAvzEw4oC/M+KAvzPigL8wIEbCqCAy4oC/NeKAv8KvNOKAvzDigL/CrzQ=)

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes

```
{×´+↕¬}
```

[Try it](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHvDl8K08J2VqCvihpXwnZWpwqzwnZWofQoKMuKAvzXigL/CrzTigL8w4oC/wq80IEbCqCA14oC/MTDigL8z4oC/M+KAv8KvMQ==)

Uses an inclusive range. This is the first thing I've ever written in BQN and I couldn't figure out how to make it tacit for the life of me. Any tips appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm not great at BQN, but I think you have this for 7b (arguments reversed, exclusive at one end): `×´⊢+↕∘-` ([Try it](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkMOXwrTiiqIr4oaV4oiYLQoKNeKAvzEw4oC/M+KAvzPigL8wIEbCqCAy4oC/NeKAv8KvNOKAvzDigL/CrzQ=))

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 5 bytes

`â-º+P`

solution for exclusive range

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=4i26K1A=&in=MiA1)

### Explantion

```
â-º+P ; implicit input, stack: [hi low]>
â     ; under -> stack: [low hi low]>
 -    ; subtraction -> stack: [low hi-low]>
  º   ; zero-based range
   +  ; add low to zero based range giving range [low,...hi-1]
    P ; product
      ; implicit output
```

---

## Itr, [7 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=4i0xK7orUA==&in=MiA1)

solution for inclusive range

`â-1+º+P`

#### [2 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=qFA=&in=MiA1) using the new range built-in

`¨P`

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 76 B

Utilizing a recursive definition of the product you may arrive at one of the following solutions:

```pascal
function p(a,b:integer):integer;begin if a=b then p:=a else p:=a*p(a+1,b)end
```

```pascal
function p(a,b:integer):integer;begin if a<b then p:=a*p(a+1,b)else p:=a end
```

```pascal
function p(a,b:integer):integer;begin if b>a then p:=a*p(a+1,b)else p:=a end
```

**86 B (standard iterative solution)**:
Pascal’s `for`-loop limits are inclusive (just like the \$\prod\$ and \$\sum\$ limits in mathematics are inclusive, too).
In Standard Pascal (as specified by ISO standard 7185) `for`-loop counters must fulfill certain eligibility criteria (some dialects may be more lenient with that).
Therefore a new variable is declared:

```pascal
function p(a,b:integer):integer;var i:integer;begin for i:=a+1 to b do a:=a*i;p:=a end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
≔¹ξＮαＮβＦ…αβ«≔×ξιξ»Ｉξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RDO8/te79n3bmNIGLT@z3LHjUsO7fx3KZDq4GSh6ef23cOqODQ7vd7Vp7b9/@/EZcpAA)

### Verbose

```
Assign 1 x
InputNumber a; InputNumber b; 
for(Range a b){
    Assign (Times x i) x
} 
Print Cast x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/BUKGCyzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIIdFaAZmbZK3AlZZfpBGUmJeeqpCokKRZzaUABFDdGiGZuanFChUKmZpAc2oVuAKKMvNKFJwTi0sUKv7/N@Iy/a@rW5ZalJRfnApkpaRC2JlplQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
Ip
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWizwLlhQnJRdDuQsWG3GZQpgA) Uses \$[a..b]\$ (the inclusive range).

**Explanation:** `p`roduct of the `I`nclusive range between the two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 9 bytes

```ruby
:!~|:/&:*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK60U62qs9NWstCD8FQUKbtFGOqaxEO6CBRAaAA)