# Construct the Identity Matrix

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, linear-algebra, binary-matrix

The challenge is very simple. Given an integer input `n`, output the `n x n` identity matrix. The identity matrix is one that has `1`s spanning from the top left down to the bottom right. You will write a program or a function that will return or output the identity matrix you constructed. Your output may be a 2D array, or numbers separated by spaces/tabs and newlines.

**Example input and output**

```
1: [[1]]
2: [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
3: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
4: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
5: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

1
===
1

2
===
1 0
0 1

3
===
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

etc.
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: _Given an integer input n ..._ -- I assume you mean a natural number?

Answer (score 26):

## MATL, 2 bytes

```
Xy
```

A translation of my Octave answer.

[Try it online.](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WHk&input=Mw&args=)

A 4 byte version with no built-ins (thanks to Luis Mendo):

```
:t!=
:     take input n and a generate row array [1,2,...n]
 t    duplicate
  !   zip
   =  thread compare over the result
```

Comment: It must have been difficult, to translate this very sophisticated code :D

Comment: @flawr You have no idea. This is truly my masterpiece.

Comment: [This seems vaguely familiar...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66203/31957) ;)

Comment: Now I see why you were asking! :-D

Comment: Without builtins: `:t!=`

Answer (score 20):

### TI-BASIC, 2 bytes

```
identity(Ans
```

Fun fact: The shortest way to get a list `{N,N}` is `dim(identity(N`.

Here's the shortest way without the builtin, in 8 bytes:

```
randM(Ans,Ans)^0
```

`randM(` creates a random matrix with entries all integers between -9 and 9 inclusive (that sounds oddly specific because it is). We then take this matrix to the 0th power.

Comment: "*that sounds oddly specific because it is*" TI-BASIC is weird. O_o

Comment: Hell yes. TI-BASIC. +1

Comment: isn't the shortest way to get a list `{N,N}`, umm, `{N,N}`?

Comment: @Cyoce No; `dim(` and `identity(` are each one byte because TI-BASIC is tokenized.

Answer (score 18):

## Julia, <s>9</s> 3 bytes

```
eye
```

This is just a built-in function that accepts an integer `n` and returns an `nxn Array{Float64,2}` (i.e. a 2D array). Call it like `eye(n)`.

Note that submissions of this form are acceptable per [this policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/on-scoring-builtin-functions).

Comment: I see what you did there! Nice one!

Comment: This also works in [Math.JS](https://a-ta.co/math/eye(3))

Answer (score 18):

## APL, 5 bytes

```
∘.=⍨⍳
```

This is a monadic function train that accepts an integer on the right and returns the identity matrix.

[Try it here](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u2218.%3D%u2368%u2373%20%u22C4%20f%204&run)

Answer (score 16):

### Python 2, 42 bytes

```python
lambda n:zip(*[iter(([1]+[0]*n)*n)]*n)[:n]
```

An anonymous function, produces output like `[(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]`,

First, creates the list `([1]+[0]*n)*n`, which for `n=3` looks like

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Using the [zip/iter trick](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2012/12/that-grouping-by-zipiter-trick-explained.html) `zip(*[iter(_)]*n` to make groups of `n` gives

```
[(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0)]
```

Note that the `1` comes one index later each time, giving the identity matrix. But, there's an extra all-zero row, which is removed with `[:n]`.

Comment: Damn that zip/iter trick is ingenious

Answer (score 14):

## Octave, <s>10</s> 4 bytes

```
@eye
```

Returns an anonymous function that takes a number `n` and returns the identity matrix.

Comment: `@eye` is sufficient.

Comment: @flawr Thanks, I knew there was a way to do it like that but I always forget :P

Comment: `eye` produces the identity matrix in a lot/some numerically oriented languages.

Comment: What does the `@` do?

Comment: @Cyoce `@` is the "function handle operator", it works like a `lambda` and also as a reference to a particular function, so for instance, `@(x)x.^2` is the squaring function and `@sqrt` is a reference to the square root function. You can read more about that [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html?s_tid=srchtitle)

Answer (score 12):

## R, 4 bytes

```r
diag
```

When given a matrix, `diag` returns the diagonal of the matrix. However, when given an integer `n`, `diag(n)` returns the identity matrix.

[Try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=q3aeHVGZ)

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, 4 bytes

```
R=€R
```

Doesn't use a built-in. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uj3igqxS&input=&args=NA)

#### How it works

```
R=€R    Main link. Input: n

R       Range; yield [1, ..., n].
   R    Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 =€     Compare each.
        This compares each element of the left list with the right list, so it
        yields [1 = [1, ..., n], ..., n = [1, ..., n]], where comparison is
        performed on the integers.
```

Comment: This code is unacceptably long.

Comment: @flawr Twice the length of the shortest one. That's indeed an unusual encounter.

Comment: @flawr Yes, and no shorter than [J](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70378/43319). FAIL!

Comment: In modern versions of Jelly, `=þ` is two bytes, *and* makes fun of the longer answers.

Comment: @Lynn That's *still* twice as long as the shortest oneS.

Answer (score 10):

## J, 4 bytes

```
=@i.
```

This is a function that takes an integer and returns the matrix.

Comment: I think you can do it in 3: `=i.`

Comment: @SamElliott that doesn't work. For example, `(=i.) 10` => `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>68</s> <s>62</s> 52 bytes

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to a neat trick from @Neil*

```
x=>[...Array(x)].map((_,y,x)=>x.map((_,z)=>+(y==z)))
```

Trying a different approach than @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ's. Could possibly be improved.

Comment: This was exactly what I wrote before I scrolled down to find out that you'd beaten me to it.

Comment: So, in response to your challenge, I give you the (in hindsight) obvious `x=>[...Array(x)].map((_,y,x)=>x.map((_,z)=>+(y==z)))` for a saving of 10 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Thanks a lot! I'll mention that it's your trick in the answer.

Comment: `x=>[...Array(x)].map((_,y,x)=>x.map(_=>+!y--))`

Comment: @l4m2 May be it will be better to post your own answer because the user is inactive

Answer (score 8):

**Haskell, <s>43</s> 37 bytes**

```
f n=[[0^abs(x-y)|y<-[1..n]]|x<-[1..n]]
```

Pretty straightforward, though I think one can do better (without a language that already has this function built in, as many have done).

Edit: dropped some bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen

Comment: You can cheat the `fromEnum` as `sum[1|x==y]`.

Comment: pretty sure you can remove the space in `fromEnum (y==x)`

Comment: @xnor One byte shorter than that: `0^abs(x-y)`.

Comment: @xnor Oh, you just used `0^(x-y)^2` yourself in another answer, even shorter.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Yes, seeing your comment was nice timing :)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
XRm0Q1Q
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XRm0Q1Q&input=5&debug=0)

Creating a matrix of zeros and replacing the diagonal elements with ones.

Comment: You can save one byte by removing the final `Q`

Comment: @jim Thanks, but that would actually be not allowed. The feature (implicit Q at the end) was implemented after the challenge was posted.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 48

Saved 1 byte thanks to sp3000.

I love challenges I can solve in one line. Pretty simple, build a line out of 1 and 0 equal to the length of the int passed in. Outputs as a 2d array. If you wrap the part after the : in `'\n'.join()`, it'll pretty print it.

```
lambda x:[[0]*i+[1]+[0]*(x+~i)for i in range(x)]
```

Comment: `x-i-1 -> x+~i`

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 25

Credit to @randomra and @Martin for extra golfing.

```
\B.
 0
+`(.*) 0$
$0¶0 $1
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XEIuCiAwCitgKC4qKSAwJAokMMK2MCAkMQ&input=MTExMQ)

Note this takes input as a unary.  If this is not acceptable, then decimal input may be given as follows:

## Retina, 34

```
.+
$0$*1
\B.
 0
+`(.*) 0$
$0¶0 $1
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJDAkKjEKXEIuCiAwCitgKC4qKSAwJAokMMK2MCAkMQ&input=MTA)

Comment: ...whoa. Retina is becoming powerful as a language for more than regex.

Comment: @ETHproductions yes, though this is answer pretty much all regex substitution.  The only special thing is the use of `$*0` to replace a number n with n `0`s.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 54 bytes

```
(#)=replicate
f n=map(\x->x#0++[1]++(n-x-1)#0)[0..n-1]
```

`f` returns the identity matrix for input n. Far from optimal.

Comment: You can save a handful of bytes using a list comprehension instead of a `map` call.

Answer (score 6):

## Lua, <s>77 75</s> 65 bytes

```
x,v=z.rep,io.read()for a=1,v do print(x(0,a-1)..'1'..x(0,v-a))end
```

Well, I'm not sure if lua is the best language for this with the two period concatenation... But hey, there's a shot at it. I'll see if there's any improvements to be made.

**EDIT:**

I figured something out on accident which I find rather odd, but, it works.

In Lua, everyone knows you have the ability to assign functions to variables. This is one of the more useful CodeGolf features.

This means instead of:

```
string.sub("50", 1, 1) -- = 5
string.sub("50", 2, 2) -- = 0
string.sub("40", 1, 1) -- = 4
string.sub("40", 2, 2) -- = 0
```

You can do this:

```
s = string.sub
s("50", 1, 1) -- = 5
s("50", 2, 2) -- = 0
s("40", 1, 1) -- = 4
s("40", 2, 2) -- = 0
```

But wait, Lua allows some amount of OOP. So you could potentially even do:

```
z=""
s = z.sub
s("50", 1, 1) -- = 5
s("50", 2, 2) -- = 0
s("40", 1, 1) -- = 4
s("40", 2, 2) -- = 0
```

That will work as well and cuts characters.

Now here comes the weird part. You don't even need to assign a string at any point. Simply doing:

```
s = z.sub
s("50", 1, 1) -- = 5
s("50", 2, 2) -- = 0
s("40", 1, 1) -- = 4
s("40", 2, 2) -- = 0
```

Will work.

---

So you can visually see the difference, take a look at the golfed results of this:

**Using string.sub (88 characters)**

```
string.sub("50", 1, 1)string.sub("50", 2, 2)string.sub("40", 1, 1)string.sub("40", 2, 2)
```

**Assigning string.sub to a variable (65 characters)**

```
s=string.sub s("50", 1, 1)s("50", 2, 2)s("40", 1, 1)s("40", 2, 2)
```

**Assigning string.sub using an OOP approach (64 characters)**

```
z=""s=z.sub s("50", 1, 1)s("50", 2, 2)s("40", 1, 1)s("40", 2, 2)
```

**Assigning string.sub using a.. nil approach? (60 characters)**

```
s=z.sub s("50", 1, 1)s("50", 2, 2)s("40", 1, 1)s("40", 2, 2)
```

If someone knows why this works, I'd be interested.

Comment: The "z.rep" line is breaking on mine.  I'm betting there should be a z='' somewhere?  A shorter variant of z=''z.rep would just be ('').rep .

You can also use the cmdline ... for reading input, and widdle the bytecount down to 57 as follows:
z='0'for i=1,...do print(z:rep(i-1)..1 ..z:rep(...-i))end

Comment: I found someone suggesting ("").rep before, but I was unable to get it to work. It'd always error out. Maybe my interpreter is the problem here.
I'm struggling to find any documentation on this command line input, do you know where it can be found?

Answer (score 6):

## C,  <s>59 or 59</s>  56 or 56

Two versions of identical length.

3 bytes saved due to suggestion from anatolyg: `(n+1)` --> `~n`

Iterates `i` from `n*n-1` to zero. Prints a 1 if i%(n+1) is zero, otherwise 0. Then prints a newline if `i%n`=0 otherwise a space.

```
i;f(n){for(i=n*n;i--;)printf(i%n?"%d ":"%d\n",!(i%~n));}

i;f(n){for(i=n*n;i--;)printf("%d%c",!(i%~n),i%n?32:10);}
```

Comment: `n+1` is too dull. Use `~n` instead!

Comment: Thanks! I should have spotted that, because it occured to me when I looked at NBZ's challenge today.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C. What does `i;` do?

Comment: @Cyoce `i;` just declares the variable `i`. In C you always have to declare a variable before using it, indicating the type so the compiler knows how much memory to allocate. With the GCC compiler, if you don't specify a type it is assumed to be `int`.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt thanks. Since it didn't specify a type I was unsure if it was a declaration

Comment: You can take 1 more byte off of the second one, since tabs are allowed, you can replace 32, with 9.

Answer (score 6):

## Mata, 4 bytes

```
I(3)
```

**Output**

```
[symmetric]
       1   2   3
    +-------------+
  1 |  1          |
  2 |  0   1      |
  3 |  0   0   1  |
    +-------------+
```

Mata is the matrix programming language available within the Stata statistical package. I(n) creates an identity matrix of size n*n

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. This is a good answer; (ab)use of built-ins is great for golfing. I noticed that your answer is actually 1 byte: `I`, and the other 3 bytes are just calling the function. That would make your answer one of the lowest on this challenge! :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>206</s> <s>170</s> 162 bytes

```
(([{}])){({}<>(())<><(({})<{({}()(<>)<>)}{}>)>)}{}(({}<><(())>)){({}()<({[()]<({}()<({}<>((((()()()()){}){}){})((()()()()){}){})<>>)>}{})>)<>((()()()()()){})<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xCsMwDER/527I2O0Q5DuMB2colIYMXYW/XZFtSodKAqHT6en4tNe1Pc/2jgCK90o6vMsAUibkQA0JhCwldu/G2TCdGlZbd6DgBaz6DhOVwZVM3Ko/TZbYpHJ8@W3XXpagiEds@w0)

Answer (score 5):

## [K6](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 1 [byte](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
=
```

`=` is exactly this

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/k-ok#@29r@v8/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
Uo £Z®¥X|0
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VW8go1qupVh8MH19ILc=&input=NQ==) Note: this version has a few extra bytes to pretty-print the output.

```
Uo £Z®¥X|0    // Implicit: U = input integer
Uo £          // Create the range [0..U). Map each item X and the full array Z to:
    Z®        //  Take the full array Z, and map each item Z to:
      ¥X|0    //   (X == Z) converted to a number. 1 for equal, 0 for non-equal.
              // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 4):

## K, 7 bytes

```
t=\:t:!
```

Take the equality cross product of two vectors containing [0,n).

In action:

```
  t=\:t:!3
(1 0 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1)
  t=\:t:!5
(1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 8 bytes

```
mmsqdkQQ
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mmsqdkQQ&input=5&debug=0).

Comment: I must say, it's highly unusual that the Pyth answer is *four times* longer than the shortest answer...

Comment: Hrm, this was the best I was able to get that looks 100% valid, but I did find `qRRQQ` which seems to work except you get `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`, however fixing this afaik requires using three bytes for `sMM` which doesn't help...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I also found qRRQQ. I've tried a number of other programs, and none of them were shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
IdentityMatrix
```

**Test case**

```
IdentityMatrix[4]
(* {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 35 Bytes

without using IdentityMatrix

```
Table[Boole[i==j],{i,1,#},{j,1,#}]&
```

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript, 40

```js
f=
n=>'0'.repeat(n).replace(/./g,"$`1$'\n")

I.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML=f(+I.value)
I.oninput()
```

```html
<input id=I value=5>
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(n,x=1:n)+!x%o%x-x^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6fC1tAqT1NbsUI1X7VCtyLO6H@ahqnmfwA)

For pure fun, just another attempt at a non-built-in R solution. Uses the shortcut `%o%` version of the `outer` function.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
°¨œÙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IZDK45OPjzz/39TAA)

Unique permutations of (10^input)[0:-1]

Comment: Nice answer! An alternative is `LDδQ`, for 4 bytes as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 7 + 1 = 8 bytes

Replace all ☺s with `\x01` and `\xad` with a soft hyphen, or use the [online interpreter](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IQEhWMKtAWo). (Turn pretty output on for one byte.)

```
!☺!X\xad☺j
  !X       eye
    \xad☺   take one argument
         j  (the input)
!☺         get the data
           implicit printing
```

Probably more interesting, a solution without a builtin is 11 + 1 = 12 bytes

```
ZXZyjjdP=Sn
  Zyjj       create a matrix of width = height = j (input)
ZX    d      matrix map
        =Sn  if x-marker is y-marker
       P     as a number
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
n=>eval("for(a=[],i=0;i<n;i++){a[i]=[];for(j=0;j<n;)a[i][j]=+(i==j++)};a")
```

Can be improved, probably.

### If `n=0` isn't necessary... 70 bytes

```
n=>eval("for(a=[i=0];i<n;i++)for(a[i]=[j=0];j<n;)a[i][j]=+(i==j++);a")
```

Comment: Since the zero by zero identity matrix is of questionable existence, `a=[],i=0` could be golfed to `a=[i=0]`.

Comment: I feel like one could argue that your other version also does not appropriately address `n=0`, since it outputs `[]`, not `[[]]`; open for interpretation, though ...

Comment: Based on [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/73111), I think you could even drop the `+(...)`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech True. this challenge predates that consensus tho

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.5 with NumPy - <strike>57</strike> <strike>49</strike> 30 bytes

```
import numpy
numpy.identity
```

NumPy.identity takes in an integer, n, and returns a n by n identity matrix. This answer is allowable via [this policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/on-scoring-builtin-functions/7206#7206).

Comment: Actually I believe`import numpy\nnumpy.identity`is a [legitimate answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7206/31625).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MorganThrapp! And @FryAmTheEggman, you mean that my answer could just be `import numpy\nnumpy.identity()` which is 30 bytes?

Comment: I got so confused by \nnumpy lol... This would also be valid, @FryAmTheEggman, no? `from numpy import identity`. 26 bytes.

Comment: Also, see my answer something [similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70942/49161)

Comment: @Ogaday I don't think that is correct, the line you've given does not evaluate to a function. You would need to do `from numpy import identidy\nidentity` (in which case it would be shorter to use `*` instead of the specific builtin)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ok, I see what you're getting at, in which case the solution would be from `from numpy import*;identity` at 27 bytes. According to the wording of the link, however, I think just importing satisfies the conditions: before the code is executed, there is no function "identity" in the scope, after execution there is. Think of importing as assignment: look at the language [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt): they both bind variables to names in the local scope.

Comment: Similar to how `s=sum` is valid even though it doesn't evaluate to anything because it binds a value to new name in the local scope. I'm open to contradiction on this though, because the logical conclusion, therefore, is that `from numpy import*` is a valid solution, because it populates the namespace with all of the names from numpy... Which I don't think is a particularly satisfying solution.

Comment: @Ogaday The piece of code in the answer that is the actual function to be run (usually the last line) should evaluate to a function, and thus be assignable and callable. Simply importing a function doesn't result in a function object that can be assigned and called.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 60 bytes

```java
n->{int[][]i=new int[n][n];for(;n-->0;)i[n][n]=1;return i;};
```

Creates a 2D array and replaces elements where row and column are equal with `1`.

Comment: You don't have to add the trailing semicolon to the byte-count for Java lambda answers.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
{,_ff=}
```

This is a code block that pops an integer from the stack and pushes a 2D array in return.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=OSwxPiAgICBlIyBbMSAuLi4gOF0KeyxfZmY9fQolOnAgICAgIGUjIE1hcC4gUHJpbnQgZWFjaC4&input=)

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```
/$/,say map$`==$_|0,@%for@%=1..<>
```

Thanks to [Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel) for saving 6 bytes

Running with the `-E` perlrun:

```
$ echo 3 | perl -E'@%=1..<>;$a=$_,say map{$a==$_|0}@%for@%'
100
010
001
```

Comment: Golfing a bit more: ``/$/,say map$`==$_|0,@%for@%=1..<>`` or even better `//,say map$'==$_|0,@%for@%=1..<>` but like that you can't put it in single quotes anymore

Comment: @TonHospel Wow thats cool, thanks. The later would require the use of `print` instead of say, because `-E` is only free on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 50 bytes

```
f=function(n)matrix(c(1,rep(c(rep(0,n),1),n-1)),n)
```

Without using diag(), because I started coding without checking if there was a command for that... Also, I like my solution, despite being way too long.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPMzexpCizQiNZw1CnKLVAw0AnT1NTJw9I/k/TMNb8DwA "R – Try It Online") by abusing recycling (but gives a warning about non-multiple of length in recycling)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```r
function(n)+outer(1:n,1:n,"==")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPUzu/tCS1SMPQKk8HhJVsbZU0/6dpGBpo/gcA)

*Thanks to Kirill L. for -1 byte*

Alternative to [Ivanneke's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129069/67312), but obviously far longer than just plain old `diag`.

Comment: You can swap `*1` for `+`: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPUzu/tCS1SMPQKk8HhJVsbZU0/6dpGBpo/gcA)

Comment: @KirillL. ah, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

Because built-ins are no fun!

```matlab
@(x)(k=1:x)==k'
@(x)~~diag(1:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/zdZBo0JTI9vW0KpC09Y2W50rHSxSV5eSmZiuARL9n6ZhpKmTpmGsqZMOYqUDWf8B)

The first one creates a vector from `1, 2, .. x`, and compares it to itself transposed, expanding it to a square matrix where the diagonal elements are `1`.

The second one creates a diagonal matrix with `1, 2, .. x` is on the diagonal, then negates it twice, to get the diagonal equal `1, 1, .. 1`.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 52 bytes

```
param($a)1..$a|%{$d++;(1..$a|%{+($d-eq$_)})-join' '}
```

Since the only built-in .NET class for matrices is ... umm ... [inadequate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx), shall we say, we're just going to construct and output a string representation here...

Takes input `$a` then executes a double-for-loop over range `1..$a`. Each outer loop we increment helper variable `$d` (the first loop, since `$d` isn't initialized, turns `$d++` into `$null + 1 = 1` ... in PowerShell logic it makes sense), and each inner loop is simply an integer-cast with `+` of an equality between `$d` and the current element `$_`. Each inner loop is `-join`ed together with spaces so it prints nicely, and each outer loop causes a newline, so output code is pretty cheap.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\construct-identity-matrix.ps1 10
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 27 bytes

```
import Data.Matrix
identity
```

Maybe a little bit boring.

Usage example:

```
Prelude Data.Matrix> identity 4
( 1 0 0 0 )
( 0 1 0 0 )
( 0 0 1 0 )
( 0 0 0 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```
->n{(([1]+[0]*n)*(n-1)+[1]).each_slice(n).to_a}
```

Explanation:

Concatenates `n - 1` sequences of `1` followed by `n` `0`s into an array, and appends `1` to the end.  Then slices the result into `n` arrays of length `n` and evaluates to an array having the slices as its elements.

Per Alex A., shaved 8 bytes by putting it in the form of a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>41 37</s>  35 bytes

```perl6
{$/=1..$_;$/.map: {$/.map: {+($^a==$_)}}} # 41 bytes
{$/=1..$_;$/.map: {$/.map: +(*==$_)}}     # 37 bytes
{$_=1..$^a;.map: {.map: +(*==$^a)}}       # 35 bytes
```

This outputs a list of lists.

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &identity-matrix = {…}

# format it so that it is readable
sub readable ( @_ ) { @_.join: "\n" }

say readable identity-matrix 10
```

```perl6
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby,38 bytes

Returns a 2D array.

```
->n{(0..n-1).map{|i|s=[0]*n;s[i]=1;s}}
```

Iterates through each row of the array. For each iteration generates a row of `n` zeros, then changes one of them to a `1`

**Usage**

```
f=->n{(0..n-1).map{|i|s=[0]*n;s[i]=1;s}}
p f[5]

[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

**A different approach (string):**

## Ruby, 47 bytes

```
->n{(0..n-1).map{|i|s='0 '*n;s[i*2]=?1;puts s}}
```

for each row, makes a string of `'0 '`repeated `n` times, changes one of the `0`s to `1`, and prints it

Comment: `(0...n)` is equivalent to `(0..n-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>11</s> 5 bytes

```
matid
```

is sufficient, or

```
n->matid(n)
```

(11 bytes) as a 'roll-your-own' closure. If you want to work entirely by hand,

```
n->matrix(n,n,i,j,i==j)
```

(23 bytes) should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>116</s> 107 characters

```
def M(n):
 x=[]
 for i in range(n):
  r=[]
  for j in range(n):
   r+=[1 if i==j else 0]
  x+=[r]
 return x
```

#### Output

```
iM(1) 
[[1]]
iM(2)
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
iM(3)
```

Comment: r.append(i) is the same as r+=[i] i think

Comment: There's a lot of further golfing that can be done here

Comment: Yeah, `1 if i==j else 0` can be `int(i==j)`.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39c2JzE3KSVRIc8qOjozr0Qjy9Y2UzMtv0ghSyEzT6EoMS89VSNPMxYkkoki8r@gCKTeV8NUU/M/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>31</s> 24 bytes

Includes +3 for `-p` (code contains `'` so I can't just use the implied `-e`)

Run with the count on STDIN, e.g.

```
./diagonal.pl <<< 3
```

Outputs:

```
100
010
001
```

`diagonal.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=0 x$_;s/./$`1$'
/g
```

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 3 bytes

```
eye
```

Does exactly this. `eye(n)` for an `n`-by-`n` matrix.

and also one without `eye`, 15 bytes:

```
diag(ones(1,n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash (w/ coreutils and awk), <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```
yes 0|head -$((N*N))|xargs -n$N|awk {\$NR=1}1
```

### Usage

Set the `N` environment variable to the matrix size

```
$ N=5
$ yes 0|head -$((N*N))|xargs -n$N|awk {\$NR=1}1
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

### Explanation

- `yes 0` generates an endless stream of `0`s to `stdout`;
- `head -$((N*N))` takes the first N<sup>2</sup> lines;
- `xargs -n$N` groups every N lines and outputs them together;
- `awk {\$NR=1}1` changes the value of the field whose index matches the line number to a `1` (otherwise it remains `0`) and then outputs the whole record.

There may be a shorter way to generate N<sup>2</sup> lines of `0`s, but I haven't found one yet...

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 11 bytes

```apl
{⍵ ⍵⍴1,⍵/0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24TqR71bFYD4Ue8WQx0grW9Q@/9R31SgTJqC5X8A)

Just for fun dfn submission

`⍵/0` replicate ⍵ zeros

`1,` prepend a 1

`⍵ ⍵⍴` mold to ⍵×⍵ square

So like for left argument 4 it will construct

```apl
1 0 0 0 0
```

And molding cycles from the beginning so, it will generate

```apl
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

the 4×4 identity matrix.

Comment: Are intentionally using the Extended variant? Then you could use `⊤2*⍵` to save a byte over `1,⍵/0`

Comment: @ovs genius golf! But I am not sure how `⊤2*⍵` works (This works in extended variant too)

Comment: After knowing how this works I will edit the answer along with explanation

Comment: `⊤2*⍵` only works in Extended, in this variant `⊤` without a left argument returns the base-2 digits of the right argument

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master), 35 bytes

```
;=nP;=i~1W<=i+1i nO S*"0 "n *2i 1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKWyNLCeS4Kq2bGSKZCFFLYEsJJcP4EuELMPUybJPlmFZQv56rrvnRSPb5C53ywfLmnm6p/uZnu4ek/RukuT7C5En2XKc7i3KsZi9vB027ZFMXNeGkvJhnq6ACpHf1IZKMZWYcToRecqyjGWz/IY@mmb0w@nHdyyoXi8@nLOwev37wTnbrV6PTt@wX6rX848sqMBHJxcW9vTjiQX9ePru4OI3Z8GZgx9t9i34GzezBxewrJxMbuOCubwSsFFgq1ExHLLdau708BNO5jBJHn1l@H1vbwWDyxAG3QRMlnEE1jCvz85OCIQf@@RkH32zDDl/KwEgb9l6F2fLlPPLfMSbTfIDduVyFJ23Ds@OnO@DKH8/iMS34NNeJLqBYPkZu3BbPmvlzA0FC1jwnQOyNZDCLkin8ZRFqGbQbMJa87hYpA5nj82GyEsmBs0GjNK6HnMnyzyBERJO4L2czr3FPL8MR9Gj7/lPoKMhQB3h4enjwKtXqF7M2f2tKNPFPE7SZgO@Z6kD4yDuSDM81roqr/KryVXBHp8uRw7vv2hxMqUhJswx1kas86LDmVShR7dg9CqH4W5XjoCdjTRbpPbAkzQnuU2Tf7LJrGD5cnqdFgtlD3PEYixuRKm1wuroTuAZj@TTZYHPusxVlne7nPVYx@/AEmip4KxIy2WRMx0pUoyCZbBqw11ciPg6S7UVYEQ2u08LJ4H1tCHs61emjUvoLSEiPne4okdscF1EgQd7FJnhFevw7KkYBUg@Xs4d3FKmOO0xeFs3WGaChdQmzbjqdCqbWh25aSAMHhijGCiBzAHfwbJ5vChZeZuCsrgoAaw2wNWM4oYmHD3RxloH6llj4TPgtNGNigwyH0O3FLMczMaI9UdgWqIZWSzncySc66jSIzb9dvwB7RbZqEOH8jyHOIYshpGrLJesfOiYoy4HjnAAM1ofMxmaqYOMkqB01UG70dQ4y2aJs@t7AUcHcdg4QQ7myyyLiwfb0Wp/zq3ted8xltGCSn6Zr0jTEgEuoZLCJk8PDl@/@fL71smvZ98sj22912Kj4nBd8VZN89vji2c0lmlBKuN8zP61jPUrqr2zl9hZX0Iy8LZjyDjeQAYJ79aF65gnypXFMsctGqhU7JazhaOTJZ0AiO1SJIxmr5eTy3B3pOyQO92m/GAMWMzhXJUTB6Dg/3aWjVs68VAp8lDJqgI4FUaBLHJy/RpujwU7dT/ReQzGfdYqi2XagiA04xiTMD6JIYXgRAtDq1WRgH6i76oaER2fX89mGcxc1xl41tfKrR855P68R7aZ12tmZmhj/pfaCEFbzrLMsU31mO9BifgfTM7XTMYy/O7g/amHxVgGGrweXwa@70M4gSvwqt8W4s/0c8nwMbBi1PIWGYA3Dz9C@tyJAl3TMcVhWccHfYbysQOAo@OTQ5dNIDsOGia01XqYh5N47mVpTi2AxZVuliRncO6eI2NVEIsT1jasOI6gZgKK8R5xMYCqInDS5I1kOl/ZASJJjKoUgjSJES6zuBdlcuu4wMxabwUcMfWXYKHqHHT6DFeRgAgJxe4M0jBvk1NKveoPayHLB1SGKwQ1oWWBtYv60MsRf6zCDDooSu5y4XNYuK67gIzn8Lb/xwT/KuR7QIJWydFNWmbQQjpt2ss27hDWyLHI@UBMHIf2EzuC5LZAWzyIU87lNkf@YKOt8ODUB8j1DuV6snXEbKAIGWh7kSSVOysrX1f@SLyZeVPNoKRNscF8AQxGA8RfNJ/N09yxFvZaRYt6BbAqmspSCfEYhf7uLzSuugtHtiQTMH2MTkEPByHrYYMHcGge6A3XgKV1eDkwyLoR9UJ4YgHJFd2gh9YiqlGDG7HQbloqGitPfgdP0j@gj8PTvubnVm3X6aawhZlsDXiyFh6wSlbnxYJ/W4P3Nq7/a6evGsoNAW8ypKpUrVPqnx2sVVwXq@Fwl1cd6Fra1KIX1EU62wsUrB@adWGgHXoke13IuLxVQfUElqE0zpXa50qdqm32TqkcpFg4q1jAAyRvSEiu3PcaxazdpmtYr4fQkeyHr6gvb2iztl@6C7DHgTfO9JEsLPOX5UJHiYkd2RRKg7rGIMqnkFcxdWMIWtsj2@5GfZvlnRbRcEFges9DuefYKNOhkRtAKBzGbBBpL0O@OaSTuNQP1Z4G3Yomrr@jLg5tq0fPUuUS5VdvLSytqMSevm6vFHKr3dnAwmoZ38CDu8aD3NdNLEw3uOYSJrKVkADUKocyadS5gtsggga9HulTRFFpXd1oyWhZyxKvfkjMq83EbP9QaHuz0D@IzZpD8o5BY6Ht5UDRLlmPWC8wLBMWqA/gnPUCOGOBDQ5/Er0HabSGjSKE0rp9PeJryonocOgrrkNObY0bEf/N1QNBk@QK3CUoEWMpgu94tbhNi7SzYPkMem2RlSJn9/ED8MbGM7i8lulNWoDMfJaneSlivG3ASZ6x@5TdxncpAJUihJdsGudLCJ@HlziK3l0j40AFMbFYZiX@ukCLm4SnIT0bo5dcocyWM5AV9ajveaT/vCEGtldD@XSRjzOsoQ/gdT7O0jH7Upn9xWh5xG@ygbMWqZwZorJeT79zgjcU1LVMfzJ5cI@CdaVAYtKr5cWonhX3mX349@xjgKJ99Wtdm0nAPqs1lDToMSsbog5fSurSHMo6gNitCKqN1S0N4VBiaM3Gsz6bptNkjmGWs@GX/f/XleFf4MpQu7K1wZdI@aJc2X@efbnqBpNxep/VAKFBhLqAbm2ys3ox7unMYysw5rWr9Ie@bKoN@7akSiVG/ut/I69ykKXGyA86fRtda4dXsVGVdevTP33h0T1wdeNBXKN26zGpkDCocRTVpK00iRKI6HaNmDT5E7gnfx6zG9Kad8zuXZTYcb27R6glvx/2dyxa3sqrRWR1WF27AK3fpXJ1QfHMWdipNb4XkugVpYPVkhduKnk73PQBoZHepcH/0BChYfjErUjMJcG0Q3ZvFIKHuGo3wCaJGgQZ/3KSHoToqpMAq4/TSQxJEjzTHabIYVKM6cemOCmhTHW2kw72nDjC2TO3XVRmaiB0g@oHh2kscmxWWVzcJB4pdV34fsfxZy26h@I/fxyfrKlf956@B/6/AQ)

Outputs a bunch of strings. It works by generating the string `0 0 ... 0`  (a space-separated string of \$n\$ `0`s), then changing the \$2i\$th character to `1` and outputting the result for each \$i\$ between \$0\$ and \$n-1\$.

Expanded code:

```
;=n PROMPT
;=i~1
WHILE <(=i +1 i) n
  OUTPUT (SET (*"0 " n) (*2 i) 1 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
´Ṫ=ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CWhztX2T7csfj///@mAA)

```
´         # argdup: use input as both arguments to function         
 Ṫ        # table: generate the outer product of all pairs
  =       # equals: 1 if arguments equal, zero otherwise
   ḣ      # heads: 1..input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$=>[unique permutate[1]++@.of:&-1,0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?BuYGJU)

Answer (score 1):

## , 3 chars / 6 bytes

```
Мƕï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=3&code=%D0%9C%C6%95%C3%AF)</kbd>

I'm finding a lot of these 3-char solutions. It's just a builtin.

## Bonus solution, 11 chars / 22 bytes

```
⩥ïⓜãĉ⇝+($≔a
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=3&code=%E2%A9%A5%C3%AF%E2%93%9C%E1%B5%96%20%C3%A3%C4%89%E2%87%9D%2B%28%24%E2%89%94a)</kbd>

The code in the interpreter link uses some more bytes to pretty-print output.

#### Explanation

```
⩥ïⓜãĉ⇝+($≔a // implicit: ï=input
⩥ïⓜ         // create a range [0,ï) and map over it
    ãĉ⇝      // get a copy of range ã and map over it
       +($≔a // output 1 or 0 depending on whether item in first map == item in current map
             // implicit output
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: It's just a builtin. I'll post a bonus solution soon.

Comment: Alright, updated.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>Seq.tabulate(n,n){(i,j)=>if(i==j)1 else 0}
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Scala, though is the space in `1 else` necessary?

Comment: @JonathanFrech yes, it actually won’t compile without it, with “Invalid literal number” message. Thanks anyway! And you should learn Scala, it is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

## [Samau](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Samau/tree/master/OldSamau), 5 bytes

```
,;`=o
```

It's a function that takes a number and return a 2D array.

```
,;`=o
,      range from 0 to n-1
 ;     duplicate
    o  take the outer product by
  `=   equality
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 75 bytes

```
N:1I:(I.N.1+<^1J:(J.I.<^0!32!'1J.+J:)1!32!'(J.N.<^0!32!'1J.+J:)10!'1I.+I:)$
```

This is a full program that reads from STDIN and prints to STDOUT. Each line will have a single trailing space and there will be one trailing newline at the end of the output.

Explanation:

```
~ Read N from STDIN
? N:

~ Initialize a row index
1 I:

~ Loop while we've printed fewer than N+1 rows
( I. N. 1 + < ^

  ~ Initialize a column index
  1 J:

  ~ Print I-1 space-separated zeros
  ( J. I. < ^
    0 !
    32 !'
    1 J. + J:
  )

  ~ Print 1 and a space
  1 !
  32 !'

  ~ Print the remaining zeros
  ( J. N. < ^
    0 !
    32 !'
    1 J. + J:
  )

  ~ Newline
  10 !'

  ~ Increment the row index
  1 I. + I:
)
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 200 Bytes

This is the shortest working java code i could come up with. Nothing to special ;)

```
class a{public static void main(String[]a){int c=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);int[][]b=new int[c][c];for(int d=0;d<c;d++){for(int e=0;e<c;e++){b[d][d]=1;System.out.print(b[d][e]);}System.out.println();}}}
```

Partly posting this hoping someone could explain why TNT 's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70392/49605) is valid (it has no class declaration and no `main(String[] args)`)? I'm new to code golf and i thought that answers had to be a working program?

Comment: The answer in question is a function, which is a valid submission by our rules. You can make this shorter by changing `class` to `interface`, which allows you to drop the `public`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 22 bytes

```
from numpy import*;eye
```

It's a bit boring, but it's short! Because of discussion on meta, I think this follows the spirit of the rules a bit more closely.

Comment: I'm unsure about your points, why don't you try adding an answer to the meta question, so it can get feedback from more people? The main thing that bothers me about it is the arguments against the empty file being valid, because then you could write a library that defined all functions to make all your answers extremely small. But I'm uncertain of how to differentiate between `import` and `def` now that you've brought it up.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman +1 I'll open it to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 42 bytes

```
->n{([1]+[0]*(n-1)).permutation.to_a.uniq}
```

creates every permutation of the array `[1,0,0,0...]` and then takes the unique ones. this will end up with the ones we want, in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 111 bytes

I love abusing for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int n){for(int j,i=0;i++<n;putchar(10))for(j=0;j++<n;putchar(32))putchar(i-j?48:49);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 102 bytes

```
SELECT SUBSTR(RPAD(0,:1,0),:1-LEVEL+2)||1||SUBSTR(RPAD(0,:1,0),LEVEL+1)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 15 bytes

```py
identity_matrix
```

Exactly what it says on the tin

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTIs8pMSc0rySypjM9NLCnKrNDI0-Tl4uUqKMrMK1FI0zDWBABS7w5P&lang=sage)

Thanks to Lynn for pointing out that I was being a doofus.

Comment: Why not eta-reduce this to `identity_matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 12 bytes

```
P`N(Rri
   -
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=UGBOKFJyaQogICAt&input=NA)
This entry is non-competing.

### Explanation

- `i` is input, and `r` computes the range from 0 to input-1.
- The operator `(` is a *left hook*. On inputs `-` and `R`, it applies `R` (rotate) to the range and its negated version. This gives the `i×i` matrix whose rows are the ranges `ri`, rotated **k** steps to the right for each row **k**.
- `` `N `` computes the logical negation of each entry: 0 goes to 1 and everything else to 0. Since the 0s are on the diagonal, this gives the identity matrix.
- `P` prints the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

## [picTuring](http://fred-choi.com/projects/picTuring/index.html) - 16 States (320 bytes)

I thought this challenge might be a good chance to show off my new Turing Machine interpreter.

```
0 * 0 * r
0 _ 1 * r
1 * 2 1 l
2 * 2 * l
2 _ d * l
d _ f * r
d 0 d 1 l
d 1 p 0 r
p * p * r
p _ q * r
q * q * r
q _ 2 0 l
f * f _ r
f _ g * r
g 1 g _ r
g 0 r 1 r
r * r * l
r _ c * r
c _ n * d
c 0 o * d
c 1 i * d
o * e 0 u
i * j 0 r
j * h 1 u
h * k * r
k _ halt * *
k * c * *
e * c * r
n * r * l
```

The input must be in binary (1 / 0), with the number terminating at the head (the white circle).

**How to Run it:**

In case you didn't realize that the link in the header leads to my interpreter, you can find it here -> http://fred-choi.com/projects/picTuring/index.html

Here is the compressed test case (since my interpreter does not support permalinks yet):

```
AwAlH0QRhBaGLTgJjCSMg AwAgVCoQTgUKB9EBGcI6ogJhSANrDtmgTkgCYmyyVIBmaclolqBrIADpOtdxP17ckAR0awxESbzFIcoArAYQGSOKpABzcbG2pta3T2i44sEzComkAYx12kAOzTlYd0AHsXb3AEtvsF4QAKY8AK7U-hAAVsawsRAAFrgRyRAA1uKZSIkAhngALmhgsJkQdhAlsKHlOs6WEHhAA
```

To use it, just hover over save, paste the compressed code in the text box, and click load.

[image: loading]

To edit the tape, make sure you're in "Type" mode (Edit -> Paint), then double click the tape, and a red box should show up, indicating that you're now editing the tape.

Once you're finished, hit *Edit -> Ok* to save the tape, then *Controls -> Run*. *Controls -> Reset* will restore the tape to when you hit *Edit -> Ok*.

Again, this is interpreter is still indev, I don't have a manual yet, so feel free to leave comments if I left anything out.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 106 bytes

```
<?php $i=$argv[1];for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){for($h=0;$h<$i;$h++){$l="0 ";if($h==$j)$l="1 ";echo$l;}echo"\n";}?>
```

Based on a double for loop, it uses the command-line argument for the input.

```
php 70365.php 3
1 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1
```

Expanded code:

```
<?php
    $i = $argv[1];
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++)
    {
        for($h = 0; $h < $i; $h++)
        {
            $l="0 ";
            if($h == $j)
                $l="1 ";
            echo $l;
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

```php
for(;$i<$argn**2;$m?:$k++)echo$k==$m?:0,($m=++$i%$argn)?" ":"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkpmT9Py2/SMNaJdMGLKSlZWStkmtvpZKtra2ZmpyRr5JtawsSMNDRUMm11dZWyVQFK9S0V1JQslLiAhrw/2tevm5yYnJGKgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
=þ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/28L7///8bGgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 59 bytes

```
|n|{let mut l=vec![vec![0;n];n];for i in 0..n{l[i][i]=1};l}
```

Defines an anonymous function, creates a vector of vectors of the specified length, sets the diagonals to 1 and returns it. Boring, but shorter than any iterator-based approaches due to .collect overhead.

Alternatively, if returning an iterator of iterators is allowed it can be done in 44 characters:

```
|n|(0..n).map(|i|(0..n).map(|j|(j==i)as u8))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp) repl, 107 bytes

```
(d =(q((A R C S)(i C(=(c(e R C)A)R(s C 1)S)A
(d #(q((A R S)(i R(#(c(=()R S S)A)(s R 1)S)A
(d f(q((S)(#()S S
```

Using the repl saves 6 bytes in implied closing parentheses at the ends of lines. Defines a function `f` which takes a positive integer and returns the identity matrix of that size as a nested list. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYsxCoAwEAR7X3GQZq/TB6QI@UHyBDUQEFFi4@vPjWDhVrt3M1fd7622wwyLeJxAkCRRsqJKhMeMtR80aELjY9LMzgwU3Ce8eIIj7qHc0ikK6S@ULhB20I4whiLTqPYA)

#### Explanation

The function `=` constructs a row in the matrix. Its arguments are (in order) an Accumulator, the Row number, the current Column number, and the Size of the matrix. If the column is not zero `(i C ...)`, then cons a number to the accumulator (1 if the row and column are equal, 0 otherwise) `(c (e R C) A)`, decrease the column number `(s C 1)`, and recurse `(= ...)`. Otherwise, return the accumulator `A`.

The function `#` constructs the matrix as a list of rows. Its arguments are an Accumulator, the current Row number, and the Size of the matrix. If the row number is not zero `(i R ...)`, then generate a row `(=()R S S)` and cons it to the accumulator `(c ... A)`, decrease the row number `(s R 1)`, and recurse `(# ...)`. Otherwise, return the accumulator `A`.

Finally, the function `f` is simply a single-argument wrapper function that calls `#`.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 45 bytes

```
#(for[i(range %)](assoc(vec(repeat % 0))i 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 49 bytes

```
function($n){for(;$n--;)$k[$n][$n]=1;return $k;};
```

There is a bit of a caveat with this answer, and I will delete it or mark it as non-competing if it is deemed invalid.

The array returned by this function technically only has `n` elements, those being a 1 at every intersection. ie: 0:0 1:1, 2:2, etc

However, not only does this satisfy the definition of the identity matrix as given by the question:

> The identity matrix is one that has 1s spanning from the top left down to the bottom right

It also works if used as an identity matrix, as an empty value in an array in PHP is treated as 0 if used arithmetically.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 68 bytes

```
f(n:PI):Matrix INT==matrix([[(i=j=>1;0)for i in 1..n]for j in 1..n])
```

test and results

```
(30) -> for i in 1..3 repeat output f(i)
   [1]
   +1  0+
   |    |
   +0  1+
   +1  0  0+
   |       |
   |0  1  0|
   |       |
   +0  0  1+
                                                               Type: Void
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
y=x=2**input()
while~-x:x/=2;print str(bin(y+x))[3:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9K2wtZISyszr6C0REOTqzwjMye1TrfCqkLf1si6oCgzr0ShuKRIIykzT6NSu0JTM9rYKvb/fxMA)

Using binary representation of powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica ,26 bytes

without using IdentityMatrix

```
Boole[#==#2]&~Array~{#,#}&
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 45 bytes

```
{param($n)0..--$n|%{"$(,0*$_+1+,0*($n-$_))"}}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvUpxk@7@6ILEoMVdDJU/TQE9PV1clr0a1WklFQ8dASyVe21AbSAPldFXiNTWVamv/G@oY6RjrmOqY61jqGBoClaopAE1RUIm3Vlev/Q8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>55</s> <s>52</s></sub> 43 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as number from cell `[A1]` and outputs the identity matrix to the range of `[A1].Resize(n,n)`

```vba
[A1].Resize([A1],[A1])="=1*(Row()=Column())
```

-2 bytes thanks to [Engineer Toast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast)

#### Previous Version

```vba
n=[A1]:[A1].Resize(n,n)=0:For i=1To n:Cells(i,i)=1:Next
```

Comment: Save 1 byte: `"=1*(Row()=Column())"`

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 47 keystrokes

```
"zy$␘a@q␛"xYoa␛"zPy$qqo␛@"0␛q@x3Gqqr1jlq@x1G2dd
```

`␘` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and `␛` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>

### Explanation

```
"zy$␘           Save n for use later
a@q␛"xY         Create the macro `x` that repeats the macro `q` n-1 times
oa␛"zPy$        Create an anonymous macro that inserts a character n times
qqo␛@"0␛q@x    Create the macro `q` that adds a new line with n zeroes and run it n times
3G               Go to the top-left corner of the matrix
qqr1jlq@x        Redefine `q` as a macro that replaces the character at the cursor with
                   a one and moves the cursor one step down-right. Run `q` n times
1G2dd            Delete the two lines used in macro defenitions
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 92 bytes

```
proc I n {time {incr j;set a "";set i 0;time {lappend a [expr [incr i]==$j]} $n;puts $a} $n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgFAX3neIRHsC2iQfoDNJCzMWPso8ZBOHZrYx2w5t5yS2lcNwcBgRciVaPi4KLmNXuEyzatgJBqs8ultmH6VHGnxxhak6j1mIeM0RQfKQdwr6cy3eq01/2zQBBGZ0sNw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
´Ṫ=ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CWhztX2T7csfj////GAA)

#### Explanation

```
´Ṫ=ḣ  -- example input: 2
   ḣ  -- range: [1,2]
´     -- duplicate argument: [1,2] [1,2]
 Ṫ    -- outer product by
  =   -- | equality: [[1==1,1==2],[2==1,2==2]]
      -- : [[1,0],[0,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 10 bytes

```
IR0PlF}D|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zPIICDHrdalxvr/f1MA)

The output for `n = 5` looks like this:

```
[1 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 1]
```

#### How it works

```
IR0PlF}D|;

IR0P       Take input n, then fill the stack with that many 0s
           and then make the top 1; stack = [0 ... 0 1]
    lF..|  Do the following n times...
      }D   Rotate the stack once to the right, and print the whole stack
         ; Terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Lã€Ësô
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/DiR01rDncXH97y/9Du/@YA)

**Explanation:**

```python
L         # List in range [1,n]
          #  i.e. 3 → [1,2,3]
 ã        # Cartesian power of this list
          #  i.e. [1,2,3] → [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
  €Ë      # Check for every pair if they are equal or not
          #  i.e. [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
          #   → [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
    sô    # Split it into parts equal to the input
          #  i.e. [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] and 3 → [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Comment: Alternative 6-byter [°¨IF=Á](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IZDKzzdbA83/v9vCgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Kaldo Ah, that's quite a bit different than my approach, but also pretty cool. And I just saw your 4-byte answer, +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
P&O`=ri
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyalMyyzO@P8/QM0/wbYo8/9/EwA)

#### Explanation

```
P&O`=ri
     ri  Range(input)
 &       With that list and itself,
  O      make a table (outer product)
   `=    using vectorized equality
P        Print as matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
Þ□
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiw57ilqEiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Vyxal literally has a builtin for this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 15 bytes

```
identity-matrix
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoQckijKTU4sVCopSS0oqC4oy80oUrLm4TP9npqTmlWSWVOqClVT81/sPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 4 bytes

```
=⌜˜↕
```

Anonymous tacit function; returns a 2D array. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgPeKMnMuc4oaVCgpGIDQ=)

#### Explanation

```
   ↕  Range(argument)
=⌜    Create an equality table
  ˜   between that list and itself
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-P`, 6 bytes

```
_=BMCa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJfPUJNQ2EiLCIiLCI5IiwiLVAiXQ==)

Just for completeness sake, here's the shortest **non-builtin** answer that I could find in Pip. In other words, an answer without the usage of `EY`.

```
_=BMCa         Input is "a"
   MCa         Map over all x,y pairs in an a by a coordinate grid
_=B            Is the x-coordinate equal to the y-coordinate?
               Implicit output joined by newlines (-P flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyz5eKyVTfUVjTl4gIACZ8BfA==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
řĐɐ=Ɩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MwjE05OsD027f9/MwA)

```
ř              implicit input; create řange [1,2,...,n]
 Đ             Đuplicate
  ɐ=           for ɐll pairs: are elements equal?
    Ɩ          cast to Ɩnteger; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
ᵒ-¬
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fssebp2ke2jNkuKk5GKo0ILlhlxGXMZcJhAuAA)

```
ᵒ-     Generate a 2d table with subtraction
  ¬    Logical not (converts 0 to 1 and other numbers to 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 110 bytes

```fortran
allocatable K(:,:);read*,n;allocate(K(n,n));K=0;forall(i=1:n)K(i,i)=1
do i=1,n;print*,(K(i,j),j=1,n);enddo;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsQgDEX3PUWXSUlhuioYPIGnSEc7WCQW8f5W6Ww@n/d4Zy61iK6/8z2tSUr5K1WOFGYHhgxyCeIXUv6rAA6UFJGd/XAPO4doN6PoIFJEu00@z5305i5R60IwzIV0DYgc1Ps8trX9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RD€=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy4JcHjWtsV1SnJRcDBVasNAEwgAA)

##### Explanation

```python
RD€=  # Implicit input
R     # Push the range [1..n]
  €   # For each number,
   =  # Compare it with
 D    # The range [1..n]
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 4 bytes

`ºµÍT`

using array operations, returns a nested array

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=urXNVA==&in=NQ==)

`¹®0^`

using matrix operations, returns a matrix

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=ua4wXg==&in=NQ==)

### Explanation

```
ºµÍT  ; implicit input
º     ; convert to zero-based array
 µÍ   ; replace each element with an array that has a 1 at the specified position
   T  ; transpose to fill in missing zero elements
      ; implicit output
```

```
¹®0^ ; implicit input
¹    ; 1-based range
 ®   ; converted to matrix
  0^ ; to the 0th power (matrix implicitly padded with zeros)
     ; implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [**T-SQL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-ver16), 202 bytes

`DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX);SELECT @s='SELECT '+STRING_AGG('CASE WHEN value='+CAST(value AS CHAR)+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END',',')+' FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,'+CAST(@n AS CHAR)+')'FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,@n);EXEC(@s)`

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BitVjfte)

Explanation:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 5; -- Input integer assigned to the variable @n. Not counted in byte count
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX); -- string variable to house the upcoming dynamic sql

-- dynamically builds a sql query that will have @n many columns and stores it in @s.
SELECT @s='SELECT '+STRING_AGG('CASE WHEN value='+CAST(value AS CHAR)+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END',',')+' FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,'+CAST(@n AS CHAR)+')' 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,@n); 
EXEC(@s) -- Executes the string @s as t-sql code.


    --Example, dynamically built query looks like this for @n = 5
    SELECT CASE WHEN value=1                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,CASE WHEN value=2                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,CASE WHEN value=3                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,CASE WHEN value=4                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,CASE WHEN value=5                              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,5                             )
    --Note, white space after integer values due to casting as CHAR. casting as VARCHAR would clean this up but cost an extra 3 bytes per call.
```

Output for @n=5

[image]

Will only work on SQL server 2022 or greater (GENERATE_SERIES needs compatibility level 160 or greater). Likely also work on Azure SQL database etc...

There is already a superior (in terms of byte count) [**oracle sql answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70967/101226). But that answer produces a single string column of zeros and ones, whereas this answer produces an n by n table of numeric zeros and ones. So I figured this was different enough to still share.

Answer (score 1):

## [jamforth](https://github.com/ambyshframber/jamforth), 152 bytes

```forth
: F DUP DUP 2* 1- DUP ALLOT SWAP DFOR 2DUP + 48 SWAP C! REPEAT TUCK + 1- 49 SWAP C! SWAP TUCK + 1- SWAP DUP DFOR -ROT 2DUP TELL CR -ROT 1- -ROT REPEAT ;
```

196 bytes compiled, theoretically half that on a 16 bit machine or token threaded forth with 16 bit tokens. F, when called, prints the NxN identity matrix where N is the number on top of the stack.

Here it is deobfuscated:

```forth
: POPULATE ( len )
    DUP 2* 1- ( len 2len-1 )
    DUP ALLOT ( len 2len-1 ptr )
    SWAP DFOR
        2DUP + [CHAR] 0 SWAP C!
    REPEAT
    TUCK + 1- [CHAR] 1 SWAP C!
;
: PRINT ( ptr len )
    TUCK + 1- SWAP
    DUP DFOR
        ( ptr len idx )
        -ROT 2DUP TELL CR
        -ROT 1-
        -ROT
    REPEAT
;
: GO DUP POPULATE SWAP PRINT ;
```

I know I committed to jamforth about 25 minutes before posting this, but I wrote DFOR a few weeks back and just didn't get around to committing it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 16 bytes

```
[$(⌼ =) #0 #0]∘⍳
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIXMpaUlaboW26JVNB717FGw1VRQNgCi2EcdMx71boZIbtHk0sjMtyovyixJzclT0MhUsNTUhEgtWAChAQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Malbolge Unshackled, 1,664,383 bytes.

A [link to GitHub](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/codegolf-submissions/blob/master/70365.mb) as StackExchange does not allow posting answers so long. One of my fastest Malbolge programs.

[image: I(16)]

Comment: Babe wake up new Malbolge program just dropped

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 24 bytes

```
,;╗r`╙k╜#"{:0%sb}"%f#`MR
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LDvilZdyYOKVmWvilZwjIns6MCVzYn0iJWYjYE1S&input=NQ)

Explanation:

```
,;╗r`╙k╜#"{:0%sb}"%f#`MR
,;╗                       get input (n), save a copy in register 0
   r                      push [0..n-1]
    `                `M   map the function:
     ╙k                     push [2**a]
       ╜#"{:0%sb}"%         push "{:0nb}"
                   f#       format and explode string
                            (push binary representation, padded with zeroes to n digits)
                       R  reverse list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>16</s>, 11 bytes

```
Ài0 ÀÄòjl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3BDpoGC9OGGwy2HNzFm5fz//9/QAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), <s>96 94</s> 92 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(n)(set'a(make-array(list n n):initial-element 0))(dotimes(i n)(setf(aref a i i)1))a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc2xDsIwDIThnafwhm@oRIGJtzGtI1k4bpWGgadPq7Jm/U6/bnLb1sab1mvi9I2p2hKNXfJ7Fg6ci3CWjw5Sivz4CCoFBV4WVk18UNesUekG8LxUy7qx0b9NLEUTCRkZRkDQgAuvxY7gPBR3SjR29d7VR1efQNsB)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```php
while($p**.5<$z=+$argn)echo$p%-~$z?0:1,"
 "[++$p%$z>0];
```

requires PHP 5.6 or later for the power operator. Note that the second line begins with a space!

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3792431ce4a9b4e67c3be0d7129911dc86a55008).

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
ＥθＥθ⁼κμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/983sUCjUEcBSrkWlibmFGtk6yjkampq/v8fbRr7X7csBwA)

This returns an array, which in Charcoal is not readable in its default format. A version using Wolfram `List`s is included below for readability.

#### Explanation

```
Ｅθ       Map for each number from 0 to first input
   Ｅθ    Map for each number from 0 to first input
      ⁼κμ Return whether both loop indices (yes, indices) are the same. The variables here are: i = first loop variable, k = first loop index, l = second loop variable, m = second loop index.
```

[Readable version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@1LDGnNLEkNSyxKDMxKSdVQym5KBXIj0@tKChKLS7OzM9T0lHwTSzQKIRTroWliTnFGtk6CrmaQPD/f7Rp7H/dshwA)
[Even accepts input as unary :P](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@1LDGnNLEkNSyxKDMxKSdVQym5KBXIj0@tKChKLS7OzM9T0lHwTSzQKIRTroWliTnFGtk6CrmaQPD/vyEK@K9blgMA)

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 88 Bytes

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJRepmCrYGrNZW8HEVNIyy/SUMm0NbBWydTWtgGrsNasVkm0TSwqSqyMT8vMydEw1AGL6xhoWqskRqtkxtoaWqcmZ@QrZOYW5OSnpGoo6SgBlWjqKXEpWdf@/w8A)

**Code**

```
<?php for($i=0;$i++<$argv;){$a=array_fill(1,$argv,0);$a[$i]=1;echo implode(",",$a)."
";}
```

**Explanation**

```
<?php 
  for($i=0;$i++<$argv;){          // loop up to the argument
      $a=array_fill(1,$argv,0);   // create an array fill with 0 with length = $argv value
      $a[$i]=1;                   // use the current iteration to place the "1"
      echo implode(",",$a)."      // implode to output the matrix
     ";}
```

**Output**

```
  $argv=5

  1,0,0,0,0
  0,1,0,0,0
  0,0,1,0,0
  0,0,0,1,0
  0,0,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 48 bytes

```forth
: f dup 0 do dup 0 do 0 i j = - . loop cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKaSUFigYKKTkIxgGCpkKWQq2CroKego5@fkFCslFENr6v6EBUMd/AA)

#### Explanation

uses nested loops to output the matrix. For each element it outputs 1 if the indexes are equal, and 0 otherwise.

#### Code Explanation

```forth
:f           \ start a new word definition
  dup        \ duplicate input
  0 do       \ outer counted loop from 0 to input - 1
    dup      \ duplicate input again 
    0 do     \ inner counted loop from 0 to input - 1
      0      \ put a 0 on the stack (used to convert -1 to 1)
      i j =  \ -1 if i equals j, 0 otherwise
      - .    \ subtract from 0 to convert -1 to 1, and output
    loop     \ end inner loop
    cr       \ output a newline
  loop       \ end outer loop
;            \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 114 bytes

```d
void f(int n){import std.stdio;int N=n*n;while(N--){if(N%(n+1))write("0 ");else write("1 ");if(N%n==0)writeln();}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1NCsQgDIbhq4TCQDJDB12LV/AOBZUJ2Di00i5Kz27tzyKL7@GF@FqXzB4ishQQ2nj856nAXPy3HWdzurPyFrP@OAV0fd@qiO6F8tFE68QlYKegIxPSHOABfcLVibXqzpIgmX2/X44Dt7lF1KphPQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 14 bytes

```
n->matrix(n)^0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW6_J07XITS4oyKzTyNOMMIII3ldPyizTyFGwVDHUUTHUUCooy80qAfCUFXTsgkQZUqqkJUbpgAYQGAA)

Takes the zeroth power of the zero matrix.

See also [Charles's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70955/9288),

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
EYa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJFWWEiLCIiLCI5IiwiLXAiXQ==)

Builtin.

Comment: What's the shortest non-builtin solution you can find?

Comment: @DLosc I found a non-builtin solution of [6 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/construct-the-identity-matrix/255151#255151).

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>6</s> 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
.;,$.@==$_
```

```
.               # map across each value of
  ,$            # 1..input
 ;              # (saving this range)
    .           #   map across each value of
     @          #   the saved range (1..input again)
      ==$_      #     are the two values equal?
```

[image]