# Create a percent sign

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given an integer **n** ≥ 1, output a 2D representation<sup>†</sup> of a percent sign of width **n**. The construction goes as follows:

1. Create an **n** by **n** matrix (or list of lists) filled with zeroes.
2. Insert ones in the top-left and bottom-right corners.
3. Place ones on the diagonal from the bottom-left to the top-right.

For input **n** = 4, this construction would look like:

```
1. 4x4 matrix of 0s
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
2. 1s in TL and BR corners
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
3. 1s across BL-TR diagonal
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

<sup>†</sup> I use a matrix of 1s and 0s, but it is also acceptable to use a string of any non-whitespace character and spaces. So, the example above could look like:

```
#  #
  # 
 #  
#  #
```

or

```
#     #
    #
  # 
#     #
```

### Test cases

```
n
output

1
1

2
1 1
1 1

3
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1

4
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1

10
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

### Final note

Adding an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can our solutions be 0-indexed?

Comment: @Cowsquack I'd say no. You're receiving the width, not an index.

Comment: Can we output a list of lists?

Comment: @xnor Yes; list of lists and matrix are synonymous in my post. I'll add that to the question

Comment: Note that this is `'1'+'0'*(n-2)` with whitespace inserted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
²Rm’Ṭs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//wrJSbeKAmeG5rHP/w4dHIOG4t@KAnCBDYWxsIGxpbmsuIFByZXR0eSBwcmludC7//zEw)

#### How it works

```
²Rm’Ṭs  Main link. Argument: n

²       Square; yield n².
 R      Range; yield [1, ..., n²].
   ’    Decrement; yield n-1.
  m     Modular; yield every (n-1)-th element of the range, staring with the first.
    Ṭ   Untruth; yield a Boolean array with 1's at the specified indices.
     s  Split the resulting array into chunks of length n, creating a matrix.
```

Comment: Also, `²Ḷ%’¬s` or `+þ%’=2`

Comment: [`²Ḷọ’s`](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//wrLhuLbhu43igJlz/8OHRyDhuLfigJwgQ2FsbCBsaW5rLiBQcmV0dHkgcHJpbnQu//8xMA) is so close...

Comment: If only there were a 1-byte "x is divisible by y" link...

Comment: @ETHproductions There's `ḍ@` but that's two bytes.

Comment: And I thought I was clever with `⁼þµ+1¦Ṫṁ³UG`...until a Dennis `²`-something solution popped up.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,y,a)=>a.map(_=>y++%~-n<1|0))
```

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 15 bytes

```
Àé ÀÄ|r#L.|ò.kl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4ZUKQKKlpkjZR6/m8Ca97Jz///@bAAA)

#### Explanation

```
Àé<space>        " Argument times insert a space
ÀÄ               " Argument times duplicate this line
                 " This gives an arg-by-arg matrix of spaces
                 "  and brings the cursor to the end of the first line
|r#              " Go to the beginning of this line and replace the first character with #
L.               " Go to the end of this matrix (bottom-right corner) and replace that character with a #
|                " Go to the beginning of the last line
ò                " Recursively do:
 .               "  Repeat the last action, r#, replace the character under the cursor with #
 kl              "  Go 1 up and 1 right
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```python
n=input()
x='#'.ljust(n-1)*3
exec'print x[:n];x=x[1:];'*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vCVl1ZXS8nq7S4RCNP11BTy5grtSI1Wb2gKDOvRKEi2iov1rrCtiLa0CrWWl0r7/9/QwMA)

Answer (score 6):

## Dyalog APL, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
,⍨⍴×,2↓⊢↑×
```

[Try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%2C%u2368%u2374%D7%2C2%u2193%u22A2%u2191%D7%295&run)

-1 byte thanks to lstefano.

### How?

```
,⍨⍴×,2↓⊢↑×
       ⊢↑× - argument-length extension of the sign of the argument (1)
     2↓    - Drop the first two elements
   ×,      - Prepend a one
,⍨⍴        - Shape into a square array with dimensions of input x input
```

Comment: I seriously don't think this can be golfed anymore... wow.

Comment: It can: `,⍨⍴×,2↓⊢↑×` (10 bytes). I am tempted to add: don't use too many commutes... :-P

Comment: [Try online with arg 5](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%2C%u2368%u2374%D7%2C2%u2193%u22A2%u2191%D7%295&run) - [Try online with arg 1](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%2C%u2368%u2374%D7%2C2%u2193%u22A2%u2191%D7%291&run)

Comment: You've got to be kidding me, wow. Nice abuse of signum.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
XyPl5L(
```

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=XyPl5L%28&inputs=7&version=20.2.1)

#### Explanation

Create identity matrix (`Xy`), flip vertically (`P`), write (`(`) value 1 (`l`) to the first and last entries (`5L`), which are the top left and bottom right.

Answer (score 5):

## GNU APL, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
{1=⍵∨⍵⍵⍴1=⍳⍵-1}
```

This is one weird day ... GNU actually beat Dyalog APL ... woah.

TIO doesn't support GNU APL ...

Explanation (input is `⍵`):

```
1=⍳⍵-1 - 1 followed by ⍵-2 0's
⍵⍵⍴    - fit into a square
⍵∨     - gcd ⍵ (0 gcd n = n)
1=     - test each element for equality with 1
```

Comment: [Ninja'd?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133805/41805)

Comment: There ... take that.

Comment: Can't believe I actually had to break out my old GNU APL, wow.

Comment: And take that!!

Comment: Ooh, I am going to take inspiration from the `1=⍵∨` and implement it in my solution

Comment: I'm assuming then it will basically be my answer but with a space then?

Comment: Eh, you're probably right

Comment: But I've beaten myself again ... this time in Dyalog APL again (I can't believe how substantially different all these answers are ... wow)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:zip(*[iter(`10L**n`[:-3]*-~n+'1')]*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqiqzQEMrOrMktUgjwdDAR0srLyHaStc4Vku3Lk9b3VBdM1YrT/N/Wn6RQp5CZp5CUWJeeqqGoY6pgaYVF2dBUWZeiUKeTk5qnkaaRp6m5n8A)

Outputs like

```python
[('1', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '0', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', '1')]
```

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda n:zip(*[iter([1]+(n*[0]+[1])[2:]*-~n)]*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDkAwFAXQma9442uRYDA08SXVoUJpwtU0XRj8etnOcMKd9gt9duOUD3vOiyWoxweW2qc1su5MxZC6NdVPoXtlZPNCGAmR3RUJ5EHRYlu5qwehyiJEj0SO//AB)

Outputs like

```python
[(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1)]
```

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda n:('%d'*n+'\n')*n%(1,*(*[0]*n,1)[2:]*-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq9DkAwFAbQmafoIr33IvETSxNPgqFCkfCRxmLx6uXM53ru9UQdXNuH3R7jZBUM6WTSglT30CxIqMyEpCsGQVZyV5lB8hcc3OkV1AblLZb5X03BJo4uv@EmR2AOHw)

A quite different string-substitution approach in Python 3. Outputs like:

```python
1001
0010
0100
1001
```

Comment: Can't you make `10L` `10`?

Comment: @Zacharý I'm relying on there always being an `L` at the end so I can cut the same number of characters off the end of large numbers and small ones.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mistakenly thought you were only using it as the number. I never knew `10` and `10L` were different.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
=þ¹UF1Q¦s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//PcO@wrlVRjFRwqZz/8OHRyDhuLfigJwgQ2FsbCBsaW5rLiBQcmV0dHkgcHJpbnQu//8xMA)

#### How it works

```
=þ¹UF1Q¦s  Main link. Argument: n

  ¹        Identity; yield n.
=þ         Equals table; compare each i in [1, ..., n] with each j in [1, ..., n].
           This yields the n×n identity matrix.
   U       Upend; reverse each row.
    F      Flatten the matrix.
       ¦   Sparse application:
      Q        Unique; yield the unique elements of the constructed array, i.e.,
               [1] if n = 1 and [0, 1] if n > 1.
     1         Yield 1.
           This replaces the elements at indices 0 (last) and 1 (first) with 1.
        s  Split the resulting array into chunks of length n.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

```apl
{⍵=1:⍵⋄⍵ ⍵⍴1=⍳⍵-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24TqR71bbQ2tgOSj7hYgqQBi9W4xtH3UuxnI1DWsBao7tALIMwUA)

Making this work for input 1 has added 6 bytes.

Looking at testcase 4, we see the output is

```apl
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```

This is basically 1 0 0 repeated throughout the matrix. In other words, 1 0 0 shaped in a 4-by-4 matrix. So in this solution, we first generate this vector with 1 and trailing 0s using `1=⍳⍵-1` and then shape it using `⍵ ⍵⍴`. But this borks for input 1, so we need to create a conditional and gain 6 bytes...

```apl
{⍵=1:⍵⋄⍵ ⍵⍴1=⍳⍵-1}    The right argument is ⍵
 ⍵=1:⍵                 If ⍵ is 1 return itself
⋄                      Otherwise
 ⍳⍵-1                   Create a range 1 .. ⍵-1
 1=                     Equals 1; 1 0 0 {⍵-2 0's} ...
 ⍵ ⍵⍴                   Shape in a ⍵-by-⍵ matrix
```

Comment: Could you replace the conditional with `1⌈⍵-1`? i.e. `{⍵ ⍵⍴1=⍳1⌈⍵-1}`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> 42 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam*

```r
n=scan();m=diag(n)[,n:1];m[1,1]=m[n,n]=1;m
```

returns a matrix; reads from stdin. creates an identity matrix `diag(n)`, flips it top to bottom `[,n:1]`, sets the top left and bottom right to `1`, and then writes to console (`''`) with width `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOtc2JTMxXSNPM1onz8ow1jo32lDHMNY2NzpPJy/W1tA697/pfwA)

Comment: You are allowed to output a matrix, so you can save a few bytes by turning it into a function (`pryr::f`).

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I could, but then I think I'd have to change the language to `R+pryr` so I'd consider that a separate language; you're free to submit that! Then you could use the idea from [Cows quack's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133805/67312) which I think would be even shorter than this in that context (a 1-liner).

Comment: Hmm, I am unsure where to draw the line to be honest. Would you consider any library used a different language?

Comment: Also, using `function(n)` would probably still be shorter

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I'm really toying with the idea of simply eschewing anything that's not base R; so using basically anything that's not in the [base installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700799/what-is-difference-between-r-base-and-r-recommended-packages) is a "different language" in my mind

Comment: Which is shorter than the oneliner implementation you referenced: `function(n)matrix(rep(c(1,rep(0,n-2)),n+1),n,n)`

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam nah, `scan` is still better since there's only one input (if I'm not gonna be using `pryr`)

Comment: Nevermind: `pryr::f(matrix(c(1,rep(0,n-1)),n,n))`.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam oh, nice one. I'd even submit that as its own answer; it's different enough in the way it's constructing the matrix!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62611/discussion-between-jarko-dubbeldam-and-giuseppe).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 7 bytes

```
n<ÝI<Öô
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/z@bwXE@bw9MOb/n/3wQA)

**Explanation**

```
n<Ý      # push range [0 ... n^2-1]
   I<Ö   # check each for equality to 0 when modulus with n-1 is taken
      ô  # split in pieces of size n
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 55 bytes

At first my approach was to recursively generate the transposed identity matrix, but then fixing the first and last line required some ugly/lengthy case distinctions. So I looked for another way to generate the identity matrix which is how I found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70397/48198) idea.

```hs
f n=[[sum[1|x+y`elem`[2,n+1,2*n]]|y<-[1..n]]|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBC4IwHEfv@xQ/RqemgkKXSD9BnTqukUKKo@3vcEoKfvelBd4e7/Hayr9rY0JoQLmUfrQyXSYxl7WpbSmziEQaZUdSapkvsUyTZMNpx8BspQk5GqMdbOVuT2zppHDAgxAXeHUMcONwH/orrZbTGRxCwLfdB7TG/@Z6TcPam5/bB85Z@AI)

#### Explanation

```hs
[[x+y|y<-[1..n]]|x<-[1..n]]
```

generates this *matrix* (for `n=4`):

```hs
[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
[4,5,6,7]
[5,6,7,8]
```

As you can see the top left element is `2` (in general), all the diagonal elements are `5` (in general `n+1`) and the bottom right element is `8` (in general `2*n`). So all we need to do is to check if `x+y` is an element of `[2,n+1,2*n]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
EM:␗Èc°NSHYå·Ñß'xSHYâÛNBSP
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
"S'!>!G0'+<[>G>'<+<-]
```

`"S'`                   take input, put it into storage and output 0

`!>!G0'`             move cursor to [input, input] and output 0

`+<[>G>'<+<-]` move cursor to [input, 1] and output 0s while moving to [1, input]

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform),<strike>121 91</strike> 88 bytes

-30 bytes because the old way was stupid.

-3  bytes by moving around the variable initialization

```cs
n=>{int i=0,k=n-1;int[,]b=new int[n,n];b[0,0]=b[k,k]=1;for(;i<n;)b[i++,k--]=1;return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Ba4QwEIXP5lfM0WAsbq/Z7KWwsNCWlrb0IB7UTWV0O0ISW0T87TbRdqEDgeG9@V5ebdO6N3oZLFIDL6N1@lMyVl9Ka@GZTQz8WFc6rOGrxzM8lEgxX@XNDHMcqN4jOeFfLooDNKBgIXWYvACoMtEpSndysytF@hvCToIKWeWZyApV5Z3oCrWTH72JJe5J8irHJBFdmgbZaDcYgkrOi2RRyD09Pr29qtvM9/0rsn0wqiZeTe4vQ9xvC5@6yjJJkE8siu56sv1F37wbdPoeSceBuCKtR9or0nJv/UfiMUfRFgGa1w4zm5cf)

Loops iterates down the array to fill in the 1's. Returns an array of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Declare `b` as `var` to save some bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>14</strike> <strike>12</strike> 7 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!</sup>

```
↗Ｎ⸿/‖Ｏ↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9jaGFyY29hbP//4oaX77yu4ri/L@KAlu@8r@KGmP//NA)

Comment: I don't think this can be any shorter...

Comment: Well, first I trimmed it to `Ｎν◨/ν←↙ν‖Ｏ↘`, but then I came up with `↗Ｎ⸿/‖Ｏ↘`!

Comment: @Neil Wow, I don't even know what `⸿` does. Does it reset to original position?

Comment: No, `⸿` is like `¶` in that it moves down a row but it always goes to column zero (as measured by `Ｊ`) rather than the column at the beginning of the string, so for example `Ｊ⁵¦⁵⸿` is the same as `Ｊ⁰¦⁶`.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 67 bytes

```powershell
param($n)0..--$n|%{-join(("1"+"0"*(($n-1),0)[!$n])*3)[$_..($_+$n)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP00BPT1dXJa9GtVo3Kz8zT0NDyVBJW8lASUsDKKtrqKljoBmtqJIXq6llrBmtEq@np6ESrw3UF1v7//9/CwA)

Takes input `$n` and loops from `0` to `--$n` (i.e., `$n` pre-decremented). Each iteration, we construct a string of `1` followed by `$n-1` `0`s, then multiply that out `3` times (e.g., `100010001000` for input of `5`). Then we index into that on a rotating basis starting from `0` to `0 + $n`. Those characters are `-join`ed into a string, which is left on the pipeline. Output is implicit.

---

*(NB -- This requires an additional 9 bytes to handle the special case of `n=1`. Below is the 58-byte code if we're guaranteed `n>1`)*

```powershell
param($n)0..--$n|%{-join(("1"+"0"*($n-1))*3)[$_..($_+$n)]}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C++, 144 bytes

```cpp
#include<string>
#define S std::string
S p(int n){S r;for(int i=0;i<n;++i){r+=S(n,32);r[r.size()-1-i]=35;r+=10;}r[0]=r[r.size()-2]=35;return r;}
```

It takes advantage of the one byte difference between '#' and 35

Comment: Where exactly does your code take advantage of the one byte difference between `'#'` and `35`?

Comment: @Zacharý It seems it was in my IDE x)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>86</s> 62 bytes

```python
n=input();a=('1'+'0'*(n-2))*2+'1'
exec'print a[:n];a=a[1:];'*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERD0zrRVkPdUF1b3UBdSyNP10hTU8tIGyjAlVqRmqxeUJSZV6KQGG2VFwtUmBhtaBVrra6V9/@/OQA)

-24 bytes: Thanks to an idea from Rod!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 72 bytes

```
(s=Table[0,#,#];s[[1,1]]=s[[#,#]]=1;Table[s[[#+1-i,i]]=1,{i,#}];Grid@s)&
```

**input**

> [5]

**output**

> 1  0   0   0   1
> 0   0   0   1   0
> 0   0   1   0   0
> 0   1   0   0   0
> 1   0   0   0   1

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to print/display it, so you can replace `Grid@s` with `s` to save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL v16, 23 bytes

```
{(1@(1 1)(⍵ ⍵))⌽∘.=⍨⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE6o1DB00DBUMNTUe9W5VAGJNzUc9ex91zNCzfdS74lHvZqBQren//wA)

Explanation:

```
{(1@(1 1)(⍵ ⍵))⌽∘.=⍨⍳⍵} -(input ⍵) 
                ∘.=⍨⍳⍵  - identity matrix with size ⍵×⍵
               ⌽        - flip that
 (1@(1 1)(⍵ ⍵))         - place 1 into the corners using the v16 operator @ (At)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
²ovUÉ hT1 òU
```

Returns a 2D array / matrix.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=sm92VckgaFQxIPJV&input=NAotUQ==) using the `-Q` flag to show array-formatted output.

### Explanation

```
²ovUÉ hT1 òU
```

Implicit: `U` = input integer

```
²o
```

Square `U` (`²`), create the array `[0, U*U)` (`o`), and map each item by...

```
vUÉ
```

`1` if it's divisible (`v`) by `U-1` (`UÉ`), else `0`.

```
hT1
```

Set the item (`h`) at index 0 (`T`) to `1`.

```
òU
```

Split the array into slices (`ò`) of length `U`.

Comment: I don't think you actually need the `hT1`, as `0` is technically already divisible by `U` for every `U`. Other than that, great job :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions That was added to deal with an input of `1`. Without it, it [returns `[[0]]`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=sm92Vckg8lU=&input=MQotUQ==) because apparently zero is not divisible by zero.

Comment: Ah, dang it. I don't know if I should fix that though...

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 117 bytes

```
m=arg[1]+0 for y=m,1,-1 do s=""for x=1,m do s=s..((x==1 and y==m or x==m and y==1 or x==y)and"#"or" ")end print(s)end
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##LcpLCoAwDATQq4S4abGKAbc5ibgoVEWwVloFPX2sn9UMb2Y5rIhnG6eO@rKBMUS42BsyFYELkBjxsZPJ@A9SXSt1MhPY1eUze3gPOX@gHy6dAQsMEQH1kMctzuuu0tNFpL0B)

Code is pretty simple. It sets m to the first argument, then adds 0 to it to convert it to a number, then iterates backwards for the Y coord, forward through the X coord and will put a # if x==y or if it's the other corners.

*This program never uses the keyword "if".*

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 37 bytes

```matlab
@(n)sparse([1 n:-1:1 n],[1 1:n n],!0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs7ggsag4VSPaUCHPStfQCkjF6gA5hlZ5IJaigeb/NNvEvGJrrrTSnByNNA1DTU0Y0wjBNEYwTRBMUyDzPwA)

Generates a sparse matrix representing the percent sign.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 53 bytes

```
for(;$i<$l*$l;)echo($i++%($l-1)?0:1).($i%$l?'':"\n");
```

The length of the side of the matrix is `$l`. This code has a PHP Notice and even a PHP Warning for division by 0 when `$l=0`, but does the job!

Comment: It seems that you expect the input to be stored in a predefined variable (->`$l`). Unfortunately this is [not one of our accepted ways to take input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/34531). In the linked meta post you'll find alternatives, e.g. using command line arguments as seen in [ricdesi's  answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133908/34531).

Comment: completed and golfed: `while($i**.5<$n=$argn)echo$i++%~-$n?0:1,"\n"[$i%$n];` or `while($i**.5<$n=$argn)echo+!($i++%~-$n),"\n"[$i%$n];` (52 bytes each)

Comment: Needs `<?` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
n=input()
a='1'+'0'*(n-2)+'1'
print a
for i in range(1,n-1):print str(10**i).zfill(n)
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncs7CoAwEEXRPqtIl5n4wQg2QhaTws@APEOMhW4@CmJ5Odx45XVHXwq8IJ6ZWAVvnKlMZyyh6bl6S8UkyDqoeU9atECngGUiV6NxPH565ESus1a4vWfZNgL/XymDegA)

Comment: Good try, but doesnt work for n=1.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

```
->n{([1]+[0]*(n-2)).cycle.each_slice(n).take n}
```

It returns an array of arrays.

The code is pretty straightforward.

- It creates a `n-1` array with `1` as the first element and the rest filled with `0`s (e.g. `[1, 0, 0, 0]`)
- It repeats it
- It takes `n` slices of `n` elements

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiPaMFY72iBWSyNP10hTUy@5MjknVS81MTkjvjgnMzlVI09TryQxO1Uhr/Z/gUJatEnsfwA)

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, <strike>273 ( without comments )</strike> 170 ( golfed-ish )

```
: % 2 base ! cr dup 1- 1 swap lshift 1 or . cr 2 over 2 - dup 0< 0= if
0 ?do 2dup s>d rot <# 0 ?do # loop #> type cr 2*  loop
1 or . else drop drop then cr drop decimal ;
```

### ( 273 version to clarify commented version: )

```
: newbase
 base @ swap base ! ;
: 0u.r
 swap s>d rot <# 0 ?do # loop #> type ;
: frame
 1- 1 swap lshift 1 or ;
: %
 2 newbase swap
 cr dup frame . cr
 2 over 2 -
 dup 0< 0= if
  0 ?do
   2dup swap 0u.r cr
   2* 
  loop
  1 or .
 else
  drop drop
 then
cr
drop base ! ;
```

( Note that, since whitespace is the primary delimiter in Forth, removing every carriage return would make no difference. Indentation, of course, does. )

### ( Commented: )

```
( Uses bit array, max 64 width on AMD64 with gforth. )

( Could shave an extra thirty or so bytes by not restoring )
( the numeric base, )
( and a few more by pulling frame and 0u.r into the definition. )

: newbase ( n -- oldbase )  ( swap base with n )
 base @ swap base ! ;

: 0u.r ( u width -- )  ( unsigned numeric output, no leading zero suppression )
 swap s>d rot <# 0 ?do # loop #> type ;

: frame ( n -- f )  ( frame )
 1- 1 swap lshift 1 or ;

: %  ( n -- )  ( Make the % sign )
 2 newbase swap ( Use binary output. )
 cr dup frame . cr ( Frame the first line. )
 2 over 2 -
 dup 0< 0= if ( Are we already done? )
  0 ?do ( Loop doesn't do the first or last. )
   2dup swap 0u.r cr ( Zero fill, right justify. )
   2* 
  loop
  1 or . ( Put the second frame out. )
 else
  drop drop
 then
cr
drop base ! ;
```

### ( Execution examples: )

```
1 % 
1 

 ok
2 % 
11 
11 
 ok
3 % 
101 
010
101 
 ok
10 % 
1000000001 
0000000010
0000000100
0000001000
0000010000
0000100000
0001000000
0010000000
0100000000
1000000001 
 ok
40 % 
1000000000000000000000000000000000000001 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000001000
0000000000000000000000000000000000010000
0000000000000000000000000000000000100000
0000000000000000000000000000000001000000
0000000000000000000000000000000010000000
0000000000000000000000000000000100000000
0000000000000000000000000000001000000000
0000000000000000000000000000010000000000
0000000000000000000000000000100000000000
0000000000000000000000000001000000000000
0000000000000000000000000010000000000000
0000000000000000000000000100000000000000
0000000000000000000000001000000000000000
0000000000000000000000010000000000000000
0000000000000000000000100000000000000000
0000000000000000000001000000000000000000
0000000000000000000010000000000000000000
0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
0000000000000000001000000000000000000000
0000000000000000010000000000000000000000
0000000000000000100000000000000000000000
0000000000000001000000000000000000000000
0000000000000010000000000000000000000000
0000000000000100000000000000000000000000
0000000000001000000000000000000000000000
0000000000010000000000000000000000000000
0000000000100000000000000000000000000000
0000000001000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000
0000000100000000000000000000000000000000
0000001000000000000000000000000000000000
0000010000000000000000000000000000000000
0000100000000000000000000000000000000000
0001000000000000000000000000000000000000
0010000000000000000000000000000000000000
0100000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000001 
 ok
```

( Final note: works to one less than the bit width of the Forth interpreter. I ran the above on gforth, AMD64. An ancient 16-bit Forth would only go to 15 bits wide, and would need a bit of modification. )

Comment: If you want to have the commented code in your answer that's fine, but you do need the golfed down code somewhere, too.

Comment: @Phoenix Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 14 bytes

```
-]\*:$1,0$~-&2
```

Ungolfed:

```
- ]\ (*: $ (1,0 $~ -&2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WTwGEdWNjtKxUDHUMVOp01YwUuFKTM/IV0hRMIQx1dZiAObqA8f//AA)

Comment: Food for thought: a 10 byte solution exists :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Damn you.  It's already past 3 am here :P

Comment: Same here, and here we are :D

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Was it ``0=<:|i.@,~``?

Comment: @miles yes, it was :)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 97 bytes

```
def f(n):
    m=[[0+(j==n-i-1)for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
    m[0][0]=1
    m[-1]=m[0]
    return m
```

## Explanation

`m=[[0+(j==n-i-1)for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]`

This is a list comprehension, the `0+(j==n-i-1)` is a shorter way to convert `j==n-i-1` to an int (as opposed to `int` function)
and then `m[-1]=m[0]` is shorter than making bottom right 1, as top and bottom rows are identical.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>59</s> <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```
(x=Sort@IdentityMatrix@#;x[[1,1]]=x[[#,#]]=1;x)&
```

The [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) has a diagonal of 1s, but it's going the wrong way. Sorting the rows fixes this. Then we set the corners to be 1 as well, and return the matrix.

You can test this out in the [Wolfram Cloud sandbox](http://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) by pasting code like the following and clicking "Evaluate cell" or hitting Shift+Enter or the numpad Enter:

`(x=Sort@IdentityMatrix@#;x[[1,1]]=x[[#,#]]=1;x)&@5//ArrayPlot`

---

## Longer solutions

```
SparseArray[#->1&/@{Band[{1,#},{#,1},{1,-1}],{1,1},{#,#}}]&
```

The `#->1&` is an anonymous function that associates the input with `1`, and the `Band` represents the coordinates from `{1,#}` to `{#,1}` going in steps of `{1,-1}`.

```
f[n_]:=Boole[#==#2==1||#==#2==n||#+#2==n+1]&~Array~{n,n}
```

This builds an `n` by `n` array where the values are `1` or `0` depending on the truth of "both indices are `1` or both indices are `n` or both indices sum to `n+1`".

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>216</s> <s>212</s> <s>186</s> <s>155</s> 145 Bytes

Just as a function that takes a matrix as input

```
f(int i,int **m){for(int a=0;a<i;a++){for(int b=0;b<i;b++){m[a][b]=((a+b+1==i)||(!a&&!b)||(a==i-1&&b==i-1))?1:0;printf("%d ",m[a][b]);}puts();}}
```

6 Bytes thanks to Conor O'Brien!

4 Bytes thanks to Zacharý!

**Old Answer**

```
main(int i){int**m=malloc(8*i);for(int a=0;a<i;a++){m[a]=malloc(4*i);for(int b=0;b<i;b++){m[a][b]=((a+b+1==i)||(a==0&&b==0)||(a==i-1&&b==i-1))?1:0;printf("%d ",m[a][b]);}printf("\n");}}
```

Instead of taking an array of arguments in the main function, it uses the length of arguments instead so the input for a 4x4 matrix would be:

[image]

Old Answer

```
main(int c,char **v){int i=atoi(v[1]);int**m=malloc(8*i);for(int a=0;a<i;a++){m[a]=malloc(4*i);for(int b=0;b<i;b++){m[a][b]=((a+b+1==i)||(a==0&&b==0)||(a==i-1&&b==i-1))?1:0;printf("%d ",m[a][b]);}printf("\n");}}
```

If only I could get rid of of those mallocs, I know C is not a great golfing language, but whatever!

Compiled with GCC on macOS Sierra.

### Ungolfed

```
main(int i) {
int **m = malloc(8 * i);    // Create n*n matrix
for(int a=0; a<i; a++) {    // Iterate through rows
    m[a] = malloc(4 * i);   // Allocate rows
    for(int b=0; b<i; b++) {    // Iteratre columns
        // Add a 1 to cell if its start or finish, or diagnol
        m[a][b]=((a+b+1==i)||(a==0&&b==0)||(a==i-1&&b==i-1))?1:0;
        printf("%d ",m[a][b]); // Print cell
    }
    printf("\n");           // Print row
}
```

### Usage

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks I just got start golfing, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you change your IO method to accepting a parameter as input, then outputting to STDOUT, then I think `f(i){int a,b;for(a=0;a<i;a++){for(b=0;b<i;b++)printf("%d ",a+b+1==i||!a&&!b||a==i-1&&b==i-1);printf("\n");}}` works.

Comment: Instead of `printf("\n")` you can do `puts("")`

Comment: Okay, is it okay if I post my solution separately due to the differing IO method?

Comment: Ya sure it's all casual for me

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 58 bytes

```
=If(A1=1,1,RegexReplace(Rept(10^(A1-2),A1+1)&1,"(.{"&A1&"})","$1
"))
```

Input is in `A1`.

Explanation:

- `10^(A1-2)` generates a one followed by `n-1` zeroes.
- `Rept(10^(A1-2),A1+1)&1` generates `n+1` copies of that sequence with
  an extra one at the end. For `n=5` as an example, that string is
  `1000100010001000100010001`.
- `RegexReplace(~,"(.{"&A1&"})","$1\n")`
  replaces every grouping of `n` characters with itself plus a line
  break. (In the actual formula, I use a literal line break rather than
  the escaped `\n`.)
- This breaks on `n=1` because `10^-1 = 0.1` so the string is `0.10.11`. The `If` at the beginning escapes that special case.

Results:

[image: Result]

<sub><sup><sup>I took the screenshot of exactly those cells and the image turned out to be 323 x 232 pixels. I think that's neato.</sup></sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 65 bytes

```cs
w=>{var l=new int[w*w];for(int i=0;i<w*w;i+=w-1)l[i]=1;return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY89awMxDIbn@FdoCfjyUXKz4yyFTi0UOnQINxhHaQWOfdi@mGLy26@6XDu0CGl4pfeRZNPWhojjkMh/wNtXynhRwpsLpt5YBF@FdSYl6KtI2WSycA10ghdDXjZVkM9Q6JQ/QUO7U@Jp8HbP4obz2B3gFaNFntFj0Yd6NRGc9lhgapdV6dQ5RDlBSO8U7VlStNZl2zbuSJ1uVcQ8RA9O3UYlJn8Ycj8w8Bct7@sbJf6RJnV1r0xcN6KKxWPwKTh8eI@UUc4g3sLeBZ0lLX8e0fNHfAP8cTyTR8nDtznGbw)

The algorithm is significantly distinct from the other C# answer, so I decided to post it separately rather than as an improvement. Inspired by the top rated Jelly answer actually, I was doing something slightly less compact before. The output is a linear array, so would require some logic to wrap it into a 2D outside the method as-is. An alternate version requires 6 additional bytes to output as a true 2D array:

```cs
w=>{var l=new int[w,w];for(int i=0;i<w*w;i+=w-1)l[i/w,i%w]=1;return l;}
```

I also have an interesting non-competing version.

```cs
using System.Linq;w=>new int[w*w].Select((_,i)=>i%(w-1)<1)
```

This ends up with almost the right output, resulting in an `IEnumerable<bool>` with true/false instead of 1/0, and it's a linear rather than 2D structure, and although not needed for that exact line of code, `using System.Collections.Generic` is necessary to do anything useful with the output. Like I said, it's very close to being valid but not quite.

Comment: For the second using a ternary as in `?1:0` works and I believe an array of the result should be fine. The collections using also isn't necessary for that code.

Comment: For the first, would setting `w*w` to a variable and moving the `int` declaration out of the loop save you anything?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Replacing the two instances of `w*w` with a single character variable saves 4 bytes, moving `int i=0` outside the loop requires a semicolon which costs 1 byte, and then adding `,s=w*w` to the declaration costs 6 bytes, so it actually nets +3 bytes.

Comment: You should use the byte count of the full 2D-representation solution. The array returned by the shorter solution would at least need to include some sort of delimiter to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 6 bytes

```
‹?²ʁḊẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%80%B9%3F%C2%B2%CA%81%E1%B8%8A%E1%BA%87&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
‹      # n-1
 ?²ʁ   # 0...n^2
    Ḋ  # Foreach, is it divisible by (n-1)?
     ẇ # Split into chunks of (implicit input) length.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 10 bytes

```
↯▽2:⊂1↘2⊚.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oav4pa9MjriioIx4oaYMuKKmi4KCkYgMQpGIDIKRiAzCkYgNApGIDUK)

Port of Adalynn's [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133919/97916).

```
↯▽2:⊂1↘2⊚.
         .  # duplicate
        ⊚   # list of n zeros
      ↘2    # drop first two
    ⊂1      # prepend one
↯▽2:        # reshape to nxn
```

Comment: TIL scalar where, nice

Comment: Alternate 10: [`↯:⊂1↘2⊃⊚⊟.`](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oavOuKKgjHihpgy4oqD4oqa4oqfLgoKRiAxCkYgMgpGIDMKRiA0CkYgNQo=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 44 bytes

```
\d+
$* 
 $
#
+` ( *)#( *)$
$&¶$1#$2 
^ | $
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0VLgUtBhUuZSztBQUNBS1MZRKhwqagd2qZiqKxipMAVp1ADUvD/vwkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>71 67 65</s> 76 bytes

```python
lambda n:n>1and''.join(' #'[i%~-n<1]+'\n'*(-~i%n<1)for i in range(n*n))or'#'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCsIwEAXQqwyUMjOVCqm4EfUirYtITR2xPyFk002vHn27l7byjjjVcJvq16/P2RMuuDuPmfn4iQZhani0du9xdY8DT@BO@t3afzXETEYGyh7LS9BBNWZuuKZsKEJBhrNq/QE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 24 bytes

```
.+
$* 
.
$'#$`¶
^ | ¶$
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRUuBS49LRV1ZJeHQNq44hRqFQ9tUuJT//zc0AAA) Explanation: The second line ends in a space, so the first stage converts the input into a row of spaces. The second stage then replaces each space in the row with a `#` in turn, collecting the resulting lines together. The final stage then adds the corner `#`s.

Answer (score 1):

## R (+pryr), 36 bytes

```
pryr::f(matrix(c(1,rep(0,n-1)),n,n))
```

Evaluates to the function:

```
function (n) 
matrix(c(1, rep(0, n - 1)), n, n)
```

Which is a port from [this APL answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133805/59530)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 131 bytes

```
<?$m=$n=0;while($m<$argv[1]){while($n<$argv[1]){echo($m==$n&&(!$m||$m==$argv[1]-1)||$m+$n==$argv[1]-1)*1;$n++;}echo"\n";$m++;$n=0;}
```

**Exploded view**

```
<?  $m = $n = 0;
    while ($m < $argv[1]) {
        while ($n < $argv[1]) {
            echo ($m == $n && (!$m || $m == $argv[1]-1) ||
                  $m + $n == $argv[1]-1) * 1;
            $n++;
        }
        echo "\n";
        $m++;
        $n = 0;
    }
```

Not my best work, I'm certain I can golf this down.

Comment: Add `$a=$argv[1];` at the beginning and replace all `$argv[1]` with `$a` to save several bytes.

Comment: Also take `$n=` out of the top 0 assignment and move `$n=0;` from the end of the outer loop to the beginning to save another 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>14</s> 18 bytes

A simple algorithm.

**Edit:** Fixing a bug for `n == 1`

```
;;D╤$0D@H@u*'1@+╪i
```

**Ungolfing**

```
                    Implicit input: n
;;                  Duplicate n twice.
  D╤$               Push str(10**(n-1))
     0D@H           Push str(10**(n-1))[:-1]
         @u*        Push str * (n+1)
            '1@+    Append a "1"
                ╪   Split into chunks of length n
                 i  Flatten this list onto the stack
                    Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/a2uXR1CUqBi4OHg6lWuqGDtqPpq7K/P/fFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 7 bytes

```
s…@(Ė¦/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/v/hRwzIHjSPTDi3T//@obeLD3UsVFB41zHFOzMlRKMlIVSgoyk8vSszVUwgoSi0pqQTyM/NKHjXMjflvaAAA)

#### Explanation

```
s        Square n
 …       Get the range from 0 to n^2-1
  @(     Push n-1
    Ė¦   For each number in the range, check if n-1 divides it
      /  Split into slices of size n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>67</s> 57 + 1 (`-p`) = 58 bytes

```perl
$\=$_=10**$_/10+($_>1);for$i(2..y///c){say;s/.//;$_.=0}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQy8zCCucTtBK7QTcIJKJAiJRsE@HVm97L23UMqjB7CF64bSGQcGcgjNK4PV0QTY/4ENHavGV5XCEkchDQc62vqnwp3zGdRe00IAurzT8)

Takes the input implicitly (-p). Convert that to 10 to the power of the input minus 1 and add one if the input is greater than one.  Outputs that as a string, then removes first character and appends a 0, looping until it has output n-1 rows.  For the last row, implicitly output the copy of the first row which has been stored in `$\`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 74 bytes

Essentially just a port of *Kamil*'s second C# solution [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137058/44945).

```java
n->{int g[][]=new int[n][n],i=0;for(;i<n*n;i+=n-1)g[i/n][i%n]=1;return g;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##fVBNS8NAED3bX7EUhESb1YKnpimIIHgQhBxjDut2GybdzIbdSSSU/Pa4mpYUKw57WHgf896UohWRqRWW2/1QNx8aJJNaOMdeBSA7zNhxagutIMUcCfKc0ut4Q6D5rkFJYJA/Hz/rFyRVKLtggJTlWb5hldirN2WlQkqhQJYMGG0OHmbFNyFB9flDxty/BST38c7YIIY13mAMtwlGy7DI4M7jcI15soytosYiK@J@uIqnkGOBY8bWwNavBgxSsoB@FRO2cOFZq9OknSNVcdMQ90WRNAZTw0drRee4I6tEFfzqwkVd6y54CMML09PwStQXdqsVmTHWP0JptFaSzsRjCP40AsY6XhpA7xLM33H@R4hwuk4/64cv)

Answer (score 1):

## [WC](https://wasp-compiled.firebaseapp.com), 92 bytes

```
;>_0|$-$-!!_1|;>@5|$''[<]!!$!_1|;>(?##@2|;>@5|$''[<<<]!!$!_1|?$-[>>>];</#)*$?!!_1|[>]!!$!_1|
```

#### Input

Artifact 0: a number ex. `5`

Artifact 1: a string ex. `#`

#### Output

```
#   #
   #
  #
 #
#   #
```

#### Explanation

```
;>_0|                  Create variable set to artifact 0
$-$-                   Decrement twice
!!_1|                  Print artifact 1 with no newline
;>@5|                  Create variable set to global 5 (the space character)
$''[<]                 Repeat variable times the previous variable
!!$                    Print with no newline
!_1|                   Print artifact 1 with newline
;>(                    Create variable as function
   ?                   Reset variable index to 0
   ##@_2|              Start if-not statement, runs if not global 2 (zero)
      ;>@5|            Create variable set to global 5 (the space character)
      $''[<<<]         Repeat variable times index-3 (first variable)
      !!$              Print with no newline
      !_1|             Print artifact 1 with newline
      ?$-              Reset index to 0 and decrement
      [>>>]            Move index up 3
      ;<               Delete at index
      /                Restart context
   #                   End statement
)                      End function
*$?                    Call function and reset index
!!_1|                  Print artifact 1 with no newline
[>]!!$                 Move index up 1 and print with no newline
!_1|                   Print artifact 1 with newline
```

**NOTE: Do NOT set artifact 1 to `1`, it will freeze. Works for n > 1**

[Try it online!](https://wasp-compiled.firebaseapp.com/?;%3E_0%7C$-$-!!_1%7C;%3E@5%7C$%27%27[%3C]!!$!_1%7C;%3E(?##@2%7C;%3E@5%7C$''[%3C%3C%3C]!!$!_1%7C?$-[%3E%3E%3E];%3C/#)*$?!!_1%7C[%3E]!!$!_1%7C&5,#)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 66 bytes

```perl5
$n=pop;$_='#';for$x(0..$n){$_.=$"x($n-2).'#'};s/(.{$n})/$1\n/g;say
```

Takes input as first command line argument.

Builds up a string of length `n^2` with `#` at the proper spots, then inserts newlines at the right places.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
´Ṫȯ¬%←¹+ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr///CtOG5qsivwqwl4oaQwrkrxYD///80) This function creates a matrix with indices from the range [0..**n**) and tests that their sum is divisible by **n** - 1.

Comment: [Another 9 byte solution](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr///CtOG5qj3huaA64oaSYOKApjL///81 "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
{(x,x)#1,2_&x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNCp0JT2VDHKF6tovZ/mrqhtqLpfwA)

Adapted from @Zacharý's [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133919/98547).

- `2_&x` generate x-2 copies of zero
- `1,` prepend a one
- `(x,x)` duplicate x
- `(...)#...` reshape into a x-by-x matrix

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 18 bytes

```
qi__))'#*\((S**/N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzAzPl5TU11ZK0ZDI1hLS99P6/9/QwMA)

Joins `n+2` hash characters together by `n-2` spaces, then splits into `n`-length groups and joins by newline.