# Help me accelerate linear recurrence relation!

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

### Background

A **[linear recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation)** is a description of a sequence, defined as one or more initial terms and a linear formula on last \$k\$ terms to calculate the next term. (For the sake of simplicity, we only consider *homogeneous* relations, i.e. the ones without a constant term in the formula.)

A formal definition of a linear recurrence relation looks like this, where \$y_n\$ is the desired sequence (1-based, so it is defined over \$n\ge 1\$) and \$x_i\$'s and \$a_i\$'s are constants:

$$
y_n =
\begin{cases}
x_n,  & 1\le n\le k \\
a_1y_{n-1}+a_2y_{n-2}+\cdots+a_ky_{n-k}, & k<n
\end{cases}
$$

In this challenge, we will accelerate this sequence by [converting it to a matrix form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Solution_by_conversion_to_matrix_form), so that the \$n\$-th term can be found by repeated squaring of the matrix in \$O(\log n)\$ steps, followed by inner product with the vector of initial terms.

For example, consider the famous Fibonacci sequence: its recurrence relation is \$y_n=y_{n-1} + y_{n-2}\$ with \$k=2\$, and let's use the initial values \$x_1=x_2=1\$. The recurrence relation can be converted to a matrix form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-1} \\ y_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_{n-1} \\ y_{n-1}+y_{n-2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-2} \\ y_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$

So multiplying the matrix once advances the sequence by one term. Since this holds for any \$n\$, it can be extended all the way until we reach the initial terms:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-1} \\ y_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-2} \\ y_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^2\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-3} \\ y_{n-2} \end{bmatrix} \\
= \cdots = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

In general, one way to construct such a matrix is the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-k+1} \\ y_{n-k+2} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n-1} \\ y_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ & \vdots & & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\ a_k & a_{k-1} & a_{k-2} & \cdots & a_1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_{n-k} \\ y_{n-k+1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n-2} \\ y_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that, if you reverse the vectors and the matrix in every dimension, the equation still holds, retaining the property of "advancing a term by matmul-ing once". (Actually any permutation will work, given that the rows and columns of the matrix are permuted in the same way.)

### Challenge

Given the list of coefficients \$a_1,\cdots,a_k\$, construct a matrix that represents the recurrence relation (so that its powers can be used to accelerate the computation of \$n\$-th term of the sequence).

You can take the coefficients in reverse order, and you can optionally take the value \$k\$ as a separate input. \$k\$ (the number of terms) is at least 1.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

In all cases, any other matrix that can be formed by permuting rows and columns in the same way is also valid.

```
Input
[1,1]
Output
[[0, 1],
 [1, 1]]

Input
[5]
Output
[[5]]

Input
[3, -1, 19]
Output
[[0,  1,  0],
 [0,  0,  1],
 [19, -1, 3]]
or reversed in both dimensions:
[[3, -1, 19],
 [1, 0,  0],
 [0, 1,  0]]
or cycled once in both dimensions:
[[3, 19, -1],
 [0, 0,  1],
 [1, 0,  0]]
etc.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @LuisMendo

```
Xy4LY)i
```

Takes the coefficients in reverse order

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6LSxCdSM/P/f2OuaGMFXUMFQ8vY/wA)

### Explanation

```
Xy4LY)i
Xy        : Create an identity matrix of size equal to input
  4LY)    : Remove the first row
      i   : Insert input onto the stack
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>10</sup> 8 bytes

Returns the matrix reversed in both dimensions.

```
,}:@=@/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/dWqtHGwd9K3@a/63SVMwVDDkAlKmIMJYIR7ItQQA)

#### How it works

```
 ,}:@=@/:   input:             3 _1 19
       /:   indices that sort: 1 0 2
            (just to get k different numbers)
     =@     self-classify:     1 0 0
                               0 1 0
                               0 0 1
  }:@       drop last row:     1 0 0
                               0 1 0
 ,          prepend input:     3 _1 19
                               1  0  0
                               0  1  0
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map((_,i)=>i?a.map(_=>+!--i):a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQEMjXidT09Yu0x7Cjbe101bU1c3UtErU/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmEW2oo2AYq6nJhSZsikXMWEdBF6TcEij3HwA)

Returns:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_{k-1} & a_k \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 56 bytes

```
method(a,a map(i,v,if(i<1,a,a map(I,v,if(I==i-1,1,0)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0UjUSdRITexQCNTp0wnM00j08ZQBybkCRHytLXN1DXUMdQx0ASB/2kaOZnFJRpAEU3NgqLMvJKcPC6omKmmpgKakLGOAlCzgqElQuo/AA)

### Explanation

```
method(a,                                              )   // Input an array.
         a map(i,v,                                   )    // Map. i = index, v = value
                   if(i<1,                           )     //     If the indice is 0,
                          a,                               //         Return the inputted list
                            a map(I,v,              )      //     Otherwise, map: (I is the current index)
                                      if(I==i-1,   )       //     If I == i-1,
                                                1,         //         Return 1,
                                                  0        //     Otherwise 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

```apl
⊢⍪¯1↓⍋∘.=⍋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXoke9qw6tN3zUNvlRb/ejjhl6tkD6f9qjtgmPevsedTU/6l3zqHfLofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cD1VQDOWClWx91t0DY6upwZpoChoS6ei1XuoKhgiGIBBpsCqSNFYAOUDC0BAA)

Tacit function taking the list of coefficients on the right.

### Explanation

```apl
⊢⍪¯1↓⍋∘.=⍋
     ⍋   ⍋  ⍝ Grade up to obtain a list of k distinct values
      ∘.=   ⍝ Outer product with operation `equals` (identity matrix)
  ¯1↓       ⍝ Drop the last row
⊢⍪          ⍝ Prepend the list of coefficients
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda l,k:[l]+zip(*[iter(([1]+[0]*k)*~-k)]*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBDoIwEETv/Yq9sUUgovEgiV9SOWAoccOyNG094MFfr4U5vZm8jNvie5VLmuABz8TD8hoH4GruDPenLzksDUXrEU3bn8y5L2dd/upZ75BocauPELag1LR6YBILJPvQhDiSdApyOH/Hj2OLy@CQJFaH2QTHFLGAQmt9iJJFtoKs1dGdzzJOyBWI1qmFVt3UFeoM9z8)

Takes input as a tuple `l` and number of terms `k`, and outputs with both rows and columns reversed.

The idea is to use the [zip/iter trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184881/20260) to create an identity-like matrix by splitting a repeating list into chunks. The is similar to my solution to [construct the identity matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70415/20260) but changed to have one fewer row by changing the inner multiplier `k` to `k-1` (written `~-k`).

Comment: Cool, a nice trick of which I was unaware!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>60</s></sup> 58 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan

```python
lambda a,k:[map(i.__eq__,range(k))for i in range(1,k)]+[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwEETv@Yq9maWpINJDhX6JlbDF2C7RmCa5@PU2plDonnaHN7Pjt/RaXbtPcIP7PtPyGAlI2a5fyEuutTZvrVUg9zTSIk5rAAZ28FUaZXE49TTsvPg1JIhbFOKAZnbm4LJQxzSy6wTkofxn5phkiXdJFbCOfuYkK6gQsXD24IyThKLcPmRY9v9WRoRfoUmSgtwG9wYacREtnPNy/QA)

Takes the coefficients in reverse order

Comment: -1 byte: `lambda a,k,r=range(k):[[i==j for j in r]for i in r[1:]]+[a] `

Comment: @ManfP - that's invalid, `k` is not defined at the point it's being used by `range` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##HY0xDsMgEAR7XnFdQCGWLCtFLPESQnGR7eQMxgho/HoCXDW7O9KFK/9OP5UNFLyLw@OzIKC0MqqI/rtyK2atSakdtjPCDuQhmobUUY@zMXeNptARzpghXYmxtjvya1NqMaS8kJ8Z1MP6yFHK/MDAyWfZxSEFR5nf4CaE6J5t3uo5CtZziFXmG0cJVogywsiebIJHhdcf)).

Comment: `lambda a,k:[map(i.__eq__,range(k))for i in range(1,k)]+[a]` is 58. Returns a list of iterables, and `False==0` and `True==1`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh sorry you are totally right, the perils of testing locally with shadowing variable names...

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩＥθ⎇κＥθ⁼⊖κμθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyEktSgvsahSI1tHASriWliamFOs4ZKaXJSam5pXkpqika2po5CrCSQKNYHA@v//6GhjHQVDSx0FXcPY2P@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Produces the "reversed in both directions" output. Works by replacing the first row of a shifted identity matrix with the input. Explanation:

```
 Ｅθ             Map over input list
   ⎇κ           If this is not the first row then
     Ｅθ         Map over input list
       ⁼⊖κμ     Generate a shifted identity matrix
           θ    Otherwise replace the first row with the input
Ｉ               Cast to string for implicit print
```

Comment: @xash Actually I was thinking of a different permutation, but either way I've probably misunderstood the question. I'll rewrite it to use the `reversed in both directions` option.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(r,k)rbind(diag(k)[-1,],r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoAwDADA3Vd0TCAdgjgI@hJx0NbUUokQ6vurLrecNXGTd00eDTXfCkZlvg5N9QRDtD1rhJi3BAUXz7SSYRMIwMSIncDwE6CnL3lEbC8)

Takes the length as well; the TIO link has a `k=length(r)` argument so you can just input the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
āDδQ`\)
```

Outputs reversed in both dimensions.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKPLuS2BCTGa//9HG@voGuoYWsYCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/I40u57YEJsRo/tf5Hx1tqGMYqxNtCsTGOrpAjiWIp2OkY6pjEhsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā        # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the implicit input-list)
 D       # Duplicate it
  δ      # Apply double-vectorized:
   Q     # Check if it's equal
         # (this results in an L by L matrix filled with 0s, with a top-left to
         #  bottom-right diagonal of 1s; where `L` is the length of the input-list)
    `    # Pop and push all rows of this matrix separated to the stack
     \   # Discard the last row
      )  # And wrap all list on the stack into a list
         # (after which the matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
W;J⁼þṖ$$
```

A monadic Link accepting a list which yields a list of lists in the reversed rows & columns permutation.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/c2utR457D@x7unKai8v///2hjHQVdQx0FQ8tYAA)**

#### How?

```
W;J⁼þṖ$$ - Link: list A                    e.g. [5,2,5,4]
W        - wrap (A) in a list                   [[5,2,5,4]]
       $ - last two links as a monad - f(A):
  J      -   range of length (A)                [1,2,3,4]
      $  -   last two links as a monad - f(J):
     Ṗ   -     pop                              [1,2,3]
    þ    -     (J) outer product (that) with:
   ⁼     -       equals?                        [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]
 ;       - (W) concatenate (that)               [[5,2,5,4],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>90</s> <s>89</s></sup> 80 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
i;j;f(a,k)int*a;{for(i=k;i--;puts(""))for(j=k;j--;)printf("%d ",i?i-1==j:a[j]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJRa4MwEMff/RRHoJDYyKqlD20qfRh72NM@gMoItm7RLi1qoaz42d1FTVuUBSSX@//ur3cm9b7StG2VyEVGJS@Y0rUrxS07lVSFhVCeJ86XuqKEMGaSOSZzTLJziWhGyWwPhKud8vwwzDcyyhMmmrZTqTGDIwfcQTO4OYALXcAooCCEhcBtC1rAfK4Y3E2r2Z5g3Y4A2RCMjpFCX6dxTOGPVJoyp7czifpQ1Z9yESXoePM5@I0YaX6vrSZC0AtLDp4pXD8AdyCqnhjewa2hDYKxZdHzAbpxWA5q@i1LF8peIvH1LYiv61d8Vtjc83lJsGI0J70/XIdZdeEWKvV7OGV0@ED2Mpxdm@jGaVg79HtPEo1sXx2RiGcAoLBAMdHt33nXeCViTdhI6i7QFI/1x6WeVGT/0N59PfjGado/)

Inputs an array of coefficients (in forward order) along with its length.
Prints a matrix that represents the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 52

Closing Parens discounted.

- Input cells is Row `1`, starting in column `B`.
- `A2` - `=COUNTA(1:1)`. Rules say that we can take this as input too, so I have discounted this as well. (Our "k")
- `A3` - `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(0^MOD(SEQUENCE(A2-1,A2)-1,A2+1)))`

The output matrix starts in `B1`.

### How it works

1. Since this is a spreadsheet, the input cells give us free output too. As long is it's the first row and we end up with a square set of cells, we're good. If this didn't count, we'd have to do this with Column 1 instead to use `TRANSPOSE()` to copy the input. (Because it's smaller than `ArrayFormula()`)
2. Cache the number of columns in A2
3. Generate a **k-1** x **k** matrix using `SEQUENCE`. Values are `MOD` number of columns + 1. (Diagonals are 0, otherwise something else).
4. Since `0^0` is `1` in Sheets, that means this effectively is a Boolean `NOT()` converted to an integer.
5. `IFERROR` handles input size of 1. (Output a Blank)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

```
a->matcompanion(x^#a-Pol(a))~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P1HXLjexJDk/tyAxLzM/T6MiTjlRNyA/RyNRU7Puf2JBQU6lRqKCrp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkgRToKERHG@oYxgJpUxBhrKOga6ijYGgZG6v5HwA)