# Diagonalize a vector

Tags: code-golf, math, array, matrix, linear-algebra

Diagonalize a vector into a matrix.

### Input

A vector, list, array, etc. of integers \$\mathbf{v}\$ of length \$n\$.

### Output

A \$n \times n\$ matrix, 2D array, etc. \$A\$ such that for each element \$a_i \in \mathbf{v}\$,

$$
A = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0  & a_2 & \cdots &  0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n
\end{array} \right)
$$

where the diagonal of \$A\$ is each element in \$\mathbf{v}\$.

### Notes

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program or function in bytes wins!
- [Construct the Identity Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/construct-the-identity-matrix) may be of use to you.
- If the length of \$\mathbf{v}\$ is 0, you may return an empty vector, or an empty matrix.
- If the length of \$\mathbf{v}\$ is 1, you must return a \$1 \times 1\$ matrix.

### Not Bonus

You can receive this Not Bonus if your program is generic across any type, using the type's zero-value (if it exists) in place of \$0\$.

### Test Cases

```python
[] -> []
[0] -> [[0]]
[1] -> [[1]]
[1, 2, 3] -> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3]]
[1, 0, 2, 3] -> [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3]]
[1, -9, 1, 3, 4, -4, -5, 6, 9, -10] -> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10]]
```

Comment: Suggested test case: a vector containing 0

Answer (score 11):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
{x*=#x}
```

My first K post. I tried real hard to make a Bubbler train work here but failed.

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qu0LJVrqjl4krT0ORKUzAAYkMQVjBSMAbTBnCWriWQMFYwUdAFIlMFMwVLBV1DAwDqfA0a)

Comment: Nice! I think the bubbler train version is possible but likely longer. I came up with: ```*/(=#:)\```

Comment: Ah, that looks cool, very nice. I am hoping my next K solution will be less trivial :P

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```
f[]=[];f(a:b)=(a:map(0*)b):map(0:)(f b)
```

Recursively generates the matrix by appending a value at the top left corner of a smaller matrix.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Xd
```

The code uses the builtin function `Xd` (which corresponds to MATLAB's `diag`). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyLl//9oQx0FAx0FIx0F41gA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
J=þ`a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/L9vC@hMT/h9vdNbMeNe7j4vr/PzpWRyHaEEzoKBjpKBhDmbqWOgpAylhHwQTIAWFTHQUzHQWgsK6hQSwA)

```
J=þ`     Identity matrix:
  þ      table
J        [1 .. length]
   `     with itself
 =       by equality.
    a    Vectorizing logical AND; replace ones with elements of the vector.
```

If output can be flat:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
jn`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8rL@H/4XZ3zaxHjfu4uP7/j47VUYg2BBM6CkY6CsZQpq6ljgKQMtZRMAFyQNhUR8FMRwEorGtoEAsA)

```
j      Join the vector on
 n     the list of, for each element, if it doesn't equal
  `    itself.
```

If the empty vector didn't have to be handled, this could tie non-flat as `` jn`sL ``; it passes all current test cases as `j¬` owing to all inputs being nonzero (which is not guaranteed by the spec).

Answer (score 5):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>135</s> 130 bytes

```go
func(v[]int)(A[][]int){for i,_:=range v{r:=make([]int,len(v))
for j,_:=range v{e:=0
if i==j{e=v[i]}
r[j]=e}
A=append(A,r)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZU9LasMwEN3rFNOsJBgXp2lLa9DCN-jemCBSKciJx0a1vRHe9BrdmEIv0xvkNpVikwS6EO-jmeG9r-99M53uWrU7qL2GWllizNZt47r7lam7FRuUAyN_-s4kL6dP09OOD0VpqRM8L8qZedM4sLjNpFMUzgzeZbJWB83P_3jUxAchWByrbsd0JlNmDVgpK6_lUNhyZK6oSqlHlkvVtpreeY5OBFt3vaNxSfIbk5zzcgGeWfqATMISyLMZRlxIemHrK0N4QNjc6vS_lbwiBNggPAYR3xPCM0Kwk3U8O55bbdFSDDAXi2k8e3PhxpG4JXHhJqqrFGF9aTRNM_4B)

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>141</s> 136 bytes + Not Bonus

```go
func f[T any](v[]T)(A[][]T){for i,_:=range v{r:=make([]T,len(v))
for j,_:=range v{var e T
if i==j{e=v[i]}
r[j]=e}
A=append(A,r)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVBBasMwEKRXvWLxSQKlJE2TtgEd8oMWcjMmqIkUlNiKkR1DEbr3D72EQj_Rn7Sv6SpOYkNBo51d7Q6z-vjc7I_fpVzt5EZBIY0lxBTl3tW3iS7q5OtQ68Hjz7s-2BXodAHSvmW0SbMFo_M0i9HrvQPDlzPhpEWRxruZKOROUXzlubK0YYzEpm2_qZEOFCyI0WCE2HolmtRkgbh0mwkVyFzIslR2TefcMSyr-uBsaP383rycDEW_lIEnxlYwExANGVt70obAz2R4ZaOOcbjjMO7nw_-lwRMHDGMO95hETDhMOWB5MIqy4bTZkhsbDbTLRTeePDvUyC01ll25jlmXMhwnZ-dVjcWNT2TCk1fECoFnjVAInYTrWNUXrFCP5P3t23sSeEumF_IQOom8L5GjxPlnj8c2_gE)

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 4 bytes

```matlab
diag
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f//f0pmYrqGoZWhgeZ/AA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 23 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
diag
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhbb04rycxXySnMLKhUycwvyi0q0uFIyE9MhsjsKijLzSjRAAhpFiXnpqRqGOoZGmpqaEGmYIQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
foldr(\a m->(a:(0<$m)):map(0:)m)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLbsMgELz7K@aQA0hraZ20lWrF/YN@AeGAXLu1YmIr9rHfXgo4fdiRQMCyM8MurPbDTOem711bnVw79G9XcTKw@YswpeDjzkpZWjMKLqWVSru5mebaTM2ECiqDH0JpgtKSbh4H1@9/SBGR4j9C2BMOC05gP8OZI/xz5KBY3eH7ayv52ttvuU20/JngzYHw4J2wHglPBA/nBW@S3M9b6BAlKeCYJclzfEWS5/jKJM/LL5ICXn6ZFHCsQpLnWKUkz0sVtdRZZk138f3i@@gV47W7zNhBiRZdVQ0EbyU@IToaJI45fltMu6@67c375PJ6HL8B)

Uses the recursive method [from Magma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262878/20260) of expanding the matrix with a new value in the top left, but with `foldr` and `<$`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes

```
x:ᵒ-¬*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FisrrB5unaR7aI3WkuKk5GKo6IKbrtGxXNEGQGwIwjoKRjoKxhCWATJH11JHAUgZ6yiYADkgbKqjYKajABTWNTSIhZgGAA)

Multiplies the identity matrix like other answers.

```
x:ᵒ-¬*
x       [0 .. length - 1]
 :      Duplicate
  ᵒ     Outer product with
   -        Subtract
    ¬   Logical NOT
     *  Multiply
```

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, 9 bytes

Thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att) for -4

```
⊢×⍤1⍋∘.=⍋­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⊢          # ‎⁡v
 ×⍤1       # ‎⁢multiplied row-wise with
    ⍋∘.=⍋  # ‎⁣the identity matrix of size (#v)
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire)

### Dyalog APL, 16 bytes + Not Bonus

The only other applicable scalar type are characters, where APL uses the space as the empty character, so this code also does

```
,⍨∘≢⍴∊⍤(⊢↑¨⍨1+≢)­⁡‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏⁡⁠⁡‌⁢‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏⁡⁠⁡‌⁣‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏⁡⁠⁡‌⁤‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏⁡⁠⁡‌­
    ⍴             # ‎⁡Reshape
,⍨∘≢              # ‎⁢to (#v)*(#v) matrix 
     ∊⍤           # ‎⁣the flattened list of lists built by
        ⊢ ¨       # ‎⁤taking each item of v
         ↑ ⍨      # ‎⁢⁡and padding it with
            1+≢   # ‎⁢⁢(#v) zeros
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire)

This works by noticing that, if the diagonalized matrix is read as a single list, row by row, each entry of `v` is spaced with as many zeros as the length of `v`.

Comment: 9 on the first: `⊢×⍤1⍋∘.=⍋`

Comment: @att nice solution, will add!

Comment: @att I somehow forgot about the Rank operator, was struggling for a while to get vec × matrix to work

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
*[:=#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/taKtbJVj/mtypSZn5CukKairQ1gwOk1Bx8oQXcgICI2B0OQ/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ėDȷ=×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5N0QlQzglQjclM0QlQzMlOTcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yJTJDMyUyQzUmZmxhZ3M9)

Inspired by Unrelated String's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ėDȷ=×  # Implicit input
ė      # Length range
 D     # Duplicate
  ȷ    # Outer product over:
   =   #  Check for equality
    ×  # Multiply by the input
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to xnor*

```python
def f(a,i=0):
 for b in a:l=a[i]=[0]*len(a);l[i]=b;i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJLTsMwEJVY5hRDVwlMpEnLt5UXnMPywqG2sLCSKA4LbsAd2HQDd4LT4E9a0VZy5Ngz7z2P7dH7_B7ep5e-2-2-3iZdP_zcb5UGXUo0jKp1AbofoQXTgVxbJrkRjJO4sqorZbWxIW835po1afvvxcek3PQsnXLAgBecCwQuBPqIBIYpJU3A_TxnCEuEVcIQyI8QU4T3IQXFQU_nW46kx9nylPtXqX5E8MsK4cYn4b9FuEPwcN3QyQHnYy4bqmQFFE_J8hRvkeUp3jLLU3pFVkDplVkBxS5keYpdyvKUuui_oghmMtgHOx1s4j3m_WYqvxgNBi4Z9AEDGEbTTeVCS2PVdoEQNQDtqORroaxTQTaLnqyNJR0M0jkvr5Ih977-Aw)

[Outputs by modifying arguments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/70761).

Comment: [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJLTsMwEJVY5hRDVwlMpEnLt5UXnMPywqG2sLCSKA4LbsAd2HQDd4LT4E9a0VZy5Ngz7z2P7dH7_B7ep5e-2-2-3iZdP_zcb5UGXUo0jKp1AbofoQXTgVxbJrkRjJO4sqorZbWxIW835po1afvvxcek3PQsnXLAgBecCwQuBPqIBIYpJU3A_TxnCEuEVcIQyI8QU4T3IQXFQU_nW46kx9nylPtXqX5E8MsK4cYn4b9FuEPwcN3QyQHnYy4bqmQFFE_J8hRvkeUp3jLLU3pFVkDplVkBxS5keYpdyvKUuui_oghmMtgHOx1s4j3m_WYqvxgNBi4Z9AEDGEbTTeVCS2PVdoEQNQDtqORroaxTQTaLnqyNJR0M0jkvr5Ih977-Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 67 bytes

```haskell
f v=m.(m.).h where m g=map g[0..length v-1];h z i j|i==j=v!!i|1>0=z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVJLTsMwFJRY5hRTiUUiOdFLCwgEZsOWHcsoiwicT8mnatxUqnITNt0gzgSnwbHbQlLJln9vZvxsP83HV56076Is9_vPjUz92--nFB2vArcKvCDHNhdrgQoZr5IVsoiCoBR1JnN0fhjf59ihwLIvOF_ybjYr-vCR-M6k-rnopGjla9KKFhyRA9XcKGaIYo8dIhpCNf8hoUbC_wjDnGFhcAZSfdiTho9bGhSjM3R-bCQfR_MpN8nm3zGoZcFwpYJhXDPcMCjYD2lyyXk_pB6yWAWkb7HypF9h5Um_0sqT-YVVQOaXVgHpKlh50lWy8mSqGHux41RJUSu_rDbyRa6fa1yizZutWpKyRPGGKFWeI3COBj3cgjUeHnycvBYb-x0d_Qs)

Answer (score 4):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, 62 bytes

```typescript
type F<V>={[I in keyof V]:{[J in keyof V]:J extends I?V[J]:0}}
```

[Try it at the TypeScript Playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPANQHwF4DeBtAklAlgOygGsIQB7AMygQF0AuTAKT0JPKtruYgA9gJ8AEwDOULAH4EGRvQAMAX3kAoJaEhQAKhGHAAjFBSw4GWTSQBuJQHorUOwD1xq8NC06ATAaMZdAGiju-gDMZta2Dk5qrtrAQV7wPv6y-oFQIUhhdlCOzupuwAAs8cZ+UAC0AJz+pUH+Bf5l9eUArP4AbP5V5bqmGTZZOUA)

It's been a little while since I've golfed in TS types, so it's possible (though I think unlikely) that I missed a shorter way to do this. This one is pretty simple, but I'll leave an explanation anyway:

```typescript
type F<V> =           // type F taking generic tuple type V
  { [I in keyof V]:   // for each I in V's indices:
    { [J in keyof V]: //   for each J in V's indices:
      J extends I     //     are J and I the same type?
        ? V[J]        //       if so, index into V with J
        : 0           //       otherwise, 0
    }                 //   end
  }                   // end
```

I tried putting `keyof V` into `type F<V,K=keyof V>` but that doesn't work since the compiler complains that `K` could be a type unrelated to an array key, and it doesn't save enough bytes for `//ts-ignore` to be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

## PARI/GP, 11 bytes

```
matdiagonal
```

Builtins are always a sad answer, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 15 bytes

```
diagonal-matrix
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoQckijKTU4sVCopSS0oqC4oy80oUilMLS1PzQKKZ@QrWXFzVXApAUK1QC6UN4CxDJJaBgpGCMZBfqxD9PyUzMT0/LzFHF2x@xf/izNyCnFTdksSknFQ9hbwchViF1MTkjP8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 9 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
-∘⍳⍤≢↑⍤0⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=033UMeNR7@ZHvUsedS561DYRyDB41LUIAA&f=S1N41LuGK03BAIgNQVjBSMEYTBvAWYfWWwJJYwUTIAuETRXMFCyBtCFIk3pJanGJOlideqI61DQNAwUNQwWNR11NOkaamppAvRo6j3pXPOqYARR61LvY5FHXIlNNBQ11M3UFc00A&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Left-pads each \$v_i\$ to a vector of length \$i\$ and implicitly mixes.

Each row's fill elements match the type of the corresponding element of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map((v,i)=>x.map(_=>i--?0:v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU1LCoMwEL3KLBOYEa220JboQUIowU9JUSNVQm6fjlIX77t472ODXduvWzaafdenQaWo6phNdhEioJNneKnaETX5I0iZnlobBF0chHBBKP@W7ggsJULFYccV4YbANRW5MccWP7R@Xv3YZ6N/i0FEyaPpBw)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 33 bytes

```
=IFERROR(MUNIT(ROWS(A1#))*A1#,"")
```

## Excel, 39 bytes + Not Bonus

```
=IFERROR(IF(MUNIT(ROWS(A1#)),A1#,0),"")
```

Input is *vertical* spilled range `A1#`.

Having to deal with the empty vector is inconvenient; otherwise these would be just 21 and 27 bytes respectively.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yUzMT0/LzHHN7GkKLPif1p0UGJeemq0oY6hgY5hbKy@fkBRZl7JfwA)

```
DiagonalMatrix
```

Comment: Does it work for empty vector? I tried passing `{}`, but got an error, but maybe I'm doing something wrong? (I don't speak Mathematica well)

Answer (score 3):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 9 bytes

`#äLºµÍ·®£`

prints the elements of the matrix separated by spaces, with `,` separating the rows. Does not print the zero entries above the diagonal.

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=itr&src=I-RMurXNt66j&in=WzEsIDAsIDIsIDNd)

## Explanation

```
#          ; read array from standard input
 äLº       ; push the range from zero to array.length-1
    µÍ     ; replace each element in the range with a vector having a one at the given index
           ; this will give an identity matrix of size array.length represented as 2D array 
      ·    ; point-wise multiplication
       ®   ; convert result to matrix
        £  ; print
```

---

## Itr, <s>10</s> [9 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=itr&src=I0y6tc23riuj&in=WzEsIDAsIDIsIDNd)

<s>`#äLºµÍ·®+£`</s> (broken in current version)

`#LºµÍ·®+£`

Adds zero to the result to force the entries above the diagonal to be printed.

---

## Itr, [8 bytes](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=itr&src=I0y6tc23rqM&in=WzEsIDAsIDIsIDNd)

`#LºµÍ·®£`

the `ä` before the `L` is no longer necessary in newer versions

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 20 bytes

```r
\(x)diag(x,sum(x|1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZbYjQqNFMyE9M1KnSKS3M1KmoMNTUhUjcT0jSSNTQ1uUCUAZQ2hNJGML6OkY4xnG2AwlPQtdRRAFLGOgomQA4Im-oomOkoAIV1DQ1g9ixYAKEB)

The `diag` built-in almost works here, but fails for inputs of length 1, where it produces identity matrix of size of the input. Unless specified `nrow` argument.

---

Less boring - without `diag` built-in:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 54 bytes

```r
\(x,`[`=matrix)c(x,rep(0*x,n<-sum(x|1)))[n+1,n,T][n,n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3zWI0KnQSohNscxNLijIrNJOB3KLUAg0DrQqdPBvd4tJcjYoaQ01Nzeg8bUOdPJ2Q2Og8nbxYqO6ENI1kDU1NLhBlAKUNobQRjK9jpGMMZxug8BR0LXUUgJSxjoIJkAPCpjoKZjoKQGFdQ6CJEHsWLIDQAA)

Idea: construct a vector such that every entry of the input \$x\$ of length \$n\$ is followed by \$n\$ zeros. A matrix with \$x\$ in the first row and followed by \$n\$ rows of zeros works too. Then, we can put this in a \$n\times n\$ `matrix` resulting in \$x\$ on the diagonal.

Ungolfed:

```r
\(x){n=length(x)
m=matrix(c(x,rep(0,n^2)), nrow=n+1, ncol=n, byrow=TRUE)
matrix(m, nrow=n, ncol=n)}
```

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 27 bytes

```r
\(v,x=seq(a=v))v*!x%o%x-x^2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuha7YzTKdCpsi1MLNRJtyzQ1y7QUK1TzVSt0K-KMICpuJqRpJGtoanKBKAMobQiljWB8HSMdYzjbAIWnoGupowCkjHUUTIAcEDbVUTDTUQAK6xoCTYTYs2ABhAYA)

Heavily inspired by [@Kirill L.'s answer to the linked challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163556/55372).

Comment: You could also do `diag(sum(x|1))*x`

Comment: @Giuseppe you're right, but it's less obvious why it works ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 23 bytes

```python
import numpy
numpy.diag
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhbbM3ML8otKFPJKcwsqucCkXkpmYjpEdldBUWZeiQZCWCPaSMdYxzRWUxOiAGYMAA)

Comment: I tried with `[['a'],['b'],['c']]`, and it gives just `['a']` as the output.

Comment: Oh oops, it doesn't seem to work for lists :(. It works for numbers and strings though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 25 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.125 bytes

```
LÞ□*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#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)

The `P` flag on the permalink is to make the test cases pass (for some strange reason, I never made it not check exact string representation.) Individual cases all produce the right output with vyxal list syntax without the flag.

### Explained

```
LÞ□*­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
L     # ‎⁡Push the length of the input
 Þ□   # ‎⁢Construct an NxN identity matrix
   *  # ‎⁣and pair-wise vectorise multiplication
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>83</s> 81 bytes

Simple and dirty imperative solution.

-2 bytes by taking a slice instead of a vec

```rust
|v:&[i8]|{let l=v.len();let mut r=vec![vec![0;l];l];for i in 0..l{r[i][i]=v[i]}r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3NCoMwEITvfYrxIgoxxNqWtiFPIjn0x5RATCHVXNRnT6O9tVKY3WW@2WVd/@qCsmgv2mY5BtN0UBBh9Oe01kc5LsQIT00TF/js2r6DE765JfXSGDdylno6aGgLRqkZXK1llPCxTW4KfHO/PpJMZelyJPP8i7BfVK4ggi1BtRqwP1lxIoijIthFM9ee4EAQcVF@Xk/hDQ)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>126</s> 124 bytes + Not Bonus

The Copy bound is technically too strict and a Clone bound would be enough, but it would also be one byte longer *:shrug:*.

```rust
fn f<T:Default+Copy>(v:&[T])->Vec<Vec<T>>{let l=v.len();let mut r=vec![vec![T::default();l];l];for i in 0..l{r[i][i]=v[i]}r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NDoIwEIX3nmLcmDYWAqImFuhGj0DcEBYIrSEpYCo0MYSzYyvu0GR@8r6ZvBnVP7tpEg2IKKEXLvJedttz@3gxpOkmTTLssCsvIpsJY4PkHchYu5I3CIdW1X0HKta8WKefklBazj52IbMhWgUVVA14risHlVaZiVibMqrRHq/zytjBsCpv9zUSlEYImwesXYZx@MUz8BbEXxICOwLBL@79HzknAqYFBPZG2DwQOBIw2PHns@P0Bg)

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 53 bytes

<sup>Hover over any symbol to see what it does</sup>

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoibDo6MCk/XFw7XG4kOkA6P3ZcXFxuMS0yMS5cXDomezp9MGw1LSY9PyRufjlvXG5+MS0xMC5cXH57fmFvIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IjI5MiAxOSAyNyAxMiA4MTIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

Comment: ahhh that's a lotta broken images lol

Comment: This is a very cool but strange way to explain a program lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-P`, 6 bytes

```
g*EY#g
```

(The flag is only necessary to format the output in a readable way; any of `-P`, `-p`, `-S` will do.)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboBS7IKlpSVpuhbL0rVcI5XTIRyo2JpoQx0FAx0FIx0FY5g6AA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
g*EY#g
     g  ; List of command-line arguments
    #   ; Length
  EY    ; Identity matrix of that size
g*      ; Multiply each row by the corresponding element of g
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
×⊞=.⍏.
```

-1 thanks to Bubbler

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RiDihpAgw5fiip49LuKNjy4KCkYgW10KRiBbMV0KRiBbMSAyIDEgMl0KRiBbMSAwIDEgMl0=)

```
×⊞=.⍏.
     .  # duplicate
 ⊞=.⍏   # identity matrix
×       # multiply
```

Comment: I think you need an extra ```⇡⧻``` or similar to cope with [1 2 1 2]....

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks, fixed.

Comment: You can get a vector of unique elements in 1 byte using `⍏`, which saves a byte over `⇡⧻`.

Comment: @Bubbler Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes

```python
def f(a):n=range(len(a));return[[(i==j)*a[i]for i in n]for j in n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3nVJS0xTSNBI1rfJsixLz0lM1clLzgFxN66LUktKivOhojUxb2yxNrcTozNi0_CKFTIXMPIU8MDMLwoSapBxdUJSZV6KRqakAV5emATHTUEfB0FBTE6oUZjkA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes

```python
def f(a):x=len(a);return[[0]*i+[a[i]]+[0]*(x+~i)for i in range(x)]
```

This solution was inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70368/106829) answer.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3nVJS0xTSNBI1rSpsc1LzgAzrotSS0qK86GiDWK1M7ejE6MzYWG0QR6NCuy5TMy2_SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vo0IzFmqScnRBUWZeiUampgJcTZoGRJWhjoKhoSZMKcxyAA)

Comment: [61 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3bXMSc5NSEhXKrKKjDWK1MrWjy6IzY2O1QRyNnNQ8jTJN7bpMzbT8IoVMhcw8haLEvPRUqIRmLNQQ5eiCosy8Eo1MTQW4wjQNiFJDHQVDQ7jSBQsgNAA)

Comment: @EthanC [56 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXISc5NSEhXKdDJtDayiow1itTK1o5NitUEsjZzUPI0yTV2NTCvbTG1DTc20_CKFJIXMPIWyWKh-5eiCosy8Eo1MTQWQZCZIMk2jKDEvPVXDUEfBEKgJqnTBAggNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes + Not Bonus

```
⭆¹ＥθＥθ×⁼μξν
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBjqKICoQjgVkpmbWqzhWliamFOskaujUKGpo5CnCQLW//9HRwPVG@goGOkoGMfG/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input array
  Ｅ         Map over elements
     θ      Input array
    Ｅ       Map over elements
        μ   Row index
       ⁼    Equals
         ξ  Column index
      ×     Multiplied by
          ν Inner element
⭆¹          Pretty-print
```

Using `And` instead of `Times` would have made the code minusculely more efficient but this way the code produces empty strings on the non-diagonal entries when given a string array as input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org), 97 bytes; Not Bonus

```rkt
(define(f v)(let([n(length v)])(for/list([i(range n)])(list-set(make-list n 0)i(list-ref v i)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09DsIwDIV3TvEUBpyh4p@FoyCG0DolajGVGyFx@uK0I5Ys29@znzXUHedp3QdpoctADcckTBEfTz1nuokVafPTwN1TfOu2T6PxRGp3DCm4oGq09VfouCoTBDufFkHZ7JB8iYkG5Zy/1aBJMuwRKYfGlNX1T9pQwAM1XOPg2DI67HHAcTaaO5xwxsX/AA)

---

### Explanation

After reading in the input as a list called `v`, we obtain the length of `v` and store it as `n`.

```rkt
(define (f v)
  (let ([n (length v)])
    ...))
```

We then loop through the range \$ 0 \le i < n \$ and for each iteration, we return a new list (a row of the matrix) of `n` length filled with zeros except at the index of `i` which is filled with the corresponding value from `v` at index `i`.

```rkt
(define (f v)
  (let ([n (length v)])
    (for/list ([i (range n)])
      (list-set (make-list n 0)
                i
                (list-ref v i)))))
```

The `for/list` function returns the collected rows after each iteration.

### Not Bonus

While the rows start with zeros, any data in `v` will still be preserved. What this means is that we can pass list of strings to `f` and receive a matrix with both strings and zeros as the zero-value:

```rkt
; Strings
(f '("h" "e" "y"))
;;> '(("h" 0 0) (0 "e" 0) (0 0 "y"))

; Symboles
(f '(a b c))
;;> '((a 0 0) (0 b 0) (0 0 c))

; Characters
(f '(#\d #\e #\f))
;;> '((#\d 0 0) (0 #\e 0) (0 0 #\f))
```

*Have a wonderful weekend!*

Answer (score 1):

## [KamilaLisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp) v0.3, 21 bytes

```
[* #0[(⌼ =)#0#0]∘⍳∘⍴]
```

The code generates a range vector from 0 to the size of the argument; then it computes the Cartesian product of the range vector and itself using equality as the functor, therefore computing the identity matrix. Each row of the identity matrix is then multiplied by the initial vector.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
£çT hYX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o%2bdUIGhZWA&input=WzEsIC05LCAxLCAzLCA0LCAtNCwgLTUsIDYsIDksIC0xMF0KLVE)

```
£çT hYX     :Implicit input of array U
£           :Map each X at index Y
 ç          :  Fill U with
  T         :    0
    hYX     :  Replace the element at index Y with X
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
āDδQ*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKPLuS2BWv//RxvqKOha6igAKWMdBRMgB4RNdRTMdBSAwrqGBrEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/I40u57YEav3X@R8dHasTbQDEhiCsY6RjDKYN4CxdSx1DHWMdEx1dIDLVMdOx1NE1NIiNBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
āDδQ   # Create an identify matrix the size of the input-length:
ā      #  Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length]
 D     #  Duplicate it
  δ    #  Apply double-vectorized:
   Q   #   Check whether the values are equal
    *  # Multiply the values in each row with the values of the (implicit) input-list
       # (after which the matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 65 bytes

```
{a:IntArray->Array(a.size){i->IntArray(a.size).also{it[i]=a[i]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Ba8MwDIXPza945GSDbdp1G6ysgR577m6lBx2aojW1i@MFVuPfnjlhGR2MHSQ9vU8I6exCw7avPywuxFZIxGLWUYMaa/SRVlsbNt7Tp67GIsi0fDvKyLqa0OQZaloXOez5sKacUkr9rDZXzzYIWfzI@Z1e3GuFB4Xlb2f@l6lfFHJZKjzmZognhWeFbOtFXp@KYvhIiOlECV1hVK@TVcnvfR158ifkaFfIVObPR9JYwbZz56MYmDQXuiKCg3l3bN/cLuShkyhVqVDuh3QoJdJ/VPZf)

Comment: Hi there, hello! Welcome to the Code golf stack exchange! Very neat first answer you've got here - I hope you enjoy your stay on the site.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
.eXmZQkb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy81IjcqMDvp//9oQx0DHSMd41gA)

#### Explanation

```
.eXmZQkbQ    # implicitly add Q
             # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
.e      Q    # enumerated map Q over lambda, b, k
   mZQ       # list of zeros the same length as Q
  X   kb     # replace position k with b
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 77 bytes

```powershell
if($l=($a=$args).count){($k=1..$l)|%{$r++
$c=1
,($k|%{$a[$_-1]*!($c++-$r)})}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFdS8MwFH3vr7iOKIlNRrqp4EOhUPTBF8XtbYxRY@bUbpn9UGHrb69pSuu6Sgwp9@uce25ut@pLJulKxjETKpElWvq78nWJUexjFPkoSl5SMhQq32Rkh9G77w2HKCb70x1KXNdBwvccqvNVIpqhBfPm5ycYCddlKCEFKYqycJwAO6APhQAHmFSGkIMMJ43tpD3S2G6awojCmLQR19dE3FRan1eoYyr/i90lHYWjXrXflV1T0GZM4UIH1XdJ4YqCTjOP98T6txGoGtkR3CjZAdyMYgdwM6sdwOvH2BG8fq0dwc067ABu9mUH8Hqhev8E9nCrkptIrNj905sUGezMT0GZTLMwSiUFJL@3uiCfwQe0qKuHqdbfQ6g2nzLJpordpWoDLFTrbSLT1KlZ2s3jTHPwGVpC0EiQf5mzh0mYp5la1zPOg3rI6kxyITTO@H4rweTH72AtdjDViiC05KDCNvpg02@4j3Xjro6pFk5R/gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 6 bytes

```
⊢×⍋=⌜⍋
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqiw5fijYs94oyc4o2LCgpGIDPigL8x4oC/NOKAvzHigL814oC/OQ==)

#### Explanation

```
⊢×⍋=⌜⍋
      ⍋  Grade up; for our purposes, gives a list of unique integers of the same
          length as the argument
  ⍋      Grade up again
    =⌜   Create an equality table
         This gives an identity matrix the same size as the length of the argument
⊢×       Multiply each row by the corresponding element of the argument
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```scala
x=>x.zipWithIndex.map((e:Int,i:Int)=>Seq.fill(x.size)(0).updated(i,e))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZLBSsQwEIbB4z7FHBNIy9SqaCFlDyLsWcSD7CHYlA1027rNQlnZJ_HSiz6Ib7E-jWmysrqtG0ibzOSbf_4OfftonkUh4m53O10KVUImc1jIoqgITeChVBo4vE7A5vOqSuBevjzNSj0HntrzTzzvwfe1zoPr3V3L0zbcqPpR6cWszGQbLkVNiEwMyVT_pjw1lWGuioK0YaM2khKk4brOhJYZUUxS6tS-zj63xoBoGrnSxHggppBQCpyDOw1v8XC9D0eg6C8UjUMMzhnERygDNIsym0GL_IrQFoyL4Qm9Y5FBYtDmVKfghoHZYgYXJuifSwZXDEw6iPA_A8N1aNgr-hi0TX0IWl8-BK11H4Lu63wMugH4GLQz8iFox-hDcD9pOtm6X7nr3P4N)

Answer (score -2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 67 bytes

```
lambda a:[[x*(i==j) for i,x in enumerate(a)]for j in range(len(a))]
```

A 42-byte solution that only works if all elements are unique:

```python
lambda a:[[x*(x==y) for x in a]for y in a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCoAgFEDRva94o0aLRBCBX2IOL8oSTMUc9OvNiLa2A/f6HA9n@9GHovhcDJ7LioCTEKklifNMQbkACbQFlA/zy4LAwegrkoB23wjrYKC08UHbSPCDqqQNCibrzf5ruQE)

Comment: The input isn't guaranteed to be unique though, so this answer is invalid.

Comment: Hence, the disclaimer.

Comment: Even with the disclaimer, the answer is invalid, and so you need to delete it.

Comment: I would recommend keeping this answer, and adding a version (even if it's much longer) that does work in the same post. That's the typical way of handling interesting but technically invalid answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rydwolf. I considered the longer solution to similar to already posted answers.