# All-inclusive semi-primes

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, primes

\$723 = 3 \times 241\$ is a semi-prime (the product of two primes) whose prime factors include all digits from \$1\$ to \$n\$, where \$n\$ is the total number of digits between them. Another way to look at this is that the (sorted) digits in the factorisation of \$723\$ are all consecutive. The first 10 such semi-primes and their factorisations are

```
[26, 62, 723, 862, 943, 1263, 2906, 3086, 7082, 7115]
[2×13, 2×31, 3×241, 2×431, 23×41, 3×421, 2×1453, 2×1543, 2×3541, 5×1423]
```

We will call the numbers that have this feature **all-inclusive semi-primes**

You may choose whether to:

- Take an integer \$n\$ and output the \$n\$th all-inclusive semi-prime (0 or 1 indexed)
- Take an integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ all-inclusive semi-primes
- Output the sequence of all-inclusive semi-primes indefinitely

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins!

[This](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//w4ZmwrVERuG5okrGkcOXTD0yxooKMcOHI@G5hMOGZmrigqzigJ3Dl2rigb4sIMOYW2r//zEwMA) is a Jelly program which takes an integer \$n\$ and outputs the first \$n\$ all-inclusive semi-primes and their factorisations. Spoilers for any Jelly based solutions.

The first 100 all-inclusive semi-primes are

```
[26, 62, 723, 862, 943, 1263, 2906, 3086, 7082, 7115, 8306, 9026, 10715, 10793, 10826, 10862, 11705, 12443, 12773, 21155, 21443, 22313, 22403, 29126, 29306, 31286, 32906, 69302, 70922, 72902, 73082, 87302, 90722, 91226, 91262, 92306, 92702, 104903, 106973, 108326, 108722, 109262, 112862, 116213, 123086, 123155, 127082, 128306, 129026, 129743, 130826, 132155, 135683, 142283, 148373, 155123, 157373, 161393, 171305, 181205, 206315, 216305, 225833, 226223, 230543, 237023, 241103, 241223, 244913, 259433, 270934, 271294, 273094, 274913, 275903, 280403, 287134, 291274, 310715, 312694, 312874, 316205, 317105, 320615, 321155, 328714, 330874, 335003, 335086, 335243, 337111, 340313, 349306, 350926, 355741, 359881, 373701, 379371, 379641, 380581]
```

Comment: I don't suppose it would be acceptable to return the 2 prime factors of each term instead?

Comment: @Shaggy Fraid that's a bit too much of a stretch, sorry

Comment: Golfed 1 off your Jelly example... [by removing the `Ɗ` from the end of the first line](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//w4ZmwrVERuG5okrGkcOXTD0yCjHDhyP/w4fhuYTDhmZq4oKs4oCdw5dq4oG@LCDDmFtq/zEwMA). My original attempt isn't even close!

Comment: Since there are only 9 possible digits for the primes, this is a finite sequence. If we choose to output *all* all-inclusive semi-primes, do we need to keep the order?

Comment: @ovs I didn't realise it was finite. In that case, yeah, you may output the entire sequence in any order, but the \$n\$th term based options must still use ascending order (my guess is that ignoring order just saves bytes from avoiding `sort`ing?)

Comment: The last term is \$842696243 = 8641 \times 97523\$.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing In my case it doesn't save any bytes, but it is just more convenient without sorting ;)

Comment: The first term without a single-digit prime factor is 21,443 = 41 x 523, I believe.

Comment: @GregMartin \$943 = 23\times41\$

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒÒDS{āQиg<
```

Outputs the infinite sequence.

-2 bytes thanks to *@CommandMaster*, which also opened up the opportunity to golf 2 more bytes
-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOT3IJrj7SGHhhR7rN//8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞         # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ        # Filter this list by:
  Ò       #  Get a list of its prime factors (including duplicates)
   D      #  Duplicate this list
    S     #  Convert the list of integers to a flattened list of digits
     {    #  Sort these digits
      ā   #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list itself)
       Q  #  Check that the two lists are equal (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    и     #  Repeat the list if prime factors that many times as list
          #  (so it'll become empty for falsey results; and stays the same for truthy)
     g    #  Pop and push the length of this list
      <   #  And decrease it by 1
          #  (NOTE: only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, so if the amount of prime factors was
          #  anything other than 2, this will be falsey)
          # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: 14 bytes: `∞ʒÒ©g<∞®J{SÅ?*` though I feel like at least one byte can be removed

Comment: @CommandMaster Ah nice! Didn't think about using `Òg` instead of `fg` like that. And using the approach of `®S{āQ` of my existing answer instead of your `∞®J{SÅ?` saves 2 more bytes, so thanks for -4. :)

Comment: [`∞ʒÒDS{āQиg<`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOT3IJrj7SGHhhR7rN//8A) for 11 bytes.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Smart little golf.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

*-3 thanks to Unrelated String!*

This defines a predicate that unifies with all-inclusive-semi-primes. In Prolog this is equivalent to a generator, that will return all all-inclusive-semi-primes one by one.

```
ḋĊcẹo~⟦₁&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3vihrDigoLhuol94bag/@G4i8SKY@G6uW9@4p@m4oKBJv//)

```
ḋĊcẹo~⟦₁&
ḋ         prime factors
 Ċ        are a pair (list of length 2)
  cẹ      and the elements of the concatenation (all the digits)
    o     ordered
     ~⟦₁  are the result of a range operation, f.e.
            4 ⟦₁ [1,2,3,4]
            [1,2,3,4] ~⟦₁ 4
        & return the input
```

Comment: Just about exactly what I was on the verge of posting, except I don't think you need the `ℕ₁ᵐ` since `⟦₁` is a range from 1 anyhow.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Ah, of course, thanks! (And sorry for stealing the Brachylog answer here. :-))

Comment: I did stick a `d` in there so it would have taken at least another minute or two to realize that's a problem. Plus, having competition means I actually have to up my game ;)

Comment: I'm new here, but why don't you need to include the header in the bytecount? The code just outputs `true.` without the header

Comment: @bRost03 Prolog's IO is a bit strange. `true.` indicates that the predicate can unify with something. To get a result, you must name an output variable: [TIO](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9icmFjaHlsb2cy///huIvEimPhurlvfuKfpuKCgSb///9Z). If you'd run this locally, you could either stop the search `.` or search for more results `,`. So this is a generator predicate, which is allowed for the [sequence] tag. More generally: usually on CG, functions are accepted that handle IO per function arguments – you don't have to build complete programs.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

Outputs all **all-inclusive semi-primes**, not quite in ascending order.

```
7°ÅpâʒS{āQ}PÙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f/NCGw60FhxedmhRcfaQxsDbg8Mz//wE)

**Commented**:

The `S{āQ` is borrowed from [Kevin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215130/64121).

```
7°              # push 10^7
  Åp            # push the first 10^7 primes
                # the first 5694505 would be enough but costs more bytes
    â           # take the cartesian product of that list with itself
                # to create all pairs of primes
     ʒ    }     # filter the pairs by
      S         #   split into a list of digits
       {        #   sort the digits
        ā       #   push the range [1 .. length]
         Q      #   are those lists equal?
           P    # take the product of each pair
            Ù   # take the unique elements
```

The different order is a result of the order of the cartesian product, pairs that start with `2` are first, then pairs with `3`, `7`... The order could be fixed by replacing `Ù` with `ê` (unique sort), but this would prevent output until all calculations are finished.

`98765431`, the `5694505th` prime number, is the largest prime that can be used to create an all-inclusive semi-prime.

Comment: You could use `ê` for your submission to conform to the spec and just replace it with `Ù` in your TIO so it runs faster.

Comment: @Shaggy I guess it hasn't been added to the post yet, but caird clarified in the comments that for this output method we can use a different order. And since the current version runs better and produces any output on TIO I will keep it like this.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

(or **[15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHtxPpzW0sKgFTwoWVHGx7ubEwp8Pv//7@RAQA)** for versions that just output the n-th, or [first *n*](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxLQT689tLSkAUsGHlh1teLizMaXA7////0YGAA) all-inclusive semi-primes, and so will always terminate instead of running indefinitely)

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime's suggestion to just use `p` twice instead of my complicated approach of spending 3 bytes just to save one character...*

*...then another -1 byte, and again -3 bytes, thanks to Razetime*

*...then -2 more bytes thanks to Leo*

```
fȯεtpfȯS¦ŀṁdpN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qG3io6bG/2kn1p/bWlIApIIPLTva8HBnY0qB3////40MAA)

Returns infinite list of all-inclusive semi-primes.
[TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qG3io6bG/2kn1p/bWlIApIIPLTva8HBnY0qB3////40MAA) header selects first 20 to avoid timing-out.

```
!fo§&o=2L(§=OoḣLṁd)pN
!                       # get the input-th element of
 f                  N   # natural numbers that satisfy
  o§&              p    # both conditions of prime factors:
     o=2L               # there are 2 of them, and
                ṁd)     # their digits
            O           # sorted
         (§=            # are equal to
             oḣL        # the sequence from 1..number of digits
```

Comment: [Shorter without combinators(and indexing)](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr//9mw7ZTPW/huKPilrJP4bmBZHBmyK89MkxwTv// "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: Yes!  Shorter, and also much less complicated!  Thanks!

Comment: Why not remove indexing?

Comment: @Razetime - that is a very good suggestion, and it should work, but why doesn't it work on TIO?

Comment: Must be the two filters. You can show that taking a few elements works, and prove it's an infinite list.

Comment: @Razetime - does the 'infinite no index' version work on a local installation?  I can only use TIO.  I'd like to claim that 18-bytes is valid, but feel nervous about posting something untested...

Comment: [`oḣL → ŀ`](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9odXNr/@KGkeKCgf9myK89MkxwZsO2Uz3FgE/huYFkcE7///8yMA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks again!

Comment: Note that the list of inclusive semiprimes is finite. I'm not sure how this affects the solution? Does it just hang after outputting all of them?

Comment: @JoKing - Yes, I suppose it will 'hang' (or rather, keep searching on & on in case it finds another, even if there aren't any more...).  Is this a problem...?

Comment: I had to look it up, but the [current consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/76162) appears to be that programs should always terminate.

Comment: @JoKing - Ok, thanks for clarifying.  I wonder how that applies when the challenge description indicates 'Output ... indefinitely' as an output option, but I'll try to also make a version that terminates...

Comment: @JoKing - Luckily output option 2 only costs +1 byte, so terminating-version now added as an alternative solution.

Comment: `=2L` can become `εt`, and using `¦` (set inclusion) instead of `=` (list equality) saves you from having to sort the list
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qG3io6bG/2kn1p/bWlIApIIPLTva8HBnY0qB3////40MAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Leo - Super!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>22 21 17</s></sup> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âH«q☻╧Ñ♦├x╓║Nm"°
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8348ae7102cfa504c378d6ba4e6d22f8&i=&a=1)

-1 byte using a generating block.

-4 bytes using a filter.

-1 byte from wastl.

Outputs infinite list, separated by newlines.

### Explanation (Uncompressed)

```
VIf|fY%2=y$eEc%R|}*
VIf                          filter natural numbers, printing truthy values 
                             take current iteration value
    |fY                      store prime factorization in Y(without pop)
       %                     Length   
        2=                   Equals 2?
          y                  Push prime factors again
           $eE               Convert to string, then to digits
              c%             copy and take length
                R            Range [1..length]
                 |}          are they setwise equal?
                   *         multiply the two values
```

Comment: 16 bytes: https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8348ae7102cfa504c378d6ba4e6d22f8&i=&a=1

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Returns the first `n` terms; replace `j` with `i` to return the 0-indexed `n`th term.

```
È=k)cì ÍeX¬ÊõXÊÉ}jU
```

Try [the first 10 terms](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yD1rKWPsIM1lWKzK9VjKyX1qVQ&input=MTA) or [the first 100 terms](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yD1rKWPsIM1lWKzK9VjKyX1qVQ&input=MTAw)

```
È=k)cì ÍeX¬ÊõXÊÉ}jU     :Implicit input of integer U
È                       :Function taking an integer X as argument
 =                      :  Reassign to X
  k                     :  Prime factors
   )                    :  End reassignment
    c                   :  Flat map
     ì                  :    Digit arrays
       Í                :  Sort
        e               :  Test equality with
         X¬             :    Join X
           Ê            :    Length (a)
             XÊÉ        :    Length of X minus 1 (b)
            õ           :    Range [b,a]
                }       :End function
                 jU     :Get the first U integers that return true (or the Uth, if using i)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 108 bytes

Returns the **n**-th term, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,k=2)=>(g=n=>a=q>n?'':n%q?g(n,q++):q+g(n/q,i--))(k,q=i=2)*i|[...a].sort().some(v=>v^++i)||--n?f(n,k+1):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BDoIwFET3nqILDP2W1uBO8MNBjIYGgVTw1wJhA5y91tVMMvNm3nrRUz2a7yzJvhrvW@SU9HgBLHiHhIVGV1AZxxkdXdmF0AkBmRPBnl1ipATgfeLQBOZktrtSSj/UZMeZQ5BPwxcslqcQBrZNSirb/4FIIet9a0dODFmaM2I3dg0Sxtl6YKy2NNmhUYPteKV5tNIOoRmtAYe9gvyw@x8)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                   // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                    //   n = input
  k = 2                 //   k = next integer to test
) => (                  //
  g = n =>              // g is a recursive function taking an integer and building
                        // a concatenation of its divisors
    a =                 //   assign the final result to a:
      q > n ?           //     if q is greater than n:
        ''              //       stop and coerce the answer to a string
      :                 //     else:
        n % q ?         //       if q is not a divisor of n:
          g(n, q++)     //         do a recursive call to g with q + 1
        :               //       else:
          q +           //         append q
          g(n / q, i--) //         and do a recursive call to g with n / q and i - 1
)(k, q = i = 2)         // initial call to g with n = k, q = 2 and i = 2
* i |                   // if i is not equal to 0 (i.e. k has not exactly 2 divisors)
[...a].sort()           // or the sorted digits of a ...
.some(v => v ^ ++i)     // ... do not match the sequence 1, 2, ..., x
|| --n ?                // or the previous conditions are met but decrementing n does
                        // not result in 0:
  f(n, k + 1)           //   do a recursive call to f with k + 1
:                       // else:
  k                     //   success: return k
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 123 bytes

outputs the nth term

```
(n=w=0;While[n<#,If[Last/@(f=FactorInteger)@w=={1,1}&&(s=Sort[Join@@(IntegerDigits@#&@@@f@w)])==Range@Max@s,n++];w++];w-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBC4IwFADgvxIIY0ND7WoP3kECoyDq0EE8DJlzkE/YHiyIfvuC6vKdvkXzbBbNbtTJQpIEEarmPruH6WmfFd3Un3TgEuUEBz3y6jtiY41XGAFedVG/hZABbqvn/rg6QpT/0TrrOGAmEHHCqAYFcNVkDZ71E0NBeT408cu2ViJdvCPelGhL/LVdldIH)

the following prints all `36918` terms

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 139 bytes

```
Union@(f=Flatten)[Times@@d/@#&/@Select[f[(q=#;TakeDrop[q,#]&/@o)&/@Permutations[o=Range@#],1],And@@PrimeQ[(d=FromDigits)/@#]&]&/@3~Range~9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc3BCoMwEATQjwmIgiClp1ICWxDP2tpTyCHoakPNpsb16q@naS9zGeaNM/xCZ9gOJrbBEkO3W2SIT7KeIJ9ksxhmpEL11uEGMFYgsgoeuODAalL5KsW1N2@sg/@otRQ6tb5I0WJwOyfb06a8vBuaEYQuT7q80QiQ/hx2Kh9lE7yr7Wx5K5Kusx9xPv6D46JjjF8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <sup><s>228</s>...<s>214</s></sup> 212 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
b->{int x=9,l,C[],y,i=b;for(;i>0;i-=b){y=++x;var s="";for(b=0;y>1&&b++<2;y/=l,s+=l)for(l=1;l++<y&y%l>0;);C=new int[l=s.length()];b-=y;for(var c:s.getBytes())b&=c-49<l&c>48?C[c-49]=1:0;for(int k:C)b&=k;}return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA/b4MwEMX3fIpTpCIs/jRUGZoYU6lIlTp0yogYbGKoE8cgbNJYEZ@dGpROHax39j3/7vRO9Eqj0/E8VZJqDV9UKLivALqBSVGBNtQ4OTlXPBgh43pQlRGtij8eRfqpDG94H8KjyKAGMrEouwtl4EZ2oQzzogxtKAjDddv7WGQbLCLC0N2SILjhK@1Bk/V66TKywTZLPI8FQfqC7TORoQ6IRHNTkgRL9249@yQdBeGcKP4DblQhiY4lV4359lGJWUTswpvh1V7HDTfv1nDtI8Q8UkXbXSq9Ktu@vuXFfCtJst8sP@a9z/t8tp3x2HMz9ApueJzwv2CurTjCxYXmH0wvVFOUQPtGoyVDAEeDBSeAQIKdpJAsGgR/HoCD1YZf4nYwcecgRiq/jmnXSesLhPDiGlfzGadf)

Returns the nth element of the sequence (1-indexed).

Ungolfed:

```
b -> {
int x = 9, l, C[], y, b, i = b;
for (; i > 0; i -= b) {
    y = ++x;
    var s = "";
    for (b = 0; y > 1 && b++ < 2; y /= l, s += l)
        for (l = 1; l++ < y & y % l > 0;);
    C = new int[l = s.length()];
    b -= y;
    for (var c : s.getBytes()) 
      b &= c - 49 < l & c > 48 ? C[c - 49] = 1 : 0;
    for (int k : C) b &= k;
}
return x;
}
```

Comment: [221 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZA/b4MwEMX3fIpTpSIsGxqqDE2MqVSkSh06ZUQM/K@JYxA2aayIz04NTacO1jv7nn6@e212yby2PM2FyJSCz4xLuG0A@jEXvAClM22ltS5/1Fz49SgLzTvpv9@L8EPqqqkGAvcighrYLL3oxqWGK9sTQeIkJYaUpCU54WxL625wKQ8l5Zjl6GYYxld6yQZQ7OFh7bbWZaLAcVqMw2dqnlhJFGYlWpolC2hp341jHstoSxEVTPmiko3@chGNmay@wf6eiJTmrPXMilz4xUH5TaXfjK6Ui1DusMLb7UPhFNHu5TVOllvKgsPviMsCp0O82E50Gio9DhKudJrpv4QuHS/hbNNzj3rgsklSyIZGoTVMAEuDFceBQUCthBCsivGfB@BolK7Ofjdqv7cQLaRb@1nfC@NyhOjqmjbLmeYf). `y/=d,s+=d` inside the loop so you can ditch the `{}`; `.toCharArray()` to `.getBytes()`; & you don't need to count the trailing `;` of lambdas

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>190</s> 175 bytes

```
: f ( n -- n ) 1 [ over 0 = ] [ dup factors [ 10 >base ] map
[ pair? ] [ concat [ length [1,b] [ 48 + ] map ] keep
diff ""= ] bi and [ [ 1 - ] dip ] when 1 + ] until nip 1 - ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVCxTsMwFNzzFadOIHCUVAyoVUFMqEsXxBQxOMlLa9V5MbZT1K8PL05hOZ3P9@6eXqebOPjp82N/eN9Ae6@vAWfyTBa9jqcEudM@kL9xb3oKeZcGw6J5zUcKCPQ9EjeJxQDnKcar@Dlim@0PG7xZqww3dgzmQipQb9QSN23Q4Q4MpQTuUaLCcJHKAjt8yaMdHf4qK5QFXmodSL567bIKThv/mozNwI2OQizxUfavysd61p@e8bDYBc9ELmtN12G1mvNrA82tuCQaSoTWzLafE7EI89zI0ViwyLNhO62L/@S0GtbpdreGfPoF)

Comment: Do you have a rationale for excluding the `USING:` statement (aka library imports) from byte count? (Not that I want to disadvantage an already verbose language even more)

Comment: @Bubbler I'm not sure at all what I do is right. My explanation is that all `words` in Factor live in `vocabularies` - for example the stack shuffling words like `swap` reside in `kernel`  vocabulary. Thus I would need to add to the byte count all imports, as well as the `IN:` export.

Comment: After further investigation, it looks like [cat started the tradition of auto-use](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76315/78410) ([relevant doc](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-auto-use__que__%2Cparser.html)), which can be toggled in the interactive UI, or enabled for running scripts [via .factor-rc file](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp1Cnr5eWmFySX6RblKxgY6Pg6u/GFRrs6edupVCQWFScWqSQl5ibWlyQmJxarGDNlVhakq9bWpxqr5CfxwVSCzOlOL@0KDkVahbUoP@GekYKKaUFCtoKaTn5QGG9/yAt@vkFJfoQhVAKXf9/AA). Maybe I should ask in meta.

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you for your investigation! What do you think about using quotations (lambdas) - as in cat's answer - instead of words, defined with a stack effect 
`: f ( n -- n )` ?

Comment: Anonymous lambdas look fine to me, as it's pushed to stack on definition and can be called and reused.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>112</s> 111 bytes

```
123456789
L$`.
:::$>`
+%/\d$/&Lv$`(.)(.*:)(.)
$`$1$3$2$'
\d+
*
A`:_?:|(:_+)\1|:(__+)\2+:
:(_+):(_+):
$.($.1*$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jci9CsJAEEXh/j7HVfcHJszGagrFPo@wkBFiYZMiSKq8@xpjc/g4y@vznp/aGrT0Vwx0gZnx5sinrk7szsNKDxKDJNsTQaeyZ@EFdcpIeLiNd9ssjDla1R921ZIN/3cElEDRxNLaFw) Above program outputs the entire sequence, but TIO times out if the total number of semiprime digits is not less than 5, so the link only outputs six elements. Explanation:

```
123456789
```

Start with the potential semiprime digits.

```
L$`.
:::$>`
```

Get all their prefixes and add some markers to delimit the potential prime factors.

```
+%/\d$/&Lv$`(.)(.*:)(.)
$`$1$3$2$'
```

Generate all permutations of the digits among the potential primes.

```
\d+
*
```

Convert all the numbers to unary.

```
A`:_?:|(:_+)\1|:(__+)\2+:
```

Delete all results unless both numbers are prime and the first is greater than the second. This is one of the slowest parts of the program; [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYi9DoJAEAb77zk@9X6SJXtIs4XGnke4hDXBgobCGF//QGlmJvN@fZb1qa1BS38dMNIFZsabI5@6OrM7j196kBgk2Y4IOpU9Cy@oc0bCw226209hytGqHrl31Ww47h@gBIomltY2) can calculate 23 results if these are split into separate filters. However, despite my best efforts, larger results are simply too slow.

```
:(_+):(_+):
$.($.1*$2
```

Calculate the resulting semiprimes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 123 bytes

```
{grep({$!=$_/($/=first $_%%*,2..$_);$!.is-prime&&{.[0]===.first(:k,0)}(+«[\∖]
"$!$/".comb.Bag,|('1'..'9'))},9..∞)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc3BDYIwFADQu1MU8qGt1l/0QIKmF9dAbNBQQpRAiheC3JnAowu4haOwSDXeX/Lawt5iV/ckNES5obRFywbwFGjJQCpT2e5OQAfBUmwRQfM9eFh169ZWdRGGA6ZRppTCP2S7q4j4yFafd3qcp2e28MED6eOlqc94yEvxYHRDEWlCOR9FgjhPL56CzkbX5T0x7DcQ01hyit0X)

- `$_` is the argument to the function.
- `grep(..., 9..∞)` filters the integers from nine to infinity.  `[$_]` indexes into that sequence with the function argument and returns that value.  Within the filtering function `$_` is the number being tested.
- `$! = $_ / ($/ = first $_ %% *, 2..$_)` sets `$/` to the smallest (necessarily prime) divisor of `$_`, and `$!` to `$_` divided by that number.
- If `$!` is not prime, then `$_` is not a semiprime, so the filter function returns false.
- `"$!$/"` is the concatenation of the semiprime's two factors.
- `.comb` returns a list of those digits.
- `.Bag` returns a bag (that is, a set with multiplicity) of those digits.
- `[\∖]` is a triangular reduction using the set-difference operator `∖` on the list consisting of the aforementioned Bag and each of the digits from 1 to 9.  The elements of this reduction are the initial Bag, then the same bag with a single `1` removed, then that second Bag with a single `2` removed, and so on.

Now the idea is to check that this sequence of bags gets exactly one element smaller as one of each successive digit is removed until it reaches a size of zero.

- `+«` turns that list of Bags into a list of their sizes (which counts multiplicity).
- That list of sizes is fed into the bracket-delimited anonymous function, which is immediately called.  Within that function, `$_` refers to the list of sizes.
- `.first(:k, 0)` returns the index of the first zero element of the list.  If no element is zero, `Nil` is returned instead.
- `.[0] === .first(:k, 0)` is true if the index of the first zero is equal to the first element of the list.  This will be true only for lists of the form `N, N-1, N-2, ..., 1, 0, 0, 0`.  From the way the list is constructed, each successive element can only ever be one or zero less than the preceding element.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 208 bytes

```python
def f(x,r={26},n=9,R=range):
 while len(r)<x:
  for d in R(2,n:=n+1):n%d<1and all(k%i for k in(d,n//d)for i in R(2,k))*(l:=[*map(int,sorted(str(d)+str(n//d)))])==[*R(1,len(l)+1)]and r.add(n)
 return sorted(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVTbctpADH3nKzTTyeBN3LL3CxP3I/JKeaDYBA9kYYzTpMPw7VTSOuXBZ6XV5Uhacf477k/ZxPNwv7fdDnbVZz00V@1vdW5S/dIMm/zaieUMPvb9sYNjl6tBPH@iAnanAVroM7xUus7LJj8pscwP7bPa5BY2x2N1eOjZ6oBWVVvnxaIVJPdfXgchHqvjslk9vm3OVZ/H@nIaxq6tLuNQteKJgL2EWIsGzV4qVROHo8Bka8oz/Ni0bZXFDIZufB8yTBEGce8@z90Wz9DASvsavK4haFNDpFOyeFLa41cniddGRvwGGclMKYd2hvRJkrOSgVQIifzQipUcSqkg6U7bEjMECoohHAErtTaKwUpOqMhdJ05glKbMptDwqCQGMmnmm1gyTCsGvksy0B0GoSgUiyRd2OpAJkraJJmoT6EQNhNj9lUYvlDXUwleKyZf2oDI9LEYzoxmHF7pqR06BS7WTJ0wutgb5yPprdYFo@H8zinNGIrsleFGBoxAflFpQi29Udw2z3qtXTTcOK/JH@k57qfBMgmtUrJgubc2caMdzpcQ@2gsITJmNLLgZBcc90lHWSYTkZAtEwqWZlPmjjPyyZZZFb1nvgYLYETibDeN3VAgssP@sL1xkuIT8rCN05ZlfGoKEbMTH2OnN@FoQIQuWLp3KUZCbJ9kTOjJ6Pk@ShfVerbdd9tDN@CTr@a/3rGE7bwGPikzF7P/28d7XdEqfW2JWCyUFEv4BuPm0F1gA3@64S8cT/kVxv6tg/EE7Yn2GlcMtvvTGfoRNR8ZTX/3I/4jAGRM3MMTKJYuKO14N/HXofCVa7XMa1aeB1z6aje/5ht8/wnXyw2uUwmrrmku69tc3P8B)

Inputs an integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ all-inclusive semi-primes (\$1\$-indexed).